# TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, decorations

Like this:

```
.------<------.
|             |
v             ^
|             |
'------>------'
```

I am currently using

```
\begin{scope}[very thick,->]
  \draw (-4,1)--(-4,0)--(0.1,0);
  \draw (0,0)--(4,0)--(4,1.1);
  \draw (4,1)--(4,2)--(-0.1,2);
  \draw (0,2)--(-4,2)--(-4,0.9);
\end{scope}
```

but this is rather inelegant. I prefer something more like

```
\begin{scope}[very thick,middle decoration=>] 
             %           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ a hypothetical option
  \draw (-4,0)--(4,0);
  \draw (4,0)--(4,2);
  \draw (4,2)--(-4,2);
  \draw (-4,2)--(-4,0);
\end{scope}
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The `decorations` library can be used to all kinds of stuff like this. Unfortunately it is slightly verbose.

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{scope}[very thick,decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}
    ] 
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-4,0)--(4,0);
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (4,0)--(4,2);
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (4,2)--(-4,2);
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-4,2)--(-4,0);
\end{scope}
```

Comment: But with a few `every path/.style={}`s then it shouldn't be too wordy.  Nice!  (Better than mine)

Comment: @Andrew When I put `postaction={decorate}` into the `every path/.style={}`, I get an error: `Undefined control sequence.
\pgf@decorate@processnextinputsegmentobject`. I have no idea why.

Comment: Hm, it also says "I cannot decorate an empty path". Is it possible that pgf is trying to apply the decoration even to the paths that the arrow is made from, and one of the paths is empty?

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/applying-a-postaction-to-every-path-in-tikz

Comment: @Caramdir, is it possible to use the arrow tip as `-latex`?

Comment: @Sigur: I suppose changing `\arrow{>}` to `\arrow{latex}` should work.

Comment: @Caramdir, ow. How couldn't I see it? So clear. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 63):

**Edit:** A general solution to apply some some styles (like put an arrow in the middle) to each segment of an arbitrary path.

There are two styles:

- the `on each segment` style uses the `show path construction` decoration of `decorations.pathreplacing` library **to apply some styles (its argument) on each segment of a path**.
- the `mid arrow` style uses the method of Caramdir's answer (via `decorations.markings` library) to **put an arrow in the middle of a path** (its argument is the color of the arrow).

First, the preamble:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
```

The two styles:

```
\tikzset{
  % style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
  on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
      }}},
}
```

Then the result and the document:

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path [draw=blue,postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=red}}]
  (.2,0) -- (3,1) arc (0:180:1.4 and 1) -- cycle
  (4,1) circle(.8)
  (6,1) ellipse(.5 and 1)
  (0,3) to [bend left] (3,4)
  (4,3) rectangle (6,4)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really useful. I wonder if this is included in the latest version of Tikz.

Comment: @BarisErkus The `show path construction` decoration is already included in the current version of TikZ. My `on each segment` style is just a simple application of this decoration.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I wanted to modify this for other arrowheads, e.g. double arrow, but it did not work. What I did was to replace "{\tikz \draw[-triangle 90] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);}" by "{\tikz 
 \draw[-triangle 90] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);
 \draw[-triangle 90] (0,0)--+(.145,0);}", but this head no effect

Comment: @klirk You can use the `arrows.meta` library (a TikZ library) and, in my code, replace `stealth` by `Stealth[]Stealth[]` or `Triangle[]Triangle[]`.

Comment: Does this mean that arcs, circles and ellipses have 4 paths? I would have expected them to be drawn all in one piece and therefore to see only one arrow in them.

Comment: @Andyc The four basic operations  for building a path are move-to, line-to, curve-to (_Béziers curves_), and close.  All other operations are just combinations of these four operations (cf. pgf manual, pp. 1096-1098).

Comment: @PaulGaborit How to put only an arrow on a circle ?

Comment: @Fabrice Try `\draw [-latex] (45:1cm) arc(45:405:1cm);`

Comment: Does this work for `plot`? Example: `\path [draw=blue,postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=red}},domain=0:1,smooth,variable=\t] plot (\t,\t);` I tried but it gave me an error, this only works for primitives?

Comment: Okay I found something for curved lines https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163689/add-arrows-to-a-smooth-tikz-function works for plot too!

Comment: is there a way to put arrows clockwise on the circle?

Comment: @Rainb Use `\arrowreversed` instead of `\arrow` in the `mid arrow` style definition.

Answer (score 31):

*Update: 2020-02-22*: This code has been superseded and shouldn't be used. It also nests tikzpictures, something that I later realised was Not Good. [Caramdir's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3172/86) is the best all-round solution, but if you want something that is close to this one then [Kpym's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430486/86) using `pic`s has the same spirit as this but without the drawbacks.

---

Given that the precise syntax you specify isn't possible, here's something that achieves the desired effect without having to specify the coordinates of the midpoints.

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 90] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[very thick, every node/.style={sloped,allow upside down}]
  \draw (-4,0)-- node {\midarrow} (4,0);
  \draw (4,0)-- node {\midarrow} (4,2);
  \draw (4,2)-- node {\midarrow} (-4,2);
  \draw (-4,2)-- node {\midarrow} (-4,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(the `arrows` tikz library is just to get more prominent arrowheads)

This produces:

[image]

(not sure what that vertical line is down the right-hand side.  It's not in the original so must be an artefact of the pdf->png process)

Answer (score 20):

(A modification of Caramdir's solution using [Ulrich Schwarz's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/applying-a-postaction-to-every-path-in-tikz/5354#5354) to [”Applying a postaction to every path in TikZ”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/applying-a-postaction-to-every-path-in-tikz).)

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{nomorepostaction/.code={\let\tikz@postactions\pgfutil@empty}}
\makeatother
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every path/.style={
        very thick,
        postaction={nomorepostaction,decorate,
                    decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}
                   }
        }
    ]
    \draw (-4,0)--(4,0);
    \draw (4,0)--(4,2);
    \draw (4,2)--(-4,2);
    \draw (-4,2)--(-4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 10):

Without decoration and with a "unique" path, a new code is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
          insert new path/.style={%
             insert path={%
                  node[midway,sloped]{\tikz \draw[#1,thick] (-.2pt,0) -- ++(.2 pt,0);}
                  }
             }
         }

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[a/.style = {insert new path = {-triangle 90}}]
  \draw[red] (-4,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,2) -- (-4,2) -- (-4,0);
  \draw[red] (0,-4pt)--(0,+4pt); % it's a  test
  \draw (-4,0)-- (4,0)[a] -- (4,2)[a] -- (-4,2)[a] -- (-4,0)[a];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It's possible to adjust the position of the arrows with something like `node[midway,sloped,right=-2pt]`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

PSTricks equivalent (out of the box):

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](4,4)
    \pspolygon[ArrowInside=->,linecolor=red](0,0)(4,0)(4,4)(0,4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The original asked for a TikZ solution, not a pstricks one.

Answer (score 8):

This is revisited version of [Loop Space's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3165/9335) using `pic` in place of `node` that were not available in 2010.

The main advantages is that the pic inherits the path style (line width, color, ...) from the current path.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{
  arrow/.pic={\path[tips,every arrow/.try,->,>=#1] (0,0) -- +(.1pt,0);},
  pics/arrow/.default={triangle 90}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[very thick,nodes={sloped,allow upside down}]
      \draw (-4,0) -- pic{arrow} (4,0);
      \draw (4,0) -- pic[blue]{arrow} (4,2);
      \draw[thin,purple] (4,2) -- pic{arrow=latex} (-4,2);
      \draw[every arrow/.style=red] (-4,2) -- pic[pos=.3]{arrow} pic[pos=.7]{arrow} (-4,0);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And you can draw your own arrow using pics, for example by redefining `arrow` style

```
arrow/.pic={\fill[every arrow/.try,scale={\pgflinewidth/1cm}] 
    (0,0) -- (-150:7) -- (150:7) -- (0,0) circle(2);}
```

will produce the following picture

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I accidentally discovered this, using circuitikz:

```
\draw (0,0) to node[currarrow] {} (1,0);
```

[image: arrow in the middle of a line]

could not yet find an alternative for currarrow in TikZ, and it doesn't work with the basic TikZ arrows.
But you can do everything in circuitikz what you can in TikZ, and more!

Comment: i forgot, the environment is:
\begin{circuitikz}
% code
\end{circuitikz}

Comment: you mean alternatives except the top three answers above?

Comment: no, I mean I did not find an alternative to the currarrow node in the basic TikZ nodes. So you have to use the circuitikz package with this solution.

Comment: btw: circuitikz also works with the basic tikzpicture environment. I personally recommend to always use the tikzpicture environment to make it easier to parse for tikzpictures in latex-code

Comment: "you can do everything in circuitikz what you can in TikZ, and more" >>> It should be the converse: "you can do everything in TikZ what you can in circuitikz, and more"

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to node[currarrow] {} (1,0)to node[currarrow,rotate=90]{}(1,1)to node[currarrow,rotate=180]{}(0,1)to node[currarrow,rotate=-90]{}(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You could improve your answer by adding some description and an image of the result.

Comment: What is the difference to matekatona's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244942/123129)?