# Applying a postaction to every path in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

Sometime, for example in a [solution to a recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line/3172#3172), one wants to apply a `postaction` (like a decoration) to a group of paths. A naive solution is to use `every path/.style={}`. Unfortunately this also this then applies the postaction to every path drawn in the postaction, leading to an infinite regress.

Is there any way to avoid this?

A somewhat stupid minimal example of the problem:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={postaction={draw}}]
    \draw (0,0)--(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with error message

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\pgfutil@g@addto@macro #1#2->\begingroup 
                                         \toks@ \expandafter {#1#2}\xdef #1{...
l.12     \draw (0,0)--(1,0);
```

Comment: Let's see if a bounty can get this question answered.

Comment: @seamus: much to me surprise it did. :)

Comment: (I only did it to get the badge for posting a bounty on someone else's question, but I actually feel like I've helped make the site better, a little bit...)

Comment: @Seamus: fair enough, it did work. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please check if the following solves your problem, in particular with regard to scoping, this seems far too easy. `nomorepostactions` is intended to locally empty out the postactions, so they don't get applied after that.

It did fix your toy problem.

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{nomorepostaction/.code=\let\tikz@postactions\pgfutil@empty}
\makeatother
[...]
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={postaction={nomorepostaction,draw}}]
    \draw (0,0)--(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: works fine, indeed: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line/5356#5356

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn’t know about `.code`. That might be useful in other situations too.

Comment: Fantastic!  I also didn't know about the `.code` and have just looked it up in the manual (p383 in v2.00).  I can think of lots of things to do with this!  (Having small kids, I also like the example for the `.store in` handler).

Comment: @Andrew With small children it may be better to evaluate what happened first, which is why `.estore in` may be the preferred option.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this answer on ["How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161/1418) might help you. This way you do not run into a recursion.

Comment: The point was that in my answer to the question you reference, one needs to add `[postaction={decorate}]` to every path by hand which in larger examples adds a lot of copy&pasted code. And copy&pasting code is usually bad design.

Answer (score 2):

(Not an answer.)

Usually one can override properties, but is there a way to remove 'postaction' completely?
I mean, there should be a way to write something like
`[every path/.style={postaction={nopostaction}},nopostaction/.style={draw, <some way to override postaction option>}]`, probably.

(Related: [Is it possible to clear tikz/pgf options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4907/is-it-possible-to-clear-tikz-pgf-options))

Comment: Interesting approach. I don’t know what to write in place of `<some way to override postaction option>` though. Setting a postaction inside a postaction seems to get ignored.

Comment: In the original example even replacing `postaction={draw}` by `postaction={}` leads to an infinite recursion.

Comment: (Re: ..even replacing..) Of course: postaction={<options>} creates a copy of the original path with these <options> added -- in this case without any additional options -- but a path is created anyway. So one really have to remove the key, not just make it empty. (Or so it seems.)