# Is there a package to create Optical Mark Reader answer-sheets?

Tags: packages

Is there a package to create Optical Mark Reader answer-sheets (aka bubble sheet)?

EDIT 1: No choice. I think I must use PSTricks and \multido to make it.

Comment: Perhaps some more detail on the requirements for such a package?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219425/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-bubble-answer-sheet-for-multiple-choice-exam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
%%\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\baselineskip=6.35mm
\parskip=0pt
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\InitToks}{\toks@={}}
\newcommand{\AddToks}[1]{\toks@=\expandafter{\the\toks@ #1}}
\newcommand*{\PrintToks}{\the\toks@}
\unitlength=1mm
\def\BOX{\framebox(3.55,2){}}
\newcount\rowNo
\newcommand*{\dynTable}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \InitToks
    \AddToks{\tabcolsep=0pt\begin{tabular}{c*{11}{>{\centering}p{6.35mm}}}}%
    \AddToks{&&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&Inv\tabularnewline}
    \rowNo=0 %
    \loop\ifnum\rowNo<#1\relax
      \advance\rowNo by 1
      \AddToks{\strobe & }
      \expandafter\AddToks\expandafter{%
         \the\rowNo & 
         \BOX & \BOX & \BOX & \BOX & \BOX & \BOX & \BOX & \BOX & \BOX & \BOX%
        \tabularnewline}%
    \repeat
   \AddToks{\end{tabular}}%
    \PrintToks
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\def\strobe{\rule{0pt}{4mm}\rule{3mm}{2.54mm}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily\small

PREFERENCE\par
\bigskip

\dynTable{28}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering. What is the command to create an ovalbox instead of a framebox?

Comment: @xport-is-sleeping: use `\usepackage{pict2e}` to allow all radii and then
`\def\BOX{\leavevmode\put(0,0.6){\oval(3.55,2)}}`

Comment: @Herbert could you take look to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285074/mcq-answer-grid-with-tikz

Answer (score 10):

Given good specifications how the sheet should look like (positions, sizes, extra markings, etc.) it shouldn't be too hard to create an answer sheet with TikZ.

As I lack these specification, I can only show you a simple proof of concept:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    \foreach \line in {1,2,...,4} {
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-\line cm]
            \foreach \count/\desc in {1/A, 2/B, 3/C, 4/D, 5/E} { 
                \node at ({\count * 0.5}, 0.4) {\desc};
                \node at (0,0) {\normalsize\textbf{\line}};
                \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] at ({\count * 0.5},0) {\count};
            }
        \end{scope}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Oh tikz, is there anything you -can't- do?

Comment: @flip: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4404/tikz-multiple-decorations-on-a-path

Comment: Touché!

Comment: thank for answering. Tikz is great, but I only know beloved PSTricks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct solution, but there were some people working on something called 'LOFT' a while back -

http://www.vialab.org/main/Publications/pdf/Stetten_ASEE_2010.pdf

Comment: Hi flip, thank you for the link. It is very interesting info. By the way, is it open source project?

Comment: I believe so, but, I've never seen the code... I did a little searching around after I posted this and can't seem to find anything. This really does seem like something that would exist...

Comment: perhaps wait a bit and then offer a bounty?

Comment: I have not offered a bounty because I don't know what it is.

Comment: @xport: see “What if I don't get a good answer?” in the [faq](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq). (Questions need to be two days old before a bounty can be offered.)