# How to generate a dynamic bubble answer sheet for multiple-choice exam

Tags: tables, exam, answers

I want to produce a bubble answer sheet where the number of questions are shown by \qCount. It is always below than 100. Is it possible to produce it dynamically?
I cannot print the question numbers before each row and cannot show bubbles within the cells.

desired output: [Sample](https://www.teachervision.com/tv/printables/0134356500_m1mufm46.pdf)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\repeatntimes}[2]{
   \newcount\i
   \i=0
   \newtoks\ans
   \loop
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}
      \advance\i by 1
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat
   \the\ans
}

\newcommand{\countRepeatntimes}[2]{
   \newcount\i
   \i=0
   \newtoks\ans
   \loop
      \advance\i by 1
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat
   \the\ans
}

\newcommand{\generateTable}[1]{%
\countRepeatntimes{#1}{\indent
\repeatntimes{4}{\textcolor{lightgray}{\rule{0.9\baselineskip}{0.9\baselineskip}} }\par
}
}

\begin{document}
\def\qCount{80}
\generateTable{\qCount}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I printed out a stepped counter in the loop for the problem number (and another counter for the bubble label) and changed the square `\rule` to a rotated "0", scaled and stretched appropriately.  You can change the size via the numerical arguments to `\scalebox{1.4}[1.5]{}`.  I also made it two column.

EDITED to provide sample filled block.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\newcommand{\repeatntimes}[2]{
   \newcount\i
   \i=0
   \newtoks\ans
   \loop
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}
      \advance\i by 1
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat
   \the\ans
}

\newcommand{\countRepeatntimes}[2]{
   \newcount\i
   \i=0
   \newtoks\ans
   \loop
      \advance\i by 1
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat
   \the\ans
}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{choice}
\newcommand{\generateTable}[1]{%
\countRepeatntimes{#1}{\stepcounter{problem}\makebox[2ex][r]{\theproblem.}%\indent
\setcounter{choice}{0}%
\repeatntimes{4}{\stepcounter{choice}\textcolor{black!35}{%
  \raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.8]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.6}{\tiny \Alph{choice}}}{\rotatebox{90}{0}}}}} }\par
}
}

\def\sampleblock{%
  \makebox[5.1ex]{}
  \stepcounter{choice}\textcolor{black!35}{%
   \raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.8]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.6}{\tiny \Alph{choice}}}{\rotatebox{90}{0}}}}}
  \stepcounter{choice}\textcolor{black!35}{%
   \raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.8]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.6}{\tiny \Alph{choice}}}{\rotatebox{90}{0}}}}}
  \stepcounter{choice}\textcolor{black!35}{%
   \smash{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.8]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1pt}{%
    \scalebox{6}[3.5]{\color{black}$\cdot$}}{\rotatebox{90}{0}}}}}}
  \stepcounter{choice}\textcolor{black!35}{%
   \raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.8]{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.6}{\tiny \Alph{choice}}}{\rotatebox{90}{0}}}}}
\par}
\voffset=\dimexpr\voffset+.5in
\textheight=\dimexpr\textheight-.5in

\begin{document}

\smash{\Shortstack[l]{%
  Name \underline{\hspace{2.4in}} Class\underline{\hspace{1.2in}}
    Date\underline{\hspace{1.2in}}\\
  \textcolor{black!50}{\rule{5.9in}{2ex}}\\
  \rule[2ex]{10ex}{2ex}\sffamily\itshape\Huge Bubble Answer Sheet\\
  \strut\\
  \sampleblock\\
  \rule{0ex}{4pt}\\}%
}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\par
\def\qCount{80}
\generateTable{\qCount}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

A comment requested a version with circular choices:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\newcommand{\repeatntimes}[2]{
   \newcount\i
   \i=0
   \newtoks\ans
   \loop
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}
      \advance\i by 1
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat
   \the\ans
}

\newcommand{\countRepeatntimes}[2]{
   \newcount\i
   \i=0
   \newtoks\ans
   \loop
      \advance\i by 1
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat
   \the\ans
}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{choice}
\newcommand{\generateTable}[1]{%
\countRepeatntimes{#1}{\stepcounter{problem}\makebox[2ex][r]{\theproblem.}%\indent
\setcounter{choice}{0}%
\repeatntimes{4}{\stepcounter{choice}\textcolor{black!35}{%
  \raisebox{0.5pt}{\scalebox{1.0}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.6}{\footnotesize \Alph{choice}}}{$\bigcirc$}}}} }\par
}
}

\def\sampleblock{%
  \makebox[5.1ex]{}
  \stepcounter{choice}\textcolor{black!35}{%
   \raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.0}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.6}{\footnotesize \Alph{choice}}}{$\bigcirc$}}}}
  \stepcounter{choice}\textcolor{black!35}{%
   \raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.0}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.6}{\footnotesize \Alph{choice}}}{$\bigcirc$}}}}
  \stepcounter{choice}\textcolor{black!35}{%
   \smash{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.0}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-2.5pt}{%
    \scalebox{8}{\color{black}$\cdot$}}{$\bigcirc$}}}}}
  \stepcounter{choice}\textcolor{black!35}{%
   \raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.0}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
    \scalebox{.6}{\footnotesize \Alph{choice}}}{$\bigcirc$}}}}
\par}
\voffset=\dimexpr\voffset+.5in
\textheight=\dimexpr\textheight-.5in

\begin{document}

\smash{\Shortstack[l]{%
  Name \underline{\hspace{2.4in}} Class\underline{\hspace{1.2in}}
    Date\underline{\hspace{1.2in}}\\
  \textcolor{black!50}{\rule{5.9in}{2ex}}\\
  \rule[2ex]{10ex}{2ex}\sffamily\itshape\Huge Bubble Answer Sheet\\
  \strut\\
  \sampleblock\\
  \rule{0ex}{4pt}\\}%
}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\par
\def\qCount{80}
\generateTable{\qCount}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can we make circles instead of boxes?

Comment: @Ghartal  Thanks.  Do you mean circles instead of ovals?

Comment: oh yes, I mean ovals.

Comment: @Ghartal Done.  See **SUPPLEMENT** to my answer.