# How to put a mark on an arc (tikz,decoration)

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I have a problem with this code  :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings, mark = at position .5 with
 {\draw (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt)  (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);}}]    

% wrong 
%\draw [postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- ++(146:1) arc (146:157:1)--(0,0);
%fine
\draw [postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- ++(146:1.2) arc (146:157:1.2)--(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The line after % wrong gives an error `dimension too large`. I think there is a math problem because the arc or the radius is too small or perhaps both. 
A solution is (another one is to use a scale >1 but for the fine line don't use a scale like .8 :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,fp}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,fixedpointarithmetic}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[fixed point arithmetic,
                    decoration={markings, mark = at position .5 with
       {\draw (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt)  (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);}}]     

\draw [postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- ++(146:1) arc (146:157:1)--(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I can't use it because the time for the compilation is too long.

Is it possible to  speed up the last code or perhaps someone knows another way to get the mark without an error ? Perhaps I use `decoration` in a wrong way!

Comment: Maybe related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4404/tikz-multiple-decorations-on-a-path (not the question, but the answer).

Comment: Unfortunately yes I put the solution with `fixedpointarithmetic` and the problem is similar. The little difference is that I want to put a mark in the middle of the arc. Perhaps I can avoid `decoration` ?

Comment: The other difference is that an arc seems to be more simple than a zigzag.

Comment: I have also had this problem with decorating rounded corners at the middle of the curve.  My solution was to alter the location by a percent or two; it seems to me that the problem is arithmetically unstable, possibly just a consequence of TeX's built-in arithmetic not being so good.

Comment: That's interesting, both lines work without an error for me, using PGF 2.10.

Comment: @Jake I have the error with PGF 2.10 and PGF 2.10 CVS. Are you sure to take the first version without `fixedpointarithmetic` ?

Comment: @Jake I am looking for a solution since three months seems to me that too surprising! Have you changed pgfmath?

Comment: @Altermundus: Ah, sorry, I had put `scale=2` as an option to the `tikzpicture` to see it better, and then it works, but not without the `scale`.

Comment: @Jake It's my fault because I knew this issue and with `scale=.8`the second line gives an error !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in the implementation of the mathematical function `veclen`.  In short, it *doesn't* just do `(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}` (How could it?  Taking square roots isn't even possible *theoretically* let alone the issues of precision.) but does something more complicated that at some stage involves *dividing* by one of the components.  You can test this by trying a simple:

```
\pgfmathparse{veclen(0.00006,0.00006)}
```

(the number was chosen as that *happens* to be the number that TeX barfs on when trying Altermundus' example.  Multiply by 10 and it all works again.)

Looking at the implementation of `veclen` I noticed that it did some initial scaling to take into account large numbers.  So I added some lines to test also for small numbers as well.  And that appears to solve the problem.

(Unfortunately, I couldn't get `\pgfmathredeclarefunction` to work properly.  Rather than debug that, I just `\let` the old function to `\relax` and overwrote it.)

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\makeatletter
\let\pgfmath@function@veclen\relax
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{veclen}{2}{%
  \begingroup%
  \pgfmath@x#1pt\relax%
  \pgfmath@y#2pt\relax%
  \ifdim\pgfmath@x<0pt\relax%
  \pgfmath@x-\pgfmath@x%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\pgfmath@y<0pt\relax%
  \pgfmath@y-\pgfmath@y%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\pgfmath@x=0pt\relax%
  \pgfmath@x\pgfmath@y%
  \else%
  \ifdim\pgfmath@y=0pt\relax%
  \else%
  \ifdim\pgfmath@x>\pgfmath@y%
  \pgfmath@xa\pgfmath@x%
  \pgfmath@x\pgfmath@y%
  \pgfmath@y\pgfmath@xa%
  \fi%
  % We use a scaling factor to reduce errors.
  % First, see if we should scale down
  \let\pgfmath@tmp@scale=\divide
  \let\pgfmath@tmp@restore=\multiply
  \ifdim\pgfmath@y>10000pt\relax%
  \c@pgfmath@counta1500\relax%
  \else%
  \ifdim\pgfmath@y>1000pt\relax%
  \c@pgfmath@counta150\relax%
  \else%
  \ifdim\pgfmath@y>100pt\relax%
  \c@pgfmath@counta50\relax%
  \else%
  % Not scaling down, should we scale up?
  \let\pgfmath@tmp@scale=\multiply
  \let\pgfmath@tmp@restore=\divide
  \ifdim\pgfmath@y<0.00001pt\relax%
  \c@pgfmath@counta1500\relax%
  \else%
  \ifdim\pgfmath@y<0.0001pt\relax%
  \c@pgfmath@counta150\relax%
  \else%
  \ifdim\pgfmath@y<0.001pt\relax%
  \c@pgfmath@counta50\relax%
  \else
  \c@pgfmath@counta1\relax%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \pgfmath@tmp@scale\pgfmath@x\c@pgfmath@counta\relax%
  \pgfmath@tmp@scale\pgfmath@y\c@pgfmath@counta\relax%
  \pgfmathreciprocal@{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgfmath@y}}%
  \pgfmath@x\pgfmathresult\pgfmath@x%
  \pgfmath@xa\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgfmath@x}\pgfmath@x%
  \edef\pgfmath@temp{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgfmath@xa}}%
  %
  % Use A+x^2*(B+x^2*(C+x^2*(D+E*x^2))) 
  % where
  % A = +1.000012594
  % B = +0.4993615349 
  % C = -0.1195159052
  % D = +0.04453994279
  % E = -0.01019210944
  %
  \pgfmath@x-0.01019210944\pgfmath@xa%
  \advance\pgfmath@x0.04453994279pt\relax%
  \pgfmath@x\pgfmath@temp\pgfmath@x%
  \advance\pgfmath@x-0.1195159052pt\relax%
  \pgfmath@x\pgfmath@temp\pgfmath@x%
  \advance\pgfmath@x0.4993615349pt\relax%
  \pgfmath@x\pgfmath@temp\pgfmath@x%
  \advance\pgfmath@x1.000012594pt\relax%
  \ifdim\pgfmath@y<0pt\relax%
  \pgfmath@y-\pgfmath@y%
  \fi%
  \pgfmath@x\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgfmath@y}\pgfmath@x%
  % Invert the scaling factor.
  \pgfmath@tmp@restore\pgfmath@x\c@pgfmath@counta\relax%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  \pgfmath@returnone\pgfmath@x%
  \endgroup%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{veclen(0.00006,0.00005)}
Vector length is: \pgfmathresult

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings, mark = at position .5 with
 {\draw (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt)  (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);}}]    

% wrong 
\draw [postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- ++(146:1) arc (146:157:1) -- (0,0);
%fine
\draw [postaction={decorate}] (2,0) -- ++(146:1.2) arc (146:157:1.2) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: decorated curve]

As can be seen, the accuracy is not great!  However, at that level of precision then it's probably not all that important.  Perhaps a better implementation would be to test if the components of the vector are less than some small number and then simply return the maximum of the two: at that level, the difference between the sup norm and the l^2 norm is not a lot!  (A slightly more sophisticated version would have a switch that returned the sup norm or the l^1 norm depending on whether it was acceptable to underestimate or overestimate.)

Comment: Interesting to know that the problem cab be solved with a  new implementation of the mathematical function `veclen. In my package `tkz-euclide` I use a macro called `\tkzveclen`. I made this macro with `fp` perhaps a solution for me is to make a temporary implementation. The problem is the time of compilation and to be sure there are no bad effects.

Comment: @Altermundus: I would guess that there are many such edge cases that weren't considered in designing the functions.  Clearly some where (such as that the vector might be too long) but I would guess it is impossible to test for everything!  Knowing exactly what to do here would require more knowledge of what actually matters than I have.  For so small a vector, I would be surprised if anyone could tell the difference between the actual length and an approximation so simply adding an escape would seem the simplest implementation.

Comment: @Andrew You can avoid `\let\pgfmath@function@veclen\relax` with `\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}`. The next macro is strange `\def\pgfmathredeclarefunction#1#2{% ...` has only two arguments and makes only `\pgfmath@namedef{pgfmath#1@}{#2}`.

Comment: @Altermundus: maybe I'm reading the manual incorrectly, but I thought that `\pgfmathredeclarefunction` was a way of replacing an existing function with new code _but the same number of arguments_.  But it didn't work so I just hacked it and didn't go looking for an alternative.  Now I look at the code, I can see that you are right.

Comment: @Andrew Perhaps the macro is not very well described in the pgfmanual or perhaps it's a bug in its definition.

Comment: @Altermundus: My money's on the bug, which makes me curious as to whether anyone's ever re-declared a PGF function before!  Clearly the `fixed point arithmetic` stuff does something, but maybe it just uses the `*` form to overwrite the functions.

Comment: @Andrew I try to find some examples of `\pgfmathredeclarefunction` on the net but I found nothing. In  `fixed point arithmetic` you only have for example `\let\pgfmathveclen@=\pgfmathfpveclen@%`

Comment: @Altermundus: We should probably report this as a bug (maybe worth reporting both issues: needed to fix the veclen function for small numbers and the `\pgfmathredeclarefunction` not working).

Comment: The code in the answer contains a typo (\multipy instead of \multiply) this causes undefined control sequences errors under certain circumstances that took me way too long to track down. However I cannot make the edit, because it's only 1 character and stackexchange wont let me.

Comment: @Maeher I'm sorry it took so long to track down, but thanks for commenting.  Can you confirm that I've fixed the typo you found (I'm pretty confident, but always worth getting a second pair of eyes).

Comment: @LoopSpace No worries, I just wanted to spare other people the journey down this particular rabbit hole. (My tikzpeople package uses the redefinition from your answer to avoid the original problem described in this question. Someone reported that tikzpeople broke pgfplots' \addplot3 functionality. The problem could ultimately be traced back to this typo.) Your edit should be correct.

Answer (score 4):

I answer to my question because perhaps it will be useful for someone. It's my first macro with `lualatex` so perhaps I made something very bad. I don't know exactly how to get the result from `luaveclen`,perhaps `tostring` is not necessary. The time of compilation is correct !

```
%!TEX TS-program =  lualatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luatextra}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}   

\begin{document}

\makeatletter     

\def\luaveclen#1#2{
    \directlua{
        x = #1;
        y = #2;
       r=(x*x+y*y)^0.5
       tex.print(tostring(r))}
}  

\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup 
  \edef\pgfmath@tmp{\luaveclen{#1}{#2}}
  \pgfmath@returnone\pgfmath@tmp pt
\endgroup    
}
\makeatother  

\pgfmathparse{veclen(0.00003,0.00004)}
 Vector length is: \pgfmathresult    

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings, mark = at position .5 with
 {\draw (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt)  (2pt,-2pt) -- (-2pt,2pt);}}]    

\draw [postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- ++(146:1) arc (146:157:1) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an _excellent_ use of lualatex.  Maybe one could write an alternative to `\pgfmathparse`: maybe `\luamathparse`.

Comment: A french guy works on this :  `pgfluamath.parser.lua,v 1.5 2011/06/07 08:58:58 cjorssen`. You can find the file in pgf CVS in the directory `luamath` of the librairies. Christophe writes in good TeX  my macros that you can find in `pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex`. My codes are not always fine :(