# Dimension too large for tkzMarkAngle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a tikz beginning.
Here is a figure I am working on. I cannot avoid the "Dimension too large" error.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm,scale=0.75]
    \coordinate [label=below:$O$](O) at (0,0); 
    \coordinate [label=below:$A$](A) at (0,-1); 
    \coordinate [label=below:$D$](D) at (-1.1,-1); 
    \coordinate [label=below:$E$] (E) at (1,-1); 
    \coordinate [label=0:$B$](B) at (15:1); 
    \coordinate [label=180:$C$](C) at (140:1);
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
\draw (C) -- (O) -- (B);
    \draw (C) -- (A) -- (B);
    \draw (D) -- (E);
    \tkzMarkAngle[label=$124^{\circ}$,dist=0.35,arc=l,size=0.2,color=black,fill=none](B,O,C)
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.3,color=black](A,C,O)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I find it works if I change "scale=0.75" to "scale=1". But I want to keep the figure small.

Comment: Since you are producing a standalone file presumably for later inclusion in a document, you can keep `scale=1` in the standalone file and then reduce the dimensions using the argument for `\includegraphics`.

Comment: But then the character size will be too small.

Comment: Nice answer. In my case I had the same problem with `size=0.25` and it got solved by adding the units, i.e., `size=0.25cm`. It does not work in the question's example, but it may help somebody else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem comes from the value used in `size` in the second `\tkzMarkAngle`; increase a little the  value for that option (the error disappears using `0.3099999`, but I used `0.33` in my example):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm,scale=0.75]
    \coordinate [label=below:$O$](O) at (0,0); 
    \coordinate [label=below:$A$](A) at (0,-1); 
    \coordinate [label=below:$D$](D) at (-1.1,-1); 
    \coordinate [label=below:$E$] (E) at (1,-1); 
    \coordinate [label=0:$B$](B) at (15:1); 
    \coordinate [label=180:$C$](C) at (140:1);
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
    \draw (C) -- (O) -- (B);
    \draw (C) -- (A) -- (B);
    \draw (D) -- (E);
    \tkzMarkAngle[label=$124^{\circ}$,dist=0.35,arc=l,size=0.2,color=black,fill=none](B,O,C)
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.33,color=black](A,C,O)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @CYAries I guess that the math parser gets in trouble with `0.3` and the scaling factor (perhaps something gets too close to a value in which some function becomes unbounded in the evaluation of a trigonometric function involved in the calculation of the arc).

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the "decorate" action. I asked a question about this here : [how-to-put-a-mark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20833/how-to-put-a-mark-on-an-arc-tikz-decoration).
If you remove in the file tkz-obj-angles.tex the option `postaction={decorate}` in the next code, you can avoid the error but it's not a fine solution

```
  \path [\tkz@mkcolor,postaction={decorate},/tkzmkangle/.cd,#1]%
(#3)--++(\tkz@dirOne:\tkz@size) arc(\tkz@dirOne:\tkz@dirTwo:\tkz@size)--cycle;
```

I need to modify the macro but I have not yet found the right way to do this.

You have a possibility to avoid the error with different option. I think your options are strange. Why `[x=2cm,y=2cm,scale=0.75]` and not `[x=1.75cm,y=1.75cm]` ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.75cm,y=1.75cm]
    \coordinate [label=below:$O$](O) at (0,0); 
    \coordinate [label=below:$A$](A) at (0,-1); 
    \coordinate [label=below:$D$](D) at (-1.1,-1); 
    \coordinate [label=below:$E$] (E) at (1,-1); 
    \coordinate [label=0:$B$](B) at (15:1); 
    \coordinate [label=180:$C$](C) at (140:1);
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
\draw (C) -- (O) -- (B);
    \draw (C) -- (A) -- (B);
    \draw (D) -- (E);
    \tkzMarkAngle[label=$124^{\circ}$,dist=0.35,arc=l,size=0.2,color=black,fill=none](B,O,C)
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.3,color=black](A,C,O)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]