# Specific compilation Error " Dimension too large!"

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging

When I compile the following document, I get the error

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.22 ...le[arc=l,size=0.30 cm, font=\tiny](m',O,m)

?
```

When I press `H` to get help, I receive the following message

```
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

?
```

How I can solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}%IMPORTANT--recognizes points, lines, circles, etc
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,bending}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}

\tkzDefPoint(1,0){u}
\tkzDefPoint(-2, 1){v} 

\tkzDefLine[bisector](u,O,v) \tkzGetPoint{m}
\tkzDefLine[bisector](m,O,v) \tkzGetPoint{m"}
\tkzDefLine[bisector](u,O,m) \tkzGetPoint{m'}

\tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.30 cm, font=\tiny](m',O,m)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Increase `size=0.3 cm` a little bit. `size=0.31 cm` works. Possible duplicate to: [♦Dimension too large for tkzMarkAngle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161496/124842)