# Problem using Lua instead of xfp

Tags: luatex, tkz-euclide, lua

The initial code is as follows: the idea is to avoid the "dimension too large" error by temporarily modifying the `veclen` macro

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 
%  Schrodinger's cat idea 03/01/20
\makeatletter
\tikzset{xfp/.code={%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup%
    \pgfmath@x##1pt\relax%
    \pgfmath@y##2pt\relax%
    \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{sqrt((\pgf@x)^2+(\pgf@y)^2)}}   
    \pgfmath@returnone\tkz@xfpMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
}}}%
\makeatother
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(2.5,0){N}
  \tkzDefPoint(-4.2,0.5){M}
  \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 30](N)
  \tkzGetPoint{B}
  \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle -50](N)
  \tkzGetPoint{A}
  \tkzInterLC[common=B](M,B)(O,B) \tkzGetFirstPoint{C}
  \tkzInterLC[common=A](M,A)(O,A) \tkzGetFirstPoint{A'}
  \tkzDrawSegments(A,C M,A M,B A,B)
  \tkzDrawCircle(O,N)
% \tkzMarkAngle[mkpos=.2, size=1.2](C,A,M) 
% Latex Error: ./testlua2.tex:32 Dimension too large.
  \begin{scope}[xfp]
    \tkzMarkAngle[mkpos=.2, size=1.2](C,A,M)
  \end{scope}
  \tkzDrawPoints(O, A, B, M, B, C, A')
  \tkzLabelPoints[right](O,A,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above left](M,C)
  \tkzLabelPoint[below left](A'){$A'$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I try to use `lua` like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 
%  Schrodinger's cat idea 03/01/20
\makeatletter
\tikzset{lua/.code={%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup%
 \pgfmath@x##1pt\relax%
 \pgfmath@y##2pt\relax%
 \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
 \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
 \edef\tkz@temp@xa{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@xa}}% \strip@pt ??
 \edef\tkz@temp@ya{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@ya}}%
 \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\directlua{tex.print(math.sqrt((\tkz@temp@xa)^2+(\tkz@temp@ya)^2))}}
% \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{round(\tkz@xfpMathLen,6)}} % with this line I get a result
\pgfmath@returnone\tkz@xfpMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
 }}}%
 \makeatother
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(2.5,0){N}
  \tkzDefPoint(-4.2,0.5){M}
  \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 30](N)
  \tkzGetPoint{B}
  \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle -50](N)
  \tkzGetPoint{A}
  \tkzInterLC[common=B](M,B)(O,B) \tkzGetFirstPoint{C}
  \tkzInterLC[common=A](M,A)(O,A) \tkzGetFirstPoint{A'}
  \tkzDrawSegments(A,C M,A M,B A,B)
  \tkzDrawCircle(O,N)
% \tkzMarkAngle[mkpos=.2, size=1.2](C,A,M) 
% Latex Error: ./testlua2.tex:32 Dimension too large.
  \begin{scope}[lua]
    \tkzMarkAngle[mkpos=.2, size=1.2](C,A,M)
  \end{scope}
  \tkzDrawPoints(O, A, B, M, B, C, A')
  \tkzLabelPoints[right](O,A,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above left](M,C)
  \tkzLabelPoint[below left](A'){$A'$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I get the following error: ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
This error disappears if I use:

```
\edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{round(\tkz@xfpMathLen,6)}}
```

I must admit that I don't understand what is going on.
How to avoid this mistake properly?

In order to convert a dimension into a number I know two methods: `\pgfmath@tonumber` `\strip@pt`. I have tried both without success. I don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: The last computation returns `9.4868329805051e-05`. You have to tell Lua to return a number not in exponential form.

Comment: something like `tex.print(string.format('\@percentchar.12f',math.sqrt(...`  should work (increase the 12 if you need more digits.)

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I had asked how to do it herei [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517820/transform-a-scientific-notation-to-decimal-notation-with-lua) but it is very heavy to use. `tex.print(string.format("\csstring\%f", r))`

Comment: You can always make a wrapper function in Lua. Something like `function print_float(x) tex.print(string.format(...) end` -- side note, to understand what's going on just print out things with e.g. `\typeout` which is sufficient in this case.

Comment: @egreg What is the most effective way to find that the last computation returns 9.4868329805051e-05. i work with the package `trace` but I get too much informations.

Comment: @AlainMatthes I just added `\show\tkz@xfpMathLen` after the `\edef` and kept hitting return until the error showed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the computations returns `9.4868329805051e-05`.

You have to tell Lua to always return numbers not in exponential form (I'm sure there's a way).

In the meantime doing

```
\edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{\directlua{tex.print(math.sqrt((\tkz@temp@xa)^2+(\tkz@temp@ya)^2))}}}
```

works around the issue, because `\fpeval` normalizes the output.

[image]

A possibly better way is to define a macro for “Pythagorean addition”:

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{iftex}

\begin{document} 
%  Schrodinger's cat idea 03/01/20
\makeatletter

\ifluatex
\newcommand{\tkz@pythadd}[2]{%
  \directlua{%
    tex.print(string.format('\@percentchar.12f',math.sqrt((#1)^2+(#2)^2)))%
  }%
}
\else
\newcommand{\tkz@pythadd}[2]{%
  \fpeval{(#1)^2+(#2)^2}%
}
\fi


\tikzset{lua/.code={%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup%
 \pgfmath@x##1pt\relax%
 \pgfmath@y##2pt\relax%
 \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
 \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
 \edef\tkz@temp@xa{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@xa}}% \strip@pt ??
 \edef\tkz@temp@ya{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@ya}}%
 \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\tkz@pythadd{\tkz@temp@xa}{\tkz@temp@ya}}%
% \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{round(\tkz@xfpMathLen,6)}} % with this line I get a result
\pgfmath@returnone\tkz@xfpMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
 }}}%
 \makeatother
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(2.5,0){N}
  \tkzDefPoint(-4.2,0.5){M}
  \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 30](N)
  \tkzGetPoint{B}
  \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle -50](N)
  \tkzGetPoint{A}
  \tkzInterLC[common=B](M,B)(O,B) \tkzGetFirstPoint{C}
  \tkzInterLC[common=A](M,A)(O,A) \tkzGetFirstPoint{A'}
  \tkzDrawSegments(A,C M,A M,B A,B)
  \tkzDrawCircle(O,N)
% \tkzMarkAngle[mkpos=.2, size=1.2](C,A,M) 
% Latex Error: ./testlua2.tex:32 Dimension too large.
  \begin{scope}[lua]
    \tkzMarkAngle[mkpos=.2, size=1.2](C,A,M)
  \end{scope}
  \tkzDrawPoints(O, A, B, M, B, C, A')
  \tkzLabelPoints[right](O,A,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above left](M,C)
  \tkzLabelPoint[below left](A'){$A'$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tanks the code is very clear like this. I have a `lua` option for my package and if it is used then compiling with lualatex is required and I load only the modules written for `lua`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small summary of the different ideas that have been proposed

A) egreg found out where the problem was coming from and a solution based on my workaround

```
\edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{\directlua{tex.print(math.sqrt((\tkz@temp@xa)^2+(\tkz@temp@ya)^2))}}}
```

B) The wrapper function is a nice idea from user202729

```
 \RequirePackage{luacode}

 \begin{luacode}
   function print_decimal(num)
      return tex.print(string.format("\csstring\%f", num))
   end
 \end{luacode}
```

then

```
\tikzset{lua/.code={%
 \pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
 \begingroup%
  \pgfmath@x##1pt\relax%
  \pgfmath@y##2pt\relax%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
  \edef\tkz@temp@xa{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@xa}}% \strip@pt ??
  \edef\tkz@temp@ya{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@ya}}%
  \edef\tkz@tmp{math.sqrt((\tkz@temp@xa)^2+(\tkz@temp@ya)^2)}
  \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\directlua{print_decimal(\tkz@tmp)}}
  \pgfmath@returnone\tkz@xfpMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
}}}%
```

and

```
\begin{scope}[lua]
     \tkzMarkAngle[mkpos=.2, size=1.2](C,A,M)
 \end{scope}
```

C) There are several possibilities to convert a number with an exponential writing to a decimal writing.
Ulrike Fischer proposed

```
tex.print(string.format('\@percentchar.12f',math.sqrt(...
```

I proposed an idea of  Henri Menke with

```
   tex.print(string.format("\csstring\%f",...))
```

Here is !