# how to use a substitute function of veclen temporarily

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

The question comes from this question : [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20833/how-to-put-a-mark-on-an-arc-tikz-decoration)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,xfp}
\usetkzobj{all} % with version 1.16 not necessary with 2.5xx (soon)
\input{mynewmacro}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\angle{5}
\def\r{8cm}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (\angle:\r);
\coordinate (B) at (0:\r);
\foreach \x/\y in {O/A,O/B} {\draw (\x) -- (\y);} 
\tkzMarkAngles(B,O,A)
\end{tikzpicture}

 %\begin{tikzpicture}
 % How to use the original function veclen here ?
 %\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the file mynewmacro.tex

```
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup%
    \pgfmath@x#1pt\relax%
    \pgfmath@y#2pt\relax%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \edef\tkz@temp@a{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@xa}}}
    \edef\tkz@temp@b{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@ya}}}
    \edef\tkz@temp@sum{\fpeval{%
        (\tkz@temp@a*\tkz@temp@a+\tkz@temp@b*\tkz@temp@b)}}
    \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{sqrt(\tkz@temp@sum)}}
    \pgfmath@returnone\tkz@xfpMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother   
\endinput
```

How to use the original function veclen in the second picture ?

Comment: What second picture?

Comment: Can't you just add an option to be put into the `tikzpicture` that load all the `kz-euclide` stuff?

Comment: @egreg  like you want for example the same but something to use  the original `veclen`

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Without my external definition of 'veclen', I get an error. With the method used, the original definition is overwritten. It should be saved, but how? The question is ultimately independent of `tkz-euclide`

Comment: The question is IMHO if one should make changes to the original Ti*k*Z content by just loading a package. I personally would say one shouldn't.

Comment: Is it normal that I get “Undefined control sequence“ for `\tkzMarkAngles`?

Comment: @egreg Sorry I forgot that I use the new version. You need `\usetkzobj{all}`

Comment: And wouldn't it be simpler to just do `\edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{sqrt(\pgf@x^2+\pgf@y^2)}}`? By the way, in the code for the function, you have `%` where they aren't needed and miss them where they are needed.

Comment: Even easier: a single line `\edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{sqrt((#1)^2+(#2)^2)}}` suffices.

Comment: @egreg  Yes I agree with you. it's a traduction from a code with `fp`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I agree with you ! This is why I wanted to use ** temporarily ** this code.

Comment: @egreg  1) I need to use `\pgfmath` because I need to use the parser (p1032 of the pgf manual). 2) I avoided `^` for obscure reasons 3) and finally I think the syntax of `fp` was not very happy. `xfp`  is progress !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to define a key that *locally* installs the `tkz-euclide` stuff that overwrites/redefines original Ti*k*Z content. That way the user can always switch back if they want to.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
% add \usepackage{fp} and define all the lengths (?) like \tkz@temp@a
\makeatletter
\tikzset{use tkz-euclide/.code={\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup%
    \pgfmath@x##1pt\relax%
    \pgfmath@y##2pt\relax%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \edef\tkz@temp@a{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@xa}}}
    \edef\tkz@temp@b{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@ya}}}
    \edef\tkz@temp@sum{\fpeval{%
        (\tkz@temp@a*\tkz@temp@a+\tkz@temp@b*\tkz@temp@b)}}
    \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{sqrt(\tkz@temp@sum)}}
    \pgfmath@returnone\tkz@xfpMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
}
% add all the stuff that redefines original tikz behavior
}}
\makeatother   
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use tkz-euclide]
 \node{here the new \texttt{veclen} is at work};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use tkz-euclide]
 \node{here the original \texttt{veclen} is at work};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Clearly, this is only pseudo-code here since I do not have `\tkz@temp@a` here, and loading `tkz-euclide` will just install the redefined `veclen` globally.

Comment: Firstly thanks! no the new version of `tkz-euclide` does not install `veclen`globally only if the user asks to use the new version. Like in my example , after include{tkz-tool-xfp} the new version is installed globally. I'm stupid for not having thought of this solution.

Answer (score 2):

With the idea from Schrödinger's cat, the problem is resolved.
Below a code without `tkz-euclide`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xfp}

\makeatletter

\tikzset{%
use veclen xfp/.code={%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup%
    \pgfmath@x##1pt\relax%
    \pgfmath@y##2pt\relax%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \edef\tkz@temp@a{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@xa}}}
    \edef\tkz@temp@b{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@ya}}}
    \edef\tkz@temp@sum{\fpeval{(\tkz@temp@a*\tkz@temp@a+\tkz@temp@b*\tkz@temp@b)}}
    \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{sqrt(\tkz@temp@sum)}}
    \pgfmath@returnone\tkz@xfpMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \pgfmathparse{veclen(0.03,0.04)}
     \let\r\pgfmathresult
      \node[draw]  at (0,3) { length is: \r} ;
\begin{scope}[use veclen xfp]
     \pgfmathparse{veclen(0.03,0.04)}
     \let\r\pgfmathresult
     \node[draw] at (0,2) {length is: \r} ;
\end{scope}
   \pgfmathparse{veclen(0.03,0.04)}
   \let\r\pgfmathresult
   \node[draw]  at (0,1) { length is: \r} ;
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Egreg's suggestion is fine :

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup%
    \pgfmath@x##1pt\relax%
    \pgfmath@y##2pt\relax%
    \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{sqrt((\pgf@x)^2+(\pgf@y)^2)}}   
     \pgfmath@returnone\tkz@xfpMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
}
```

[image]