# Plot a loop with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image] I am learning the use of tikz. Your help is very impressive. I have to complete my drawing soon and its gives me difficulty to fix the positions of points from where to start and where to go. Would you suggest me at least one of the two plots at your earliest? I will be much benefited if you kindly help me for this.

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  decorations,
  decorations.markings,
  hobby,
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut, scale=1.5]
     \draw[thick] (0.4, 0) .. (0.8, 0.3) .. (1.0, 0) .. (0.4, 0);
    \draw  (-.3 ,1).. (0, 0) .. ( 1.2 , 0 )
     \draw  (-.3 ,-1).. (0, 0) .. ( 1.2 , 0 ) .. ( 0 , 0 ) ;
     \draw   (.5, 0) .. ( .8 , 0 ) .. ( .6 , 0 ) .. ( .7 , -0.012);
     \draw (-.1, 1)..(-.08, .7)..(-.05, .4)..( .1 , .4 )..( .7 , .6 )..( 1.4 , 0 )..( .7 , -.6 )..( .2 , -.4 )..(-.1,-.5)..(-.11 ,-.8);
    \node[inner sep=1.5pt,circle,fill=red] at  ( .7 , -0.01) {};
    \node[rotate=0] at  ( 1.2 , -0.7) {\scriptsize H};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is for the 2nd.

Comment: You have asked almost the exact same question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159084/plot-using-hobby).

Comment: By puting a grid over those images you can easily see/calculate where the points you are looking for are. **EDIT:** You have one question with an (to my eyes, good) answer which you haven't accepted.

Comment: Dear  Svend Tveskæg, You are right. But still I am unable to draw the figs. Tried a lot but it gives me trouble. I am not very friendly with tikz. I am very much benefited if I get another help. Thanking you a lot.

Comment: Dear  Manuel, Very sorry. Now I have accepted by clicking on the tick sign.

Comment: @user1942348 Post what code you have tried so far and explain why you have problems *fixing the position of the points*. **EDIT:** From `\documentclass…` to `\end{document}`, so we can easily copy-paste it. Why don't you use the method Heiko Oberdiek provided you?

Comment: This is not at all duplicate. I got an answer of different fig which looks same to the fig but these figs are different.