# Many body perturbation diagrams (closed Feynman diagrams) in latex with labelling

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, feynman

I would like to draw many body Feynman diagrams using latex. These are closed and often used in condensed matter and nuclear physics in contrast to the open scattering diagrams in particle physics. For instance I am attaching two examples : (i) A particular Feynman diagram with labelling and (ii) Equations using Feynman diagrams.

(i)
[image]

(ii)
[image]

I hope these are possible using Tikz or PSTricks.

PS. A working example for the first figure is wanted. 
 The second figure could be tedious, so for that a hint may suffice.

Comment: Hint --> Use `feynmp` package with metapost

Comment: Would be nice if a minimal working example is shown, eg. the first figure. 
Hope Tikz/PSTricks option exist as well.

Comment: Nice documentation here with some MWEs: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Feynman_diagrams And there are many examples here, some of them being rather similar to the ones you need - they should be straight forward to modify: http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/fmfsamples.pdf and http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/fmfman.pdf

Comment: see http://ctan.org/pkg/feynman

Comment: @Herbert CTAN refused that due to license problems. I don't have any details for the reason though.

Comment: @percusse: not `CTAN`, but `TeXLive`. It is easy to install that package.

Comment: @Herbert Ha! I need more coffee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a straight-forward `tikz` `decorations` solution:

## (i)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

% particle decorations borrowed from: Kjell Magne Fauske
% http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feynman-diagram/
\tikzset{
    every node/.append style={font=\small},
    every edge/.append style={thick},
    arrow/.style={thick, shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,->},
    photon/.style={decorate, decoration={snake}},
    electron/.style={postaction={decorate},
        decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with {\arrow[]{>}}}},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{scope}[scale=2]
      % coordinates
      \coordinate (in) at (-.5,0);
      \coordinate (out) at (1.5,0);
      \fill (0,0) circle (1pt) coordinate (lb);
      \fill (0,1) circle (1pt) coordinate (lt);
      \fill (1,0) circle (1pt) coordinate (rb);
      \fill (1,1) circle (1pt) coordinate (rt);

      % edges
      \draw (lb) edge[electron] node[below] {$i\omega_n+i\nu_m$} (rb);
      \draw (lt) edge[electron,out=45,in=135] node[above] {$i\omega_p+i\nu_m$} (rt);
      \draw (rt) edge[electron,out=-135,in=-45] node[below] {$i\omega_n$} (lt);
      \draw (lb) edge[photon] node[left] {$i\nu_m$} (lt);
      \draw (rt) edge[photon] node[right] {$i\nu_m$} (rb);

      % arrows
      \draw[arrow] (in) -- (lb);
      \draw[arrow] (rb) -- (out);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Another example, using `tikz-cd`:

## (ii)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    every node/.append style={font=\small},
    every edge/.append style={thick},
    b/.style={bend right=45},
    photon/.style={decorate, decoration={snake,segment length=8pt,amplitude=2pt}},
    electron/.style={postaction={decorate},
        decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with {\arrow[]{>}}}},
}

\tikzcdset{diagrams={nodes={inner sep=0pt}},every arrow/.append style={dash},
    cells={nodes={circle,radius=1pt,very thin,draw,fill,align=center,inner sep=0pt}}}

\begin{tikzcd}
    \arrow[rr,photon] & & \ar[d,electron,b] \\
    & \arrow[r,photon] \ar[d,electron,b] & \ar[u,electron,b] \\
    \arrow[r,photon] \ar[uu,electron] & \ar[u,electron,b] &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

## (ii)...

You can also nest several diagrams within a `tikzpicture` and draw additional nodes and lines around them:

[image]

The diagrams are positioned using the `tikz` `chains` library:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  every node/.append style={font=\small},
  every edge/.append style={thick},
  b/.style={bend right=45},
  photon/.style={decorate, decoration={snake,segment length=8pt,amplitude=2pt}},
  electron/.style={postaction={decorate},
    decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with {\arrow[]{>}}}},
}

\tikzcdset{diagrams={nodes={inner sep=0pt}},every arrow/.append style={dash},
  cells={nodes={circle,radius=1pt,very thin,draw,fill,align=center,inner sep=0pt}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain,
  node distance=1mm, 
  diag/.style={on chain},
  +/.style={diag},
  con/.style={red,thin,->}
  ]
  % joined diagrams
  \node [diag] {
    \begin{tikzcd}
       \ar[r,photon] & \ar[d,electron,b] \\
       \ar[r,photon] \ar[u,electron] & \ar[u,electron,b]
    \end{tikzcd}
  };
  \node [+] {$+$};
  \node [diag] {
    \begin{tikzcd}
        \ar[rr,photon] & & \ar[d,electron,b] \\
        & \ar[r,photon] \ar[d,electron,b] & \ar[u,electron,b] \\
        \ar[r,photon] \ar[uu,electron] & \ar[u,electron,b] &
    \end{tikzcd}
  };
  \node [+] {$+$};
  \node [diag] {
    \begin{tikzcd}
       \ar[rrr,photon] & & & \ar[d,electron,b] \\
       & & \ar[r,photon] \ar[d,electron,b] & \ar[u,electron,b] \\
       & \ar[r,photon] \ar[d,electron,b] & \ar[u,electron,b] & \\
       \ar[r,photon] \ar[uuu,electron] & \ar[u,electron,b] & &
    \end{tikzcd}
  };
  \node [+] {$+\cdots$};
  % labels
  \node [red,yshift=1.5cm] (rpa) at (chain-3.north) {RPA};
  \draw (rpa) edge[out=180,in=90,con] (chain-1);
  \draw (rpa) edge[con] (chain-3);
  \draw (rpa) edge[out=0,in=90,con] (chain-5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thnks @sergej. So I may not need to install any extra package. Could you attempt a higher order diagram or can we make a bubble as one unit and produce higher orders?

Comment: @hbaromega I have added an example showing the nesting of diagrams within a `tikzpicture`.

Comment: While compiling for the second example, somehow I'm getting an error message saying `I can't find file `tikzlibrarycd.code.tex'.` But I think, `cd` is already there in my tikz libraries. And also why do the wiggly lines become different here. Can we make further variations, say more like saw-tooth wave?

Comment: @hbaromega Seems like `tikz-cd` is not installed, you should update your `TeX` installation. The style of the wiggly lines is controlled by `photon/.style={decorate, ...`, you can adopt it to your needs. See the `tikz` manual for other decoration styles.

Comment: sorry, I would like to reverse the directions of the arrows in the first diagram (i.e. rightward one should head towards left and vice-versa), but not being able to get (I interchanged angles, but no success). Can you help?

Comment: like [this](http://imgur.com/Hy480Ol)?

Comment: No no, all the arrows have to get reversed, importantly the ones inside the bubble.

Comment: like [that](http://imgur.com/bjiQjnB)?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.

Comment: @hbaromega That's easy: `arrow/.style={thick, shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,<-},` and `decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with {\arrow[]{<}}}},`

Comment: I probably meant [this](http://imgur.com/MI7BEZ8). Do I need to define two arrows, say `arrow1` and `arrow2`?

Comment: @hbaromega see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4404/tikz-multiple-decorations-on-a-path)