# Is it possible to apply two pathmorphing/pathreplacing decorations in succession?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, decorations, pgf-decorations

Suppose one wants to achieve the following:
[image: Goal: Two pathmorphing/pathreplacing decorations in succession]

### Current Status

Based upon [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4404/tikz-multiple-decorations-on-a-path), I was able to create a "MWE" of how I would like this to work:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.pathreplacing}

\def\width{5mm}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{make wide}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[width=1pt]
    {
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.5*\width}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{-0.5*\width}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5*\width}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{0.5*\width}}
    }
    \state{final}
    {
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5*\width}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{0.5*\width}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.5*\width}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{-0.5*\width}}
    }
}

\tikzstyle{make wide and ticks} = [
    decoration={make wide},
    decorate,
    postaction={
        decoration={ticks},
        decorate
    }
]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[make wide and ticks](0,0)to[out=0, in=180](5,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the output is:
[image: MWE: Resulting Output]

To rule out any weird order of execution issues that I previously encountered with `tikzstyle`, I also tried it without defining a `tikzstyle` with the same result (just like one would expect).
From my understanding of the implementation of `postaction`, it is not possible to to use every `decoration` within the `postaction` phase.

### Questions:

1. Is there a way to achieve the desired output with `decoration`s?
2. Is there another simple way that also works for arbitrary shaped paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The solution is realized in two steps:

1. points characterizing a certain tubular neighborhood of the path are constructed through a decoration `towards tubular` which takes two arguments (step and distance from the path that are taken in `pt`)
2. the two corresponding paths of the tubular neighborhood are constructed and decorated with the predefined decoration `ticks` through the commands `L ticks` and `R ticks` (left and right tubular borders).

Note, in the first drawing of the above figure, that there is a problem with the last tick of the decoration; it does not "cover" the last part of the initial path (drawn in black).  For this reason, some "tail" is added and then the decoration `towards tubular` is invoked (see the middle drawing).  The tail is added through the option `e`.

I hope that the last drawing approaches what you are looking for.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  e/.style={% step length -- in points
    % needed for the last tick of open curves
    insert path={-- ([turn]0: #1pt)}
  },
  towards tubular/.style 2 args={% step length, width -- in points
    % create the points describing the tubular neighborhood
    decoration={markings,
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step #1pt with {
        \tikzmath{%
          integer \pNumber;
          \pNumber = \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark
            info/sequence number};
        }
        \pgfextra{\xdef\pNumber{\pNumber}}
        \path (0, #2pt) coordinate (TL-\pNumber);
        \path (0, -#2pt) coordinate (TR-\pNumber);
      }
    },
    postaction=decorate
  },
  L ticks/.style 2 args={% step length, tick length -- in points
    decorate,
    decoration={ticks, segment length=#1pt, amplitude=#2pt},
    insert path={%
      (TL-1) \foreach \i in {2, ..., \pNumber}{-- (TL-\i)}
    }
  },
  R ticks/.style 2 args={% step length, tick length -- in points
    decorate,
    decoration={ticks, segment length=#1pt, amplitude=#2pt},
    insert path={%
      (TR-1) \foreach \i in {2, ..., \pNumber}{-- (TR-\i)}
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines, opacity=.3] (-4, -3) grid (4, 4);

  % first drawing
  \draw[towards tubular={3}{6}]
  (-3, -2.5) .. controls ++(30:5) and ++(210:3) .. ++(-1, 6);
  \draw[blue, L ticks={4}{2}];
  \draw[red, R ticks={4}{2}];

  % second drawing
  \path[towards tubular={6}{6}]
  (0, -2.5) .. controls ++(30:5) and ++(210:3) .. ++(-1, 6) [e=5];
  \draw
  (0, -2.5) .. controls ++(30:5) and ++(210:3) .. ++(-1, 6);
  \draw[blue, L ticks={4}{2}];
  \draw[red, R ticks={4}{2}];

  % third drawing
  \path[towards tubular={3}{6}]
  (3, -2.5) .. controls ++(30:5) and ++(210:3) .. ++(-1, 6) [e=3];
  \draw[blue, L ticks={4}{2}];
  \draw[red, R ticks={4}{2}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution does almost what I need; I can easily adapt it to my case specific needs. As an added bonus, your suggestion contains an interesting approach using `e/.style` to fix path length issues, which I had also some struggles with and now was answered before even asking :-)