# Tikz style conflicting with clip command

Tags: tikz-styles

Below is my example. I'd like to use a global style for all my tikz pictures to set up the line width. It is working well until I use a `clip`. I guess that it is not possible to pass some style option to `clip`. The code below gives the error msg

```
Package tikz Error: Extra options not allowed for clipping path command. \clip (2,0) circle (2cm);
```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every path/.style={line width=2pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (2,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4907/is-it-possible-to-clear-tikz-pgf-options

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Here are three solutions.*

1) If you necessarily need `every path/.style`, choose this [excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4912/14500) from [Matthew Leingang](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1402) (but the TeX group around `\clip` prevents the propagation of the *bounding box*):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{every path/.style={draw=blue,line width=2pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  {
    \tikzset{every path/.style={}}
    \clip (2,0) circle (2cm);
  }
  \draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

2) Most of the time, you can avoid to use `every path/.style`. Here, you can use `every picture/.style` instead of `every path/.style`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=2pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (2,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

3) The third solution redefines the `clip` option :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{clip/.code={%
    \let\tikz@mode=\pgfutil@empty%
    \let\tikz@preactions=\pgfutil@empty%
    \let\tikz@postactions=\pgfutil@empty%
    \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
    \tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@cliptrue}%
  },
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{every path/.style={line width=2pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (2,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, if you’re proposing the second solution, do `\tikzset{clip/.code={\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@cliptrue}\let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty}}` and you can use the original `\path[clip]` and `\clip`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for your suggestion: I edited my answer.

Comment: Of these three, Matthew's is the most reliable and robust.  It really should  be the first version given.

Comment: @AndrewStacey The first solution is simpler: `every picture` can replace `every path` in the majority of cases!

Comment: Disagree.  In *simple* cases, maybe, but it's not difficult to come up with examples where the behaviour is radically different.  `every scope` comes in between, for example.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I misspoke: Most of the time, you can avoid using `every path` (replacing it by `every picture`,  `every scope`, or global options for example). For the current question, the solution is `every picture`.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I edited my answer...

Comment: @AndrewStacey Matthews's solution prevents the correct calculation of the bounding box....

Comment: @PaulGaborit The bounding box issue is, in my view, a bug in how clip interacts with subsequent bounding box calculations (it is confined to the group, not the scope).  I've edited some fixes into Matthew's solution.

Answer (score 5):

This is a crude method. Instead of changing the `path` style, you can define a `my path` and use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{my path/.style={line width=2pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (2,0) circle (2cm);
\draw [my path] (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or define `tikzset` after `clip` (if needed put it inside a `scope`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (2,0) circle (2cm);
\begin{scope}
\tikzset{every path/.style={line width=2pt}}
\draw  (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But with you suggestion I would have to use the `my style` on every picture. I'd like to set up global line width to change on the whole document.

Comment: @Sigur Unfortunately yes. But second option is somewhat less brutal. For using it globally, one has to patch the `\clip` command. Let us wait for tikz gurus. `:-)`