# "\clip" conflict with "every path" in tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want `every draw` in `magenta` and `every` text in `blue`. Without `\clip` the following MWE does not produce any error.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
every path/.style={magenta,text=blue}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \filldraw (-3,0)--(1,1)--(3,-2)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But it does with the present of `\clip`. Is there any approach of avoiding putting style on each `\draw`?

Comment: "But it does [produce an error] with [..] `\clip`" Which one exactly?

Comment: See [Is it possible to clear tikz/pgf options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4912/150114)

Comment: SayOL, the accepted answer to the question linkedby @javi_gg1 above should fix it.