# Where do I find the pgf manual v2.00?

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation

This might be a very stupid question, but I don't manage to find the pgf manual `v2.00`. On CTAN I only found `v2.10`. (I'd like to find it because I want to follow Andrew's comment to [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/applying-a-postaction-to-every-path-in-tikz/5354#5354).)

Comment: If you want the concordance, Andrew's referring to the PGF Key Management Utility which is described in Chapter 55 of the 2.10 manual.  Key handlers such as `.code` are in Section 55.4.

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks for the references, but I also wanted the full 2.00 manual.

Comment: don't you already have it on your system (`texdoc pgfmanual`)?  Surely, you should read the version of the manual directly relevant to the version that you have?  (And I should have put the section number in my comment as being a better reference.)

Comment: @Andrew: I have both a very old version (by an administrator globally) and version 2.10 (by myself locally) installed. I wanted to have a look at the example for the `.store in` handler that you mentioned, and could more easily find this in the 2.00 manual. Moreover, I wanted to have a look at changes as there is this question about the bug in 2.10.

Comment: fair enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way is to use the TeX Live SVN repo: the root of the trees is at http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/. Then you append the location of the pgf manual: `texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf` (using `texdoc -l pgf` will show you that the file is there), and click the `pgfmanual.pdf` link to see the list of revisions. Finally, use the "download" link for the revision you want: here the final url is http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=6741.

This works fine for files whose location doesn't change too often.

Comment: Thanks; this is a nice option since I can find different versions at the same spot.

Answer (score 2):

You can get old versions of pgf at [the pgf sourceforge site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/). The manual should be bundled with the rest of the files.

Comment: Thanks! Not the most convenient way to obtain the manual, but I did succeed to find it in the tarball.