# Label plots in pgfplots without entering coordinates manually

Tags: pgfplots

I like to label my plots directly, i.e. without using a legend, but instead using a `pin` node. So far, I have added the labels with manually specified coordinates, which means trial-and-error for data plots. A better way would be to let `TikZ` handle the positioning, but I don't know how to access the paths of the plots. Is there a way of adding a node to a plot in `pgfplots`, similar to the `[pos=0.5]` option for normal paths? Just adding `node [pos=0.5] {x}` to the `\addplot` command does not position the node on the line, but instead at some location in the lower left of the plot area, regardless of the `pos` value.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2} node [pos=0.75,pin={-10:$x^2$},inner sep=0pt] {}; % This does not position the node on the line
\addplot {1.5*x^2};
\node at (axis cs:4,16) [pin={-10:$x^2$},inner sep=0pt] {}; % This is what I want, but without calculating the coordinates by hand
\node at (axis cs:4,24) [pin={170:$1.5 x^2$},inner sep=0pt] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots plot with nodes annotating the lines]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The current version of pgfplots (>= 1.5.1) supports this as you expected it in the first place (i.e. using `node[pos=0.75]`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2} node [pos=0.75,pin={-10:$x^2$},inner sep=0pt] {};
\addplot {1.5*x^2} node [pos=0.75,pin={170:$1.5 x^2$},inner sep=0pt] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis on top=true,
        xmin=-7,
        xmax=7,
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=4,
        clip=false
] 

\addplot[
    mark=none,
    domain=-4:6,
    samples=80,
    red,
    thick,
] {(x<-2)*-2 + (!(x<-2) && (x<3))*x + (!(x<3)) * 3}
    node[pos=0.1,pin=135:{\color{purple}$f(x)=-2$}] {}
    node[pos=0.6,pin=135:{\color{blue}$f(x)=x$}] {}
    node[pos=0.9,pin=135:{\color{green!70!black}$f(x)=3$}] {}
;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It is available for download on http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Just discovered: `pos=...` does not work correctly if coordinates are read from an unsorted table, e.g. if `x = {3 4 5 1 2}` (sort of...). You'll have to sort the table first.

Comment: @Christoph from what I understand, a plot with the provided coordinates is completely different from one with sorted coords. I would say it is expected behavior that they look different... if you think it is an error, I would be interested in a complete bug report.

Comment: @Christian "does not work correctly" was probably a bad choice of words. The pos option can simply not be used for unsorted data in order to place something along the path without some trial and error. It's not a bug.

Answer (score 18):

I'm very keen on seeing other people's approaches to this, but in the meantime I'll post what I came up with:

The following code defines a new `tikzstyle` that creates a vertical path at a specified position in the plot, intersects that line with the plot, and adds something like a glorified `pin` (actually a line with a `label` at the end, which gives finer control over the text placement than just a `pin`) at the intersection.

It takes three arguments:

- The position of the vertical line, specified as a fraction of the plot width (0 is the left edge, 1 the right)
- The position of the label relative to the intersection of the line and plot. It can be given as polar coordinates (`{45:1cm}`) or a relative coordinate (`{0.4cm,2cm}`) and has to be enclosed in curly braces.
- The label text, or, more accurately the `label` code: Either just the text, or something like `{[red]left:<text>}` to position the label to the left of the end of the label line and colour it red.

It's not exactly what I asked for, in that it does not position the label at a given distance along the graph, but rather at a fixed horizontal distance along the plot canvas. I find this to be more of a feature than a shortcoming, though, because it allows for nice alignments of the labels. Using other paths for defining the intersections, like horizontal lines or circles instead of the vertical line, is easily possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/linelabel/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{name path global=labelpath,execute at end plot={
\path [name path global = labelpositionline]
(rel axis cs:#1,0) --
(rel axis cs:#1,1);
\draw [help lines,text=black,inner sep=0pt,name intersections={of=labelpath and labelpositionline}] (intersection-1) -- +(#2) node [label={#3}] {};},
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot +[linelabel=0.8:{-45:0.75cm}:{[blue]right:$x^2$}] {x^2};
\addplot +[linelabel=0.8:{-.6cm,.6cm}:$1.5x^2$] {1.5*x^2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**A way of placing labels at a specified position along the plot path**, based on the answer to [How determine slope of straight line (with auto scale of axis) in PGF plots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22582/how-determine-slope-of-straight-line-with-auto-scale-of-axis-in-pgf-plots/22588#22588)

Alternatively, a decoration can be used to place label nodes. The `decorations.markings` library allows to place a node somewhere along a path. To use the decoration in `\addplot`, it has to be applied it through an `every path/.style`, which leads to a problem with the decoration being applied to itself. Thankfully, this has been solved already: [Applying a postaction to every path in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/applying-a-postaction-to-every-path-in-tikz/5354#5354).

Also, PGFplots seems to have a problem with using TikZ nodes in the decorations. This can be avoided by using `\pgfnode` instead, which does exactly the same as `\node`, but looks a bit unusual.

Here's an example where a `plotlabel` style is defined (based on Altermundus' idea in [How to label a path drawn using tikz with \draw plot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21537/how-to-label-a-path-drawn-using-tikz-with-draw-plot/21540#21540), and adapted to work around the described problems). You specify the label with `plotlabel={<rel pos along path>}{<label text>}`. To change the color of the label, `\color{<color name>}<label text>` can be used. The `plotlabel` option can be used multiple times to add different labels to the same plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    nomorepostaction/.code={\let\tikz@postactions\pgfutil@empty},
    plotlabel/.style 2 args={
        every path/.append style={
            postaction={
                nomorepostaction,
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=at position #1 with {
                        \pgftransformresetnontranslations
           \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
           \pgfsetstrokecolor{black}
           \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
           \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.3cm}{0.6cm}}
           \pgfusepath{stroke}
           \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-0.3cm}{0.6cm}}
                        \pgfnode{rectangle}{east}{#2}{}{}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis on top=true,
        xmin=-7,
        xmax=7,
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=4,
        clip=false
] 

\addplot[
    mark=none,
    domain=-4:6,
    samples=80,
    red,
    thick,
    plotlabel={0.1}{\color{purple}$f(x)=-2$},
    plotlabel={0.6}{\color{blue}$f(x)=x$},
    plotlabel={0.9}{\color{green!70!black}$f(x)=3$}
] {(x<-2)*-2 + (!(x<-2) && (x<3))*x + (!(x<3)) * 3};%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot with label]