# How to put a label to a /draw plot command in TikZ correctly?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw some interpolation curves and came across the following command

```
\draw plot[smooth] coordinates {(1,1) (4,8) (6,3) (8,9)};
```

That seems quite nice. Now I wanted to add some labels and found some information [here (Labeling a function's plot generated by “plot function”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41237/labeling-a-functions-plot-generated-by-plot-function) and [here (How to label a path drawn using tikz with \draw plot?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21537/how-to-label-a-path-drawn-using-tikz-with-draw-plot)

Now my solution looks like:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[label/.style={postaction={decorate,
     transform shape,
     decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with \node #1;}}}]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,10);
  \draw[->,label={[above]{1}}] plot[smooth] coordinates {(1,1) (4,8) (6,3) (8,9)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Everything seems to work, but at one point I get an error I can't understand or solve. If I change `mark=at position` to a value less than `0.4` it still produces the desired output, but gives me the following error messange.

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.10 ...th] coordinates {(1,1) (4,8) (6,3) (8,9)};

! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@x 

l.10 ...th] coordinates {(1,1) (4,8) (6,3) (8,9)};

! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.10 ...th] coordinates {(1,1) (4,8) (6,3) (8,9)};
```

Any ideas what's going on there or how to solve it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are looking for plotting alternatives, how about package `pgfplots`?

Comment: BTW; Your example runs fine on my machine, maybe you jusst need an update. You can list all used files by putting `\listfiles` in your very first line, and have a look into the log file afterwards. The recent version of tikz/pgf is 3.0

Comment: It compiles fine on my machine too (also for `pos=0.9`).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Does it also compile for `pos=0.2`?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I updated to version 3.0, but there is still the error when compiling with `pos=0.2`

Comment: @stephanboehme Yes. I can confirm the problem for `position=<value>` for any non negative `<value>` less than `0.39` (using version 3.0 of PGF).

Comment: There is some conflict between `smooth` and `decorate`. You have two options (as work around): put another point close to `(1,1)` or remove `smooth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conflict between `smooth` and decorations has already appeared here; the most recent example is [Add arrows to a smooth tikz function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163689/3954). In your concrete case, a work-around to prevent the "Dimension too large" error allowing you to still use `smooth`, is to use `pre length=1pt, post length=1pt` in the decoration. For the example below I changed to a style with two argument so as to be able to control the location of the decoration, but you can use your original settings:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
label/.style 2 args={
  postaction={
    decorate,
    transform shape,
    decoration={
      pre length=1pt, post length=1pt,
      markings,
      mark=at position #1 with \node #2;
      }
  }
}  
]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,10);
\draw[->] plot[smooth] coordinates {(1,1) (4,8) (6,3) (8,9)} [
  label={0}{[above]{1}},
  label={0.05}{[above]{1}},
  label={0.1}{[above]{1}},
  label={0.15}{[above]{1}},
  label={0.2}{[above]{1}},
  label={1.25}{[above]{1}}
  ];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]