# Add arrows to a smooth tikz function

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using this answer here I have been able to draw smooth curves using tikz
[Easy curves in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz)
but I also wanted arrows along my curves, after a bit of fiddling I came up with
the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\input{arrowsnew}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{arrow data/.style 2 args={%
      decoration={%
         markings,
         mark=at position #1 with \arrow{#2}},
         postaction=decorate}
      }%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
\node[label=below:$A$] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[label=below:$B$] (B) at (2,0.25){};
\draw [red,arrow data={0.25}{stealth},
           arrow data={0.5}{stealth},
           arrow data={0.75}{stealth}] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(A) (1,0) (1.14,-0.6) (0.5,-0.5) (0.5,0.5) (1.5,0) (B)};
\draw [black] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(A) (1,0) (1.14,-0.6) (0.5,-0.5) (0.5,0.5) (1.5,0) (B)};
\end{scope}
\draw [fill=black] (A) circle (1pt);
\draw [fill=black] (B) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This seems somewhat hacky and I am looking for a solution improving a few parts about the code. Optimally I would like

- *that the arrow scales along with the scaling of the figure (or specify size, not really wanted).*
- *different colors for the curve and the arrow heads. Something along the lines of*
  `\draw[color = black,arrow color = red,...]`
- *to specify number of arrows along the curve OR use the number of points.
  Eg* `\draw[arrow number=10]` and `\draw[arrow number=points]`

For the colors I used the same plot function twice, ugh. Optimally the arrows should be in front of the figure and not behind. 
I have seen a post about scaling arrow heads, for an example 
[Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf)
but I was not able to implement the solution... Adding arrowhead=10mm to the `\draw`
command did nothing. I also found a question regarding several arrows along a curve 
deppendant on the number of points, [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line)
However this is using the `\path` option in tikz instead of `\plot` as I am using. 
Blindly implementing the solution Latex decided to throw me a couple of `dimensions to large` errors, so I guess one has to use a bit more finesse to implement this.

Any help or ideas for implementing the bulleted items would be much appreaciated. I really tried solving these issues on my own, but my tikz abilities are somewhat limited.

Comment: Related: Qrrbrbirlbels answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131325/10995

Comment: With `TiKZ 3.0` and its `arrows.meta` library, arrow size is proportional to line thickness, you can define tip color different form line color, ... (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161238/1952)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adapting Qrrbrbirlbels answer from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131325/10995

You will want to use it like

```
\draw plot ... [arrow inside={end=stealth,opt={scale=2}}{0.25,0.5,0.75}];
```

It is important, to place it **after** the plot part, because else you will get `Dimension too large` errors, which emerge from an incompatibility between `smooth` and `decorate`. The first argument of `arrow inside` accepts the keys `end` and `opt`; in `end=...` you put the arrow tip, in `opt={...}` you can put any arrow tip options. The second argument to `arrow inside` is a list of positions between `0` and `1` where you want the markings to be placed.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    set arrow inside/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/arrow inside}{#1}},
    set arrow inside={end/.initial=>, opt/.initial=},
    /pgf/decoration/Mark/.style={
        mark/.expanded=at position #1 with
        {
            \noexpand\arrow[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/opt}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/end}}
        }
    },
    arrow inside/.style 2 args={
        set arrow inside={#1},
        postaction={
            decorate,decoration={
                markings,Mark/.list={#2}
            }
        }
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[scale=2]
        \node[label=below:$A$] (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node[label=below:$B$] (B) at (2,0.25){};
        \draw[blue] plot [smooth,tension=1]
        coordinates {(A) (1,0) (1.14,-0.6) (0.5,-0.5) (0.5,0.5) (1.5,0) (B)}
        [arrow inside={end=stealth,opt={red,scale=2}}{0.25,0.5,0.75}];
    \end{scope}
    \draw [fill=black] (A) circle (1pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (B) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

---

Alternatively you can draw an arrow at the end of each line segment using the `on each segment` style as defined here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69225/10995

You need the `bending` library (from TikZ 3.0.0) to use the `[bend]` option for the arrows, because else the arrow will modify the path's tension such that the original path and the path redrawn using `on each segment` will visibly differ. Of course you still apply color, etc. to the arrows. It seems, though, that `scale` is not possible.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,bending}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    on each segment/.style={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            moveto code={},
            lineto code={
                \path [#1]
                (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            curveto code={
                \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
                .. controls
                (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
                ..
                (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            closepath code={
                \path [#1]
                (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
        },
    },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\clearpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[scale=2]
        \node[label=below:$A$] (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node[label=below:$B$] (B) at (2,0.25){};
        \draw[blue] plot [smooth,tension=1]
        coordinates {(A) (1,0) (1.14,-0.6) (0.5,-0.5) (0.5,0.5) (1.5,0) (B)}
        [postaction={on each segment={draw,-{stealth[red,bend]}}}];
    \end{scope}
    \draw [fill=black] (A) circle (1pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (B) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! This solves one of my three problems, really nice (+1)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Really? Which problems are still open? I thought, I solved them all.

Comment: Ah you edited your post! Sneaky man ^^ 

One still has to specify the placement of the arrows. Is it possible to instead specify how many one wants? If I want 
`n` arrows the placement of them should be `i/(n+1)` where `i` ranges from `1` to `n`. I tried to impliment this with a loop 
http://pastebin.com/hG1GnNES
However if i try to replace `{0.25, 0.5, 0.75}` with `{\arrowN{3}}` I get the following error 

`! Use of \@undeclaredcolor doesn't match its definition.\kernel@ifnextchar ...rved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f... ...={end=stealth,opt={scale=2}}{\arrowN{3}}];`

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I don't think, that this is possible with the current solution, because the list needs to be expanded before it can be passed to `arrow inside` (for reference try passing `\xyz` as second argument, where `\def\xyz{0.25,0.5,0.75}`). It might be possible with plastering the code with `\expandafter`s.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I added a solution, which uses the plot coordinates to draw the arrows.

Comment: @HenriMenke is there any way to choose the direction of the arrows? Also, when plotting more than one curve on a tikz image is there any way to remove the dimension too large errors?