# Tikz: Is there a shortcut for drawing a polygon with many coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

In `tkz-euclide` there is a shortcut:

```
\tkzDrawPolygon(A1,A...,A13)
```

Is there something similar in plain `tikz-pgf`? I'm looking for a shortcut for the following:

```
\draw (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4) -- (A5) -- (A5) -- (A6) -- (A7) -- (A8) -- (A9) -- (A10) -- (A11) -- (A12) -- (A13) -- cycle;
```

Comment: Sure, `\draw plot[samples at={1,...,13}] (A\x);` or `\draw plot[samples at={1,...,13}] (A\x) -- cycle;`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given a set of coordinates `(A1)`, `(A2)`, ... `(A<n>)`, we can draw the polygon through them via

```
 \draw plot[samples at={1,...,<n>}] (A\x) -- cycle;
```

which is only slightly longer than the `tkz-euclide` syntax.

Since there is no MWE, I had to create some nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path foreach \X in {1,...,13} {(360*\X/14:2+rnd) coordinate (A\X)};
 \draw plot[samples at={1,...,13}] (A\x) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can, of course, also change the plot handler, e.g.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path foreach \X in {1,...,13} {(360*\X/14:2+rnd) coordinate (A\X)};
 \draw plot[smooth cycle,samples at={1,...,13}] (A\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As usual, you can define styles for this. Here is a style `polygon through` which produces the above polygon with

```
\draw[polygon through={A1,A...,A13}];
```

One can then use several of those in a path, e.g.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[polygon through/.style={insert path={
    plot[samples at={#1}] (\x) -- cycle}}]
 \path foreach \X in {1,...,13} {(360*\X/14:3+rnd) coordinate (A\X)
 (360*\X/14:1.5+rnd) coordinate (B\X)};
 \fill[even odd rule,blue,
    polygon through={A1,A...,A13},polygon through={B1,B...,B13}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "it is perhaps a bit easier to add the usual keys to \draw such as `colors, decorate, save path and so on`"  ? Yes and No: Yes currently there's a slight problem with "decorate" but no with `color, save path`. With the next version, for this macro I was able to authorize the use of decorate. I'll try to generalize to the other macros.

Comment: @AlainMatthes Thanks for letting me know! Can you also just append stuff to the path in the macro, to get the same effect as e.g. `\draw[fill=blue,even odd rule] plot[smooth cycle,samples at={1,...,13}] (A\x) (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];`? (Thinking loudly, the answer is probably yes, at least `insert path` should work.)

Answer (score 5):

Behind tkz-euclide there is TikZ. You can recreate the same macro

```
\def\tkzDrawPolygon[#1](#2,#3){%
 \begingroup
 \draw[#1] (#2)
     \foreach \pt in {#2,#3}{--(\pt)}--cycle;
 \endgroup
} 

\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path foreach \X in {1,...,13} {(360*\X/14:2+rnd) coordinate (A\X)};
  \draw[thick,blue] (A1) foreach \pt in {A1,A...,A13} {--(\pt)} --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a suspicion why decorations may not work: in `\def\tkzDrawPolygon[#1](#2,#3){%
 \begingroup
 \draw[#1] (#2)
     \foreach \pt in {#2,#3}{--(\pt)}--cycle;
 \endgroup
} ` you plot the point `#2` twice, so you have a segment of length 0, which decorations often do not like.

Comment: Yes you are right ! It’s why I used another définition of the macro !

Comment: ;-) BTW, I found (more or less empirically) that many of the `dimension too large` errors in decorations come from the built in reciprocal. If you replace that by an `fpu` variant, say, these errors are gone, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540276/194703) for a concrete example. Since you are improving several functions in `tkz-euclide`, one may think of providing the user with  a switch that allows them to get rid of some of these unnecessary errors.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Very fine answer ! I like the `polygon through/.style`. Yes I agree with you about the use of `flu`. I'm already using it.

Comment: Yes, an ordinary `flu` is less dangerous than this virus...

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  Coincidence does the trick.:)

Answer (score 3):

Probably less elegant than [Schrödinger's cat's technique](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541178/73317), here is another one based on `expl3`'s `\int_step_function:nnN` (it is “restricted expandable,” which is enough here).

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \intstepfunction \int_step_function:nnN
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Define some coordinates
  \foreach \i in {1,...,13} {
    \coordinate (A\i) at (360/13*\i:3);
  }

  % Use them in the prescribed way
  \def\tmp#1{-- (A#1)}
  \draw[blue] (A1) \intstepfunction{2}{13}{\tmp} --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, regular polygons can be drawn using the `shapes.geometric` Ti*k*Z library:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=13, draw=blue,
      inner sep=3cm] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]