# Label Tikz Paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a simple neural network structure and have the following:

```
\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,draw=black!80,thick,minimum size=17pt,inner
        sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {$x_\y$};

    \node[neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:$h_\theta(x)$}, right of=H-2] (O) {};

    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \path (H-\source) edge (O);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which, when rendered, produces the following:

[image]

I want to be able to label the `\path`, but [everywhere I've looked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279275/how-to-label-paths-in-tikz) talks only about labeling a `\draw` or `\node`. I thought I should be able to add:

```
\path (H-\source) edge (O) {Label Text};
```

Or set the `label` attribute in the edge:

```
\path (H-\source) edge[label=Label Text] (O);
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I realize the this segment:

```
\foreach \source in {1,...,3}
    \path (H-\source) edge (O);
```

sets the edges. I've also tried creating a new `node` inside the loop, but wasn't sure what how to position it relative to the edge, because the edge does not have an identifier.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: for example `\path (H-\source) edge ["Label Text"] (O);` (needed `quotes` library) or `\path (H-\source) edge node[above] {Label Text} (O);` ... is this what you looking for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look up the syntax of the basic tikz commands in some tutorial. To add labels, you need a `node`. E.g., you can have arrows with labels by using

```
\draw[->] (H-\source) -- node[above]{a\source} (O);
```

or

```
\path (H-\source) edge node[above]{a\source} (O);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  [shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep,
   every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
   neuron/.style={circle,draw=black!80,thick,minimum size=17pt,inner
        sep=0pt},
   annot/.style = {text width=4em, text centered}
  ]
  \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
     \node[neuron,yshift=0.5cm] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {$x_\y$};
  \node[neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:$h_\theta(x)$}, right of=H-2] (O) {};
  \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
     \draw[->] (H-\source) -- node[above]{a\source} (O);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me convert my comments to answer:

> for example \path (H-\source) edge ["Label Text"] (O); (needed quotes
>   library) or \path (H-\source) edge node[above] {Label Text} (O); ...
>   is this what you looking for?

Consider the first possibilities, library `chains` and `positioning` for neurons positioning and correct syntax for this, your MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
\def\layersep{12mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, ->, draw=black!50, 
           node distance = \layersep and 2*\layersep,
             start chain = going below,
   every pin edge/.style = {<-,shorten <=1pt},
           neuron/.style = {circle,draw=black!80, thick,
                            minimum size=17pt, inner sep=0pt,
                            on chain},
            annot/.style = {text width=4em, text centered},
every edge quotes/.style = {above,font=\footnotesize}
                    ]
\foreach \y in {1,2,3}
     \node (H-\y) [neuron] {$x_\y$};
\node (O) [neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:$h_\theta(x)$}, 
      right=of H-2] {};
\foreach \y in {1,2,3}
     \draw[->] (H-\y) edge [above,"a\y"] (O);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm pretty sure, that few days ago I wrote answer on very similar question.