# Consistent Pgfplot Labels Positions with/without Gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, gnuplot

I like that I can place a node at the end of plot and the node appears relative to the last point on the graph. When the domain is specified in **increasing** order `\DomainMin:\DomainMax`, the label gets placed exactly where I want it -- both with, and without `gnuplot` (see Graphs 1 and 2):

[image]

However, when the domain is specified in **decreasing** order `DomainMax:\DomainMin`, I get the label where I want it if I use PGF to compute the coordinates (See Graph 3), but it is in the wrong place when I use `gnuplot` (See Graph 4).  I suspect this is because `gnuplot` ignores the order the start and end of the domain are specified and computes coordinates in increasing x order.

[image]

I tried to use `pos=0` thinking that it would place the label at the point I want, but this not quite the case -- it appears quite a bit lower, but don't know why.

[image]

So, is there a way I can use `gnuplots` place the label the same place that `pgfplots` places it when I specify the domain in decreasing order?

Here is the code that produces the above 5 graphs:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand*{\XAxisMin}{-1.0}
\newcommand*{\XAxisMax}{3.0}
\newcommand*{\YAxisMin}{-2.0}
\newcommand*{\YAxisMax}{10}

\newcommand*{\DomainMinF}{\XAxisMin}
\newcommand*{\DomainMaxF}{2.2}
\newcommand*{\PlotLabel}{$y=x^3$}%


\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Axis Style/.style={
    clip=false,% so that we can see labels placed outside
    xmin=\XAxisMin, xmax=\XAxisMax,
    ymin=\YAxisMin, ymax=\YAxisMax, 
    width=6.5cm
}}

% Gnuplot options here  have no effect if not using GnuPlot
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Plot Style/.style={
    translate gnuplot=true,% can use ‘^’ instead of ‘**’
    id=foo,
    mark=none,%
    domain=\DomainMinF:\DomainMaxF,%
    samples=50,%
    ultra thick,
}}

\newcommand*{\AddLabel}[1]{\node [align = center] at (axis cs: 0.4,5) {#1};}%

\begin{document}
With increasing domain=$\DomainMinF:\DomainMaxF$, we get label at the end of the graph as desired:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Axis Style]
    \addplot [Plot Style, blue, domain=\DomainMinF:\DomainMaxF]
        {(x)^3} node [right] {\PlotLabel};%
    \AddLabel{1. without \\ Gnuplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Axis Style]
    \addplot [Plot Style, red, domain=\DomainMinF:\DomainMaxF]
        gnuplot% Use Gnuplot for Graph 2
        {(x)^3} node [right] {\PlotLabel};%
    \AddLabel{2. with \\ Gnuplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
But, with decreasing domain=$\DomainMaxF:\DomainMinF$, we get the label in the wrong spot with Gnuplot:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Axis Style]
    \addplot [Plot Style, blue, domain=\DomainMaxF:\DomainMinF]
        {(x)^3} node [right] {\PlotLabel};%
    \AddLabel{3. without \\ Gnuplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Axis Style]
    \addplot [Plot Style, red, domain=\DomainMaxF:\DomainMinF]
        gnuplot% Use Gnuplot for Graph 4
        {(x)^3} node [right] {\PlotLabel};% adding pos=0.0 does not work
    \AddLabel{4. with \\ Gnuplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Axis Style]
    \addplot [Plot Style, red, domain=\DomainMaxF:\DomainMinF]
        gnuplot% Use Gnuplot for Graph 5
        {(x)^3} node [right, pos=0.0] {\PlotLabel};
    \AddLabel{5. with \\ Gnuplot (pos=0.0)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really similar to my question [Label plots in pgfplots without entering coordinates manually](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12207/label-plots-in-pgfplots-without-entering-coordinates-manually): The development version of PGFplots supports placing nodes using `pos`.

Comment: @Jake: Definitely a related/similar question. I did have a look at that but was not able to get `linelabel` to work. I can try to recreate it and post as a separate question if you like. But, I normally either label at either end of the plot, or manually place the label independent of the plot.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do is probably to upgrade to the current version of PGFplots (>=1.5.1), which allows nodes to be placed along plots using `[pos=...]`.

Alternatively, you could use the `plotlabel` style that I used in my answer to [Label plots in pgfplots without entering coordinates manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12207/label-plots-in-pgfplots-without-entering-coordinates-manually). It allows you to place nodes at specified distances along the path. The syntax is `plotlabel{<pos>}{<label text>}`. This uses the  `markings` decoration, which uses `pgfnode` instead of TikZ `node`s, which isn't quite as flexible.

And thirdly, here's a trimmed down version of the `linelabel` style that I used in my answer to [Label plots in pgfplots without entering coordinates manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12207/label-plots-in-pgfplots-without-entering-coordinates-manually). This has the syntax `linelabel={<relative horizontal position along axis>}{<label code>}`, where `<label code>` will be passed to a `label` (see p. 194 of the [pgfmanual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)), so you can use something like `[node options]<placement>:<label text>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    nomorepostaction/.code={\let\tikz@postactions\pgfutil@empty},
    plotlabel/.style 2 args={
        every path/.append style={
            postaction={
                nomorepostaction,
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=at position #1 with {
                        \pgftransformresetnontranslations
                        \pgfnode{rectangle}{west}{#2}{}{}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
\makeatother


\newcommand*{\XAxisMin}{-1.0}
\newcommand*{\XAxisMax}{3.0}
\newcommand*{\YAxisMin}{-3.0}
\newcommand*{\YAxisMax}{10}

\newcommand*{\DomainMinF}{\XAxisMin}
\newcommand*{\DomainMaxF}{2.2}
\newcommand*{\PlotLabel}{$y=x^3$}%


\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Axis Style/.style={
    clip=false,% so that we can see labels placed outside
    xmin=\XAxisMin, xmax=\XAxisMax,
    ymin=\YAxisMin, ymax=\YAxisMax, 
    width=6.5cm
}}

% Gnuplot options here  have no effect if not using GnuPlot
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Plot Style/.style={
    translate gnuplot=true,% can use ‘^’ instead of ‘**’
    id=foo,
    mark=none,%
    domain=\DomainMinF:\DomainMaxF,%
    samples=50,%
    ultra thick,
}}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/linelabel/.style 2 args={name path global=labelpath,execute at end plot={
\path [name path global = labelpositionline]
(rel axis cs:#1,0) --
(rel axis cs:#1,1);
\draw [name intersections={of=labelpath and labelpositionline}] (intersection-1)  node [label={#2}] {};},
}}

\newcommand*{\AddLabel}[1]{\node [align = center] at (axis cs: 0.4,5) {#1};}%


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Axis Style]
    \addplot [Plot Style, blue, domain=\DomainMinF:\DomainMaxF,plotlabel={0}{\PlotLabel}]
        {(x)^3};
\AddLabel{1. without \\ Gnuplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Axis Style]
    \addplot [Plot Style, red, domain=\DomainMinF:\DomainMaxF,plotlabel={0}{\PlotLabel}]
        gnuplot {(x)^3};
\AddLabel{2. with \\ Gnuplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Axis Style]
    \addplot [Plot Style, blue, domain=\DomainMinF:\DomainMaxF,linelabel={0}{[blue]right:\PlotLabel}]
        {(x)^3};
\AddLabel{1. without \\ Gnuplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Axis Style]
    \addplot [Plot Style, red, domain=\DomainMinF:\DomainMaxF,linelabel={0}{[red]right:\PlotLabel}]
        gnuplot {(x)^3};
\AddLabel{2. with \\ Gnuplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does appear to solve the problem for this specifc case, but I would prefer the label at where the left end of the graph is. So, for example if the setting had been `\newcommand*{\DomainMinF}{0.0}` this won't work as there is no intersection. I was thinking that if the first coordinate could be extracted from the g`nuplot` file, and the node placed at that point

Comment: I thought that I could use `linelabel={\DomainMinF}...`, but that too did not work. Also, I don't quite understand the syntax of the 2nd parameter to `linelabel` where the color is in `[]`, but the position is outside?

Comment: I've added the second approach from the answer I linked to, which allows you to specify a `pos` along the label path. The syntax of the second parameter is explained in the section on `label`s in the pgfmanual.