# Plotting line contours using pgftikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to plot line contours from a data file specifying the value of the line such as the one shown in example here. It takes a lot of time to plot, export and enter the PDF in to the thesis.

[image: Contour of a fluid flow problem]

Comment: How did you get these curves?

Comment: See [Contour plot labeling applied to ordinary 2D plots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37665/contour-plot-labeling-applied-to-ordinary-2d-plots)

Comment: Does the question percusse linked to answer your question? Then we can close this as a duplicate. If it doesn't, please add more information to your question. At the moment, all you could reasonably expect is an answer along the lines of "Yes, there's a way, but it depends."

Comment: Actually, the link provided by @percusse is not exactly what i need. What i want is that pgfplots should read the data from a file, then plot the specific contour line according to the value specified (labeling is only the next issue). Is this possible?

Comment: I can feel that it is possible but if you can give us some dummy data and a basic construction, we can understand better what you are doing. Right now, all I can see is bunch of plots and numbers attached to them which is not what you are describing in the your last comment.

Comment: Take a look at the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots), section 4.5.7 Contour Plots.

Comment: @Jake thanks for the info. Actually its a extension of this which i want.
Ex:
`\begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{axis}[colormap/cool]
\addplot3[surf,samples=25,domain=0:1,shader=flat]
{x*(1-x)*y*(1-y)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}`

In the above plot, i want the contour lines projected on to the ground for specific values of z-axis.
@percusse Will this be enough?

Comment: @sgp: So do you want a perspective view, like in the example in your comment, or do you want a 2D view, like in the picture you posted in your question?

Comment: @Jake Actually both are fine. But my main aim is to show the contour lines on to the ground. In gnuplot, the command would look like,
`set contour
unset clabel
set view 0,0
unset surface
set cntrparam levels 10
sp 'Plot.dat' w l u 1:2:3`

Comment: @sgp: So what's wrong with the first example, in section 4.5.7 of the manual, (`\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[contour gnuplot]
{x*y};
\end{axis}`)? That should be exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Jake I am very sorry for the inconvenience, my pgfplots package documents seem to be out of date. The example in 4.5.7 is different in my document to that of your link.

Comment: @sgp Thanks for the update. If you add `\listfiles` to your preamble, it will list the version info of each package in the `.log` file. If older than 1.5.1, I would recommend you to update to the latest (v1.5.1 currently) version.

Comment: @Jake For the pdf manual you point to,-- Revision 1.16 (2018/03/28)) -- the section for contour plots is 4.6.8 (eigth subsection of the "Three Dimensional Plot Types" section.