# pgfplotsinvokeforeach is invoked only twice

Tags: pgfplots, loops

I would like to plot the family of curves with equation *xy=c* for several values of *c*.  I also want each curve to be labeled with the value of *c* it corresponds to.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3.0,xmax=3.0,
        ymin=-3.0,ymax=3.0,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis y line=middle,
        axis equal image,
        cycle list={blue}
        ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-3.0,-2.5,...,-0.5,0.5,1.0,...,3.0}{
            \addplot+[domain=-3:-0.1,forget plot] {#1/x};
            \addplot+[domain=0.1:3] {#1/x} node[pos=0.5] {$#1$};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get each curve plotted, but only two of them are labeled:

[image: sample code output]

How do I get all twelve curves labeled?

Comment: Just remove the axis restrictions and you'll see them :-) `pos=0.5` is not always in the visible range.

Comment: @percusse:  You are right, of course.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get finer control over the placement of the nodes, you could adapt my approach from [Label plots in pgfplots without entering coordinates manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12207/label-plots-in-pgfplots-without-entering-coordinates-manually). For example, you could define a curved path and place all the labels at the intersections of their plot and the path:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\pgfkeys{
    /pgfplots/linelabel/.style={
        name path global=labelpath,
        execute at end plot={
            \path [name path global = labelpositionline]
                (rel axis cs:0.85,0) to [bend left=45, looseness=1] (rel axis cs:0.85,1);
            \path [name intersections={of=labelpath and labelpositionline}] (intersection-1) node [font=\scriptsize] {#1};
        },
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3.0,xmax=3.0,
        ymin=-3.0,ymax=3.0,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis y line=middle,
        axis equal image,
        cycle list={blue}
        ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-3.0,-2.5,...,-0.5,0.5,1.0,...,3.0}{
            \addplot+[domain=-3:-0.1,forget plot] {#1/x};
            \addplot+[linelabel=#1,domain=0.1:3] {#1/x};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool.  I was looking for an intersections solution but I was not able to refer to the plot by name.  I was using `name path` instead of `name path global` and that must be the difference.

Answer (score 6):

If you use a different value for `pos`, they will be visible:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3.0,xmax=3.0,
        ymin=-3.0,ymax=3.0,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis y line=middle,
        axis equal image,
        cycle list={blue}
        ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-3.0,-2.5,...,-0.5,0.5,1.0,...,3.0}{
            \addplot+[domain=-3:-0.1,forget plot] {#1/x};
            \addplot+[domain=0.1:3] {#1/x} node[pos=0.92] {$#1$};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I hadn't thought to try that.  Any idea why it doesn't work with `0.5`?

Comment: Oh, wait.  It might be that pos=0.5 is outside the window...

Comment: @MatthewLeingang yes ;-)

Comment: Should have thought of that.  I need a better way to place the nodes, then.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang You can play around with `restrict y to domain=-4:4,` to keep the plots stay in the visible range.

Answer (score 2):

As the first few commenters pointed out, the labels *were* placed, just outside the window defined by the pgfplots `ymin`/`ymax` keys.

My workaround was to alert the domain of each plotted function so that there were no points outside the window.  Then `pos=0.5` was exactly where I wanted it.

```
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-3.0,-2.5,...,-0.5,0.5,1.0,...,3.0}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{abs(#1)/3}
        \addplot+[domain=-3:-\a,forget plot] {#1/x};
        \addplot+[domain=\a:3] {#1/x} node[black,fill=white,pos=0.5,sloped,inner sep=0pt] {$#1$};
    }
```

The disadvantage is that if `ymin` or `ymax` were changed the line defining `\a` would need to be updated.  So it's not optimal but the output is not bad.

[image]