# pgfplots - Placing Nodes on x Coordinates of a Plot

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, plot, coordinates

I want to plot some graphs in pgfplots and want to place nodes on the exact same x coordinate of the plot. The position of the note has to be set in x direction but free in y direction.
Here is one example of the way it shouldn't be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\begin{axis}
    \addplot {-x}  [yshift=8pt] node[pos=0.1] {$0,1$};
    \addplot {x^2} [yshift=8pt] node[pos=0.1] {$0,1$};
    \addplot{3*x^2}[yshift=8pt] node[pos=0.1] {$0,1$};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With the example linked by Jake I adapted the file. Now it is producing the return value 1 and no good result. What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\begin{axis}
\addplot[yshift=8pt,add node at x={-4}{$0,1$}] {-x};
\addplot[yshift=8pt,add node at x={-4}{$0,1$}] {x^2};
\addplot[yshift=8pt,add node at x={-4}{$0,1$}] {3*x^2};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the `(axis cs:x,y)` to use the axis coordinate system to place your nodes.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  To add to @percusse's comment: you need to place them separately form the `\addplot` via something like `\node at (axis cs: 0,20) {$f(x)$};` which places the node at `(0,20)`, for example.

Comment: Related/duplicate? [pgfplots: Placing node on a specific x-position](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88404/pgfplots-placing-node-on-a-specific-x-position)

Comment: With (axis cs:x,y) I place the note on a fix coordinate position. But I want to note the graph on a defined x position and the y position of the note is set by the function. I'm looking for something like node[xpos=-4].

Comment: @Nils: That's what the solution does that I linked to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the code from the answer to [pgfplots: Placing node on a specific x-position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88404/pgfplots-placing-node-on-a-specific-x-position):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\makeatletter
\def\parsenode[#1]#2\pgf@nil{%
    \tikzset{label node/.style={#1}}
    \def\nodetext{#2}
}

\tikzset{
    add node at x/.style 2 args={
        name path global=plot line,
        /pgfplots/execute at end plot visualization/.append={
                \begingroup
                \@ifnextchar[{\parsenode}{\parsenode[]}#2\pgf@nil
            \path [name path global = position line #1-1]
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) --
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \path [xshift=1pt, name path global = position line #1-2]
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) --
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \path [
                name intersections={
                    of={plot line and position line #1-1},
                    name=left intersection
                },
                name intersections={
                    of={plot line and position line #1-2},
                    name=right intersection
                },
                label node/.append style={pos=1}
            ] (left intersection-1) -- (right intersection-1)
            node [label node]{\nodetext};
            \endgroup
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\begin{axis}
\addplot[add node at x={-4}{[fill=white]{$0,1$}}] {-x};
\addplot[add node at x={-4}{[fill=white]{$0,1$}}] {x^2};
\addplot[add node at x={-4}{[fill=white]{$0,1$}}] {3*x^2};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great Answer! But unfortunately the nodes created that way are not using the color of the graph, like it would with the original approach. Is there a way to implement this without setting the node colors manually?