# Add annotations at right margin of plot

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to add annotations outside the plotting area, at the right axis, and at positions that depend on the coordinates of the plot.

I could do that with custom ticks, or adding nodes manually, but in the latter case I have to give the code in `after end axis` or disable clipping (which can have other undesirable effects, such as... not clipping). The best solution I've found so far is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\angs{0.529177208354}
\def\ev{27.2113838656}

\begin{axis}[
  xmin = 2,
  xmax = 4,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 5,
  xlabel = {$r$},
  ylabel = {$E$},
  after end axis/.code = {
    \path (axis cs:4.0,1.6) node[right] {B3LYP};
  } 
] 

\def\ezero{-1.11}
\addplot+ table[x expr={\thisrowno{0}*2*\angs}, y expr={(\thisrowno{2}-\ezero)*\ev}] {data.dat};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It has to problems:

1. I'd like to give the code next to `\addplot`, and not in the `axis` options.
2. I'd like the coordinates (in particular the ordinate) to be calculated automatically.

This shows the result with the following `data.dat` file:

```
2.0 -13840.8142382 -0.8142382
2.1 -13840.9230067 -0.9230067
2.2 -13840.9967745 -0.9967745
2.3 -13841.0454158 -1.0454158
2.4 -13841.0762998 -1.0762998
2.5 -13841.0944654 -1.0944654
2.6 -13841.1038383 -1.1038383
2.7 -13841.1070221 -1.1070221
2.8 -13841.1059849 -1.1059849
2.9 -13841.1022183 -1.1022183
3.0 -13841.0966277 -1.0966277
3.1 -13841.0899909 -1.0899909
3.2 -13841.0828688 -1.0828688
3.3 -13841.0755779 -1.0755779
3.4 -13841.0687860 -1.0687860
3.5 -13841.0626993 -1.0626993
3.6 -13841.0572297 -1.0572297
3.7 -13841.0527363 -1.0527363
3.8 -13841.0493218 -1.0493218
3.9 -13841.0467450 -1.0467450
4.0 -13841.0447949 -1.0447949
4.1 -13841.0433105 -1.0433105
4.2 -13841.0421877 -1.0421877
4.3 -13841.0413471 -1.0413471
4.4 -13841.0407159 -1.0407159
4.5 -13841.0402353 -1.0402353
4.6 -13841.0398710 -1.0398710
4.7 -13841.0395993 -1.0395993
4.8 -13841.0393960 -1.0393960
4.9 -13841.0392397 -1.0392397
5.0 -13841.0391747 -1.0391747
```

[image: test plot]

PS. Another question as a bonus: is there a way to use the numbers in the 2nd column, rather than the 3rd (which is just the 2nd + 13840), without losing precision?

Comment: By automatically, do you mean the point where the plot intersects the axis box or at a certain x coordinate specifically?

Comment: @percusse Any of those. Getting the y for an arbitrary x would have other uses, but for this particular task the intersection with the box would be enough (and probably as "automatic" as it can get).

Comment: Yeah, density function theory, right?

Comment: Related: [Align pinned nodes in PGFplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112597)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the code from [pgfplots - Placing Nodes on x Coordinates of a Plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93819/pgfplots-placing-nodes-on-x-coordinates-of-a-plot) for this. It allows you to write

```
\addplot+ [add node at x={4}{[anchor=west]B3LYP}] table ...
```

(or

```
`\addplot+ [add node at x={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}{[anchor=west]B3LYP}] table...
```

if you don't want to specify the x value manually) to get

[image]

Note that you have to set `clip mode=individual` if you're using plot styles without markers to prevent the node from being clipped away.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter
\def\parsenode[#1]#2\pgf@nil{%
    \tikzset{label node/.style={#1}}
    \def\nodetext{#2}
}

\tikzset{
    add node at x/.style 2 args={
        name path global=plot line,
        /pgfplots/execute at end plot visualization/.append={
                \begingroup
                \@ifnextchar[{\parsenode}{\parsenode[]}#2\pgf@nil
            \path [name path global = position line #1-1]
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) --
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \path [xshift=1pt, name path global = position line #1-2]
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) --
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \path [
                name intersections={
                    of={plot line and position line #1-1},
                    name=left intersection
                },
                name intersections={
                    of={plot line and position line #1-2},
                    name=right intersection
                },
                label node/.append style={pos=1}
            ] (left intersection-1) -- (right intersection-1)
            node [label node]{\nodetext};
            \endgroup
        }
    }
}

\def\angs{0.529177208354}
\def\ev{27.2113838656}

\begin{axis}[
  xmin = 2,
  xmax = 4,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 5,
  xlabel = {$r$},
  ylabel = {$E$},
  cycle list name = linestyles*,
  clip mode=individual
] 

\def\ezero{-1.11}
\addplot+ [,add node at x={4}{[anchor=west,]B3LYP}]
 table[x expr={\thisrowno{0}*2*\angs}, y expr={(\thisrowno{2}-\ezero)*\ev}] {
2.0 -13840.8142382 -0.8142382
2.1 -13840.9230067 -0.9230067
2.2 -13840.9967745 -0.9967745
2.3 -13841.0454158 -1.0454158
2.4 -13841.0762998 -1.0762998
2.5 -13841.0944654 -1.0944654
2.6 -13841.1038383 -1.1038383
2.7 -13841.1070221 -1.1070221
2.8 -13841.1059849 -1.1059849
2.9 -13841.1022183 -1.1022183
3.0 -13841.0966277 -1.0966277
3.1 -13841.0899909 -1.0899909
3.2 -13841.0828688 -1.0828688
3.3 -13841.0755779 -1.0755779
3.4 -13841.0687860 -1.0687860
3.5 -13841.0626993 -1.0626993
3.6 -13841.0572297 -1.0572297
3.7 -13841.0527363 -1.0527363
3.8 -13841.0493218 -1.0493218
3.9 -13841.0467450 -1.0467450
4.0 -13841.0447949 -1.0447949
4.1 -13841.0433105 -1.0433105
4.2 -13841.0421877 -1.0421877
4.3 -13841.0413471 -1.0413471
4.4 -13841.0407159 -1.0407159
4.5 -13841.0402353 -1.0402353
4.6 -13841.0398710 -1.0398710
4.7 -13841.0395993 -1.0395993
4.8 -13841.0393960 -1.0393960
4.9 -13841.0392397 -1.0392397
5.0 -13841.0391747 -1.0391747
};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect... now it only has to work with `cycle list name = linestyles*` :)

Comment: @Jellby: You need to add `clip mode=individual` in that case...

Comment: Thanks. There's still something wrong, when I add more lines all the labels are at the same position, but I cannot reproduce that in the sample file... I'll come back when I find the reason or a non-working example.

Comment: Without the options `cycle list name=linestyles*` and `clip mode=individual` the `execute at end plot visualization` gets executes twice.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Does it? How do you know? And when does it matter?

Comment: The  `execute at end plot visualization` code may not get executed twice, but the `add node at x` style gets *with* the `+` and *without* the mentioned options. To test it, add `\newcounter{test}` to the preamble and `/utils/exec=\stepcounter{test}\errmessage{\arabic{test}}` to the `add node at x` style. If you use the style twice (`[add node at x={3}{B4LYP},add node at x={4}{B3LYP}]`), you will get something similar to what @Jellby reported.

Comment: That might be a reason, another problem occurs when the label is placed exactly at the limit of the data (in this case, `add node at x={5}`, but replacing `x expr` with `x index=0`. Would it be possible to use the intersection *or* the last point in the plot if there is no intersection?