# How do I add a marker to TikZ plot for specific x coordinate?

Tags: pgfplots

Please take a look at my code. I am plotting values from a file and I want to add a marker at the `x` coordinate of 100 GHz.

```
\documentclass[convert={density=400,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[ymin=-30,ymax=10,enlargelimits=false,
title=Large Signal S-parameters of Pre-Amplifier, 
ylabel=S-parameters(dB),
xlabel=Frequency(GHz), 
legend style={legend pos= south east}, 
ytick={-30,-25,-20,-15,-10,-5,0,5,10},
grid=major]
\addplot +[smooth][mark=none, line width=1.5pt]
file{S21_preamp};
\addlegendentry{$S_{21}$}
\addplot +[smooth] [mark=none, line width=1.5pt]
file{S11_preamp};
\addlegendentry{$S_{11}$}
\draw [<-,thick](100,360) -- (120,370) node[above]{5.8dB} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Right now I have an arrow pointing to the `x` position. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I can't add images, need more reputation for that

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again. — More importantly, a sample of your data files would be helpful or at least a dummy plot or the right min and max settings, so that we can have the right limits. By the way, inside the `axis` environment, you can use the `axis cs` and the `axis direction cs` to use the coordinate of the plot. There is also `extra x tick`/`extra x label` (or similar).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the approach from [pgfplots: Placing node on a specific x-position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88404/pgfplots-placing-node-on-a-specific-x-position) to place a coordinate at a desired x-coordinate along the plot without having to determine the y-coordinate manually (example adapted from Tom's answer):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, intersections}

\makeatletter
\def\parsenode[#1]#2\pgf@nil{%
    \tikzset{label node/.style={#1}}
    \def\nodetext{#2}
}

\tikzset{
    add node at x/.style 2 args={
        name path global=plot line,
        /pgfplots/execute at end plot visualization/.append={
                \begingroup
                \@ifnextchar[{\parsenode}{\parsenode[]}#2\pgf@nil
            \path [name path global = position line #1-1]
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) --
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \path [xshift=1pt, name path global = position line #1-2]
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) --
                ({axis cs:#1,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
            \path [
                name intersections={
                    of={plot line and position line #1-1},
                    name=left intersection
                },
                name intersections={
                    of={plot line and position line #1-2},
                    name=right intersection
                },
                label node/.append style={pos=1}
            ] (left intersection-1) -- (right intersection-1)
            node [label node]{\nodetext};
            \endgroup
        }
    },
    add node at y/.style 2 args={
        name path global=plot line,
        /pgfplots/execute at end plot visualization/.append={
                \begingroup
                \@ifnextchar[{\parsenode}{\parsenode[]}#2\pgf@nil
            \path [name path global = position line #1-1]
                ({axis cs:0,#1}-|{rel axis cs:0,0}) --
                ({axis cs:0,#1}-|{rel axis cs:1,1});
            \path [yshift=1pt, name path global = position line #1-2]
                ({axis cs:0,#1}-|{rel axis cs:0,0}) --
                ({axis cs:0,#1}-|{rel axis cs:1,1});
            \path [
                name intersections={
                    of={plot line and position line #1-1},
                    name=left intersection
                },
                name intersections={
                    of={plot line and position line #1-2},
                    name=right intersection
                },
                label node/.append style={pos=1}
            ] (left intersection-1) -- (right intersection-1)
            node [label node] {\nodetext};
            \endgroup
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}
[   ymin=5,
    ymax=25,
    enlargelimits=false,
    title=Large Signal S-parameters of Pre-Amplifier, 
    ylabel=S-parameters(dB),
    xlabel=Frequency(GHz), 
    legend style={legend pos= south east}, 
    ytick={5,10,...,25},
    grid=major,
]
\addplot +[smooth, mark=none, line width=1.5pt,
    add node at x={3}{[coordinate, name=freq3]}] coordinates {(1,10)(2,8)(3,11)(4,13)(5,9)};
\addlegendentry{$S_{21}$}
\addplot +[smooth, mark=none, line width=1.5pt] coordinates {(1,17)(2,20)(3,19)(4,21)(5,18)};
\addlegendentry{$S_{11}$}
\draw [stealth-, thick] (freq3) -- ++(0,6ex) node [above] {Label};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very interesting, I wondered if this was possible!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the axis coordinate system via `(axis cs: x,y)`. I made up some sample data for testing. I also used a nicer arrow tip, you'll need the `arrows` library for that. Lastly for the tick labels you can use the `{a,a+b,...,c}` notation which will give you labels spaced `b` starting from `a` to `c`:

### Code

```
\documentclass[convert={density=400,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}
[   ymin=5,
    ymax=25,
    enlargelimits=false,
    title=Large Signal S-parameters of Pre-Amplifier, 
    ylabel=S-parameters(dB),
    xlabel=Frequency(GHz), 
    legend style={legend pos= south east}, 
    ytick={5,10,...,25},
    grid=major,
]
\addplot +[smooth][mark=none, line width=1.5pt] coordinates {(1,10)(2,8)(3,11)(4,13)(5,9)};
\addlegendentry{$S_{21}$}
\addplot +[smooth] [mark=none, line width=1.5pt] coordinates {(1,17)(2,20)(3,19)(4,21)(5,18)};
\addlegendentry{$S_{11}$}
\draw [stealth-,thick] (axis cs:3,11) -- (axis cs:3,15) node[above]{5.8dB} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]