# Getting PGFplot to align \draw commands between plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to use `pgfplots` to add slope triangles to several plots on the same axis which look like the following:

[image: current output from <code>pdflatex</code>]

I thought I was in luck to see parts of this process explained specifically in the `pgfplots` documentation, but as you can see from the output, the right sides of the slope triangles are not aligned. I originally thought this was related to the `coordinate [pos=...]` command using arc length instead of x (or y) distance, but I don't think this can explain why the middle triangle is the furthest to the right.

Here is the code (some non-essentials removed):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}       

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{loglogaxis}[%
width=0.962707\textwidth,
height=0.75\textwidth,
xlabel={mesh size, $h^e$},
xmax=0.1,
ylabel={$L_2$ Error}
]
\addplot table[row sep=crcr]{%
0.052   0.08922\\
0.026   0.03718\\
0.013   0.01128\\
0.0065  0.00301\\
0.00325 0.00076\\
}
% add slope triangle
coordinate [pos=0.95] (A)
coordinate [pos=0.75] (B)
;
\draw (A) -| (B)
node [pos=.75,anchor=west]{$2.0$};

\addplot table[row sep=crcr]{%
0.052   0.02903\\
0.026   0.00918\\
0.013   0.00219\\
0.0065  0.00050\\
0.00325 0.00012\\
}
% add slope triangle
coordinate [pos=0.95] (A)
coordinate [pos=0.75] (B)
;
\draw (A) -| (B)
node [pos=.75,anchor=west]{$2.0$};

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

I am aware that the tables are ordered in reverse (right to left), but changing this did not seem to make a difference. Can someone please explain what is going on and how to correct it

Also, if it is possible to compute slope values of the labeled segment automatically, that would be extremely helpful, as I have several of these plots each with unique data.

Comment: Related: [pgfplots: Placing node on a specific x-position](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88404/pgfplots-placing-node-on-a-specific-x-position)

Comment: Thanks Jake. I saw this answer last night but didn't understand which part of the code applied to my problem. After looking at Harish's comment it's pretty clear.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `pos` key finds the points by considering the total length of the line. Here since the plots are of different lengths, as `pos` value increases, the points differ in position.

You can use `intersections` library, draw two vertical lines and find their intersections with the plots to draw the slope.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{loglogaxis}[%
width=0.962707\textwidth,
height=0.75\textwidth,
xlabel={mesh size, $h^e$},
xmax=0.1,
ylabel={$L_2$ Error}
]
\path[name path global = vert1] (rel axis cs: 0.12,   0) -- (rel axis cs: 0.12,   1);
\path[name path global = vert2] (rel axis cs: 0.25,   0) -- (rel axis cs: 0.25,   1);
\addplot+[name path global =plot1] table[row sep=crcr]{%
0.052   0.08922\\
0.026   0.03718\\
0.013   0.01128\\
0.0065  0.00301\\
0.00325 0.00076\\
};
% add slope triangle
\path [name intersections={of = vert1 and plot1, by=a}];
\path [name intersections={of = vert2 and plot1, by=b}];

\draw (a) -| (b)node [pos=.75,anchor=west]{$2.0$};

\addplot+[name path global=plot2] table[row sep=crcr]{%
0.052   0.02903\\
0.026   0.00918\\
0.013   0.00219\\
0.0065  0.00050\\
0.00325 0.00012\\
};
% add slope triangle
\path [name intersections={of = vert1 and plot2, by=a}];
\path [name intersections={of = vert2 and plot2, by=b}];
\draw (a) -| (b)
node [pos=.75,anchor=west]{$2.0$};

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, thank you. Do you have any tips for automatically computing the slope? In the PGFplots manual they use an ``\xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona}`` to save the slope, but I don't have a linear regression. I'm only interested in the slope of a single segment (as pictured).

Comment: @DavidMcWilliams: Calculation of slopes automatically for non linear graphs is not straight forward and hence deserves to be a separate question. However, you may plot that particular segment separately and use `\xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona}` for that segment. I mean use another `\addplot` for that segment alone.