# Visualize relative positions of graph for composition purposes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I often use the possibility of [pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots) to annotate my graphs by adding nodes on it based on its relative position. For a linear plot that is rather simple, after after a few guesses I find the right spot, where I want to place my annotation.

But often I work with **semilogxaxis** plots and it gets really tough to get where on the graph e.g. a third of my (optical) x-axis is reached, as you can see in the MWE.

I know there are ways to [**place nodes on exact positions on the graph**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88421/36835), but that's usually not trivial. I'm just looking for a **fast and uncomplicated** way to place my nodes - using the `pos=...` property is unbeatable for that purpose. So I wonder if it may be possible to put a "relative grid" on top of the graph for composition.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{semilogxaxis}[
    width = \linewidth,
    ]

\addplot {x^2}
node[pos=0.3, fill, circle=10pt, pin=135:{ annotation in graph color }] {0.5}
node[pos=0.5, fill, circle=10pt, color=red, text=black] {0.5}
node[pos=0.2, fill, circle=10pt, color=red, text=black] {0.2}
;

\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Of course I could use a loop to plot multiple of the red dots to get an idea of the positions on the graph, but I wonder if there is a neater solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automatically add nodes at different `pos` values using a `foreach` loop, which can then be used for finding the desired position:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\showpos{
 foreach \pos in {0, 0.1, ..., 1} {node [pos=\pos, pin=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pos}, circle, inner sep=1pt, fill] {} }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{semilogxaxis}[
    width = \linewidth,
    ]

\addplot [green!50!blue] {x^2} \showpos node[pos=0.15, fill, circle=10pt, pin=135:{ annotation in graph color }] {0.15};

\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `datavisualization` library you can use the `when` key to specify when a label or pin has to be placed on your graph. You can use it by calling `when=<x|y> is <value>` in a `pin in data` or `label in data` command.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[scientific axes,
                       x axis={grid={step=.5}, logarithmic},
                       visualize as line=myfunc,
                       every data set label/.append style={
                         text colored, 
                         node style={font=\scriptsize}
                       },
                       style sheet=vary hue,
                       myfunc={
                         label in data={text={$f(x)=x^2$}, when=x is .25},
                         pin in data={text={$x=1$}, when=x is 1},
                         pin in data={text={$x=4$}, when=x is 4},
                         pin in data={text={$y=60$}, when=y is 60},
                    }]
    data [format=function, set=myfunc] {
        var x : interval [0.1:10] samples 250;
        func y = \value x * \value x;
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image 1]

It is **important** to use enough `sample`-steps to have exact datapoints for positioning the `pin` or label. Otherwise the `pin` or `label` will be placed at the next datapoint available to the requested `when` argument. This doesn't have to be exactly your requested value.

Here the rendered output from above with `samples 10` instead of `samples 250`.

[image: rendered image 2]

If you use `style={mark=*}` in your `myfunc={...}` you can mark every available datapoint. This exhibits the problem of insufficient samples even better:

[image: renderd image2.1]

**UPDATE:**
You can also add circle-nodes to your graph. See the following code for an example (the `second label in data`):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[scientific axes,
                   x axis={grid={step=.5}, logarithmic},
                   visualize as line=myfunc,
                   every data set label/.append style={
                     text colored, 
                     node style={font=\scriptsize}
                   },
                   style sheet=vary hue,
                   myfunc={
                     label in data={text={$f(x)=x^2$}, when=x is .25},
                     pin in data={text={$x=1$}, when=x is 1},
                     pin in data={text={$x=4$}, when=x is 4},
                     pin in data={text={$y=60$}, when=y is 60},
                     label in data={text=$5$ , when=x is 5, node style={fill=red, circle, anchor=center}},
                }]
data [format=function, set=myfunc] {
    var x : interval [0.1:10] samples 250;
    func y = \value x * \value x;
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image 3]

Comment: This library seems to offer some essential features pgfplots is missing. However I'm limited to pgfplots as I couldn't use the pgfplots-based libraries provided at my institute. Thanks for the introduction! Also I think this answer is better suited [*here*](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88404/pgfplots-placing-node-on-a-specific-x-position/88421#88421).