# How to replicate a normal distribution plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I was wonder if it is possible to replicate a normal distribution plot as shown. If so, how? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It is possible. Start for example from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11368/bell-curve-gaussian-function-normal-distribution-in-tikz-pgf and then add the annotations using something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88404/pgfplots-placing-node-on-a-specific-x-position.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You could use the `plot` function, for example like this: `\draw[smooth] plot coordinates { (0,0) (1,0.5) (2,1.5) (3,0.5) (4,0) };`.