# Drawing node in tikz with both background fill and grid pattern?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is it possible to use the grid pattern on a node but also setting a background color to it, say blue?

I want to use something like

```
\node (b) [fill=red, pattern=grid] {b};
```

I am aware of the solution here:
[How to combine fill and pattern in a pgfplot bar plot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24964/how-to-combine-fill-and-pattern-in-a-pgfplot-bar-plot),
but it does not seem to apply directly to a node. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikz{\node[preaction={fill, red}, pattern=grid] {b};}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much, especially for the timely reply! Saved my life by the due date!

Comment: I am newbie on posting and answering questions though. Can you let me know if there's a way to formally ``accept'' the answer to help your reputation? I am happy to do it!

Comment: Yes, click on the check mark which is under the vote arrows.

Comment: Done! Thx again! :-)