# PGFplots ybar patterns not showing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a bar plot graph and I want to use patterns to fill the columns. However it seems that patterns are not working. For compiling I use `pdflatex` or `lualatex`.

I also wanted to use pattern width different fill color. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfplotsset{every tick/.style={black,}}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.8,
    compat/show suggested version=false,
    ybar,
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={%
        font=\footnotesize,
        at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=2
        legend cell align=left,
        nodes={inner xsep=2pt,inner ysep=0.4pt,text depth=0.15em},
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    ylabel={y-axis},
    symbolic x coords={AAA,BBB},
    xtick=data,
    bar width=16pt,
    enlarge x limits=0.4,
    nodes near coords,
    font=\footnotesize,
    legend entries={C,D,E,G},
]

    \addplot[pattern=horizontal lines] coordinates {(AAA,0.32) (BBB,0.43)};
    \addplot[pattern=vertical lines] coordinates {(AAA,0.91) (BBB,0.93)};
    \addplot[pattern=north east lines] coordinates {(AAA,0.19) (BBB,0.16)};
    \addplot[pattern=north west lines] coordinates {(AAA,0.74) (BBB,0.72)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For the pattern color use:

```
\addplot[red,pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=red] coordinates {(AAA,0.32) (BBB,0.43)};
```

The first `red` is for the contour of the bar e the `pattern color=red` is for the pattern itself.

What errors do you have? I use `pgfplots 1.5.1` so I use `compat=1.5` and I comment your `compat/show suggested version=false` line and this works for me.

[image]

Comment: It seems in the newer versions of PGFplots it only works when compiling with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` or `latex+dvipdf`.