# PGFPlots pattern bug

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, xetex, pdftex, luatex

I tried to compile the example in [How to combine fill and pattern in a pgfplot bar plot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24964/how-to-combine-fill-and-pattern-in-a-pgfplot-bar-plot) to answer the question here [PGFplots ybar patterns not showing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116845/pgfplots-ybar-patterns-not-showing) and the pattern doesn't appear when I use `lualatex` `xelatex` or `pdflatex`; it only works with `latex+dvipdf`. I have `PGF 2.10` and `PGFplots 1.8`. Is there any known bug and workaround here?

I tried this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar, samples=10, enlarge y limits=upper, ymin=0]
\addplot +[
    black,
    fill=yellow,
    postaction={
        pattern=north east lines
    }
]{rnd};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result with `pdflatex`:

[image]

The result with `latex+dvipdf`:

[image]

The only warning that appears is

`Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} into y
our preamble.`

By the way, I am not sure, but in one of my tests, it seemed that if I had only none bar, it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, xelatex doesn't support patterns. About lualatex I have no idea.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina your comment is no longer true: the unstable of PGF supports patterns in xelatex (can be downloaded from texample.net). But `pdflatex` should have worked; it is supposed to be the best-supported driver.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Good to know. Thank you. Do you know when this unstable version will be the stable one?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger as I said I tried with all those drivers, I usually use `pdflatex` but it failed. Then I tried `latex+dvipdf` and to my surprise, it worked! Both `xelatex` and `lualatex` were tried after, with the same result as `pdflatex`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am currently unfamiliar with the release plan of PGF.

Comment: @cacamailg could you provide the resulting pdf somewhere? Perhaps it really is corrupted somehow. Did you modify the mentioned source code somehow? Did you get error messages? Ah, and note that you need to configure a special driver for PGF in order to use xelatex (please inspect the manual for details; I don't have it at hand now)

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I didn't modify the code that I mention.

Comment: Can you try with the `\usepackage{tikz}` line removed? You don't have to load tikz as pgfplots load it automatically but maybe something is overwritten.

Comment: @percusse I tried your suggestion, but it gave me the same result. Can you try the example with `pdflatex` and see if it compiles fine? Maybe the "bug" only affects me.

Comment: You can check it here https://www.writelatex.com/211132bctsfk Ther version of the PGFPLOTS is outdated though.

Comment: @percusse As I said before, my version of PGF is 2.10 and PGFPlots 1.8. I think for know I will use the `latex+dvipdf` and wait for the new release of TeXLive 2013.

Comment: On my computer with your configuration, I still can't replicate it though. I'll try to check again in the evening.

Comment: Indeed, I can't replicate this. Win 7, MikTeX 2.9, TikZ CVS, pgfplots 1.8. Maybe it is something fixed in TikZ CVS? `{Luq,Xe,PDF}LaTeX` all render correctly. But `Latex->dvi->PDF` fails.

Comment: @percusse I will keep this open, and wait for TeXLive 2013, and see if it renders correctly. It is strange that yours `Latex->dvi->PDF`, because with me it is the only one that works :). I assume that probably it is fixed with TikZ CVS.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue (because of I'm using matlab2tikz).  However, as mentioned in the [matlab2tikz page](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz), you should type `\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}` in your preamble.  I did it and I'm not longer experiencing the warning (I guess the `compact=newest` is the responsible)

Comment: @MarioS.E. your solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @cacamailg It was worth the try... I did get rid of the warning by doing so

Comment: This is 'works for me' with pdfLaTeX with an up-to-date TeX Live 2013: are you still seeing an issue?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved by updating the software