# using pattern inside tikz shapes with dropped shadows

Tags: tikz-pgf, shadows

Please, consider the mwe below.

Question: why does the `fill` of the second node become transparent?

Subquestion: why are lines in the pattern which are thicker than `1pt` not smooth?

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
    \usetikzlibrary{chains,patterns,shadows}
\tikzset{% customization of pattern
         % based on <m.wibrow@gm...> - 2013-03-24 07:20: 
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=5pt
        }
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north east hatch}% name
    {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}% below left
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain=going below,
    node distance=2mm,
   Node/.style = {minimum width=#1,
                  shape=rectangle, draw, fill=white,
                  on chain},
Pattern/.style = {pattern=north east hatch,
                  pattern color=teal!30,
                  hatch distance=7pt, hatch thickness=2pt},
                        ]\small\sffamily
%----------------
\node[Node=24mm,Pattern]    (a) {without shadow};
\node[Node=24mm,Pattern,
      drop shadow]          (b) {with shadow};
\node[Node=24mm,
      drop shadow]          (c) {without pattern};
%---
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does [Drawing a proper shadow for overlapping objects](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43618/13304) help you?

Comment: By default all nodes are transparent. If you want to make them opaque, fill them with a white color.

Comment: my Node has fill=white,i.e. it is not transparent. that should be seen from third rectangle. my observation is, that use of pattern make a shape transparent again. i need to see how the suggestion of Claudio work.

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino, unfortunately, the solution given link doesn't help. It doesn't change look out of my second rectangle. It stay the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**New answer**

I've found the correct answer which, of course, is perfectly explained in pgfmanual. 
I must give some credit to [Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25032/1952)
in [How to combine fill and pattern in a pgfplot bar plot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24964/how-to-combine-fill-and-pattern-in-a-pgfplot-bar-plot) because it switched on the light.

It's called `preaction` or `postaction` and you can read about them in section (v3.0.0) 15.10 Doing Multiple Actions on a Path.

> ```
> /tikz/preaction=<options>
> ```
>
> [...]
>   When this option is used on a
>   `\path`, the effect is the following: When the path has been completely
>   constructed and is about to be used, a scope is created. Inside this
>   scope, the path is used but not with the original path options, but
>   with `<options>` instead. Then, the path is used in the usual manner. In
>   other words, the path is used twice: Once with `<options>` in force and
>   then again with the normal path options in force.
>
> ```
> /tikz/postaction=<options>
> ```
>
> The postactions work in the
>   same way as the preactions, only they are applied after the main
>   action has been taken. Like preactions, multiple postaction options
>   may be given to a \path command, in which case the path is reused
>   several times, each time with a different set of options in force. If
>   both pre- and postactions are specified, then the preactions are taken
>   first, then the main action, and then the post actions.

and from section 66.1 Overview (Shadows Library) (bold is mine)

> A *shadow* is usually a black or gray area that is drawn behind a path
>   or a node, thereby adding visual depth to a picture. The `shadows`
>   library defines options that make it easy to add shadows to paths.
>   **Internally, these options are based on using the `preaction` option to
>   use a path twice: Once for drawing the shadow (slightly shifted) and
>   once for actually using the path.**

Therefore, if you want to fill a pattern you can use `preaction={fill=white}`. The node will be drawn twice, the first one it will be filled while the *transparent* pattern will be added on the second use of it.

```
\node[Node=24mm, Pattern, preaction={fill=white}] (a) {without shadow};
```

When nodes have `shadow` options, you must be careful with options order. Shadows use `opacity=.5` and if your filling preaction is used before the shadow,

```
\node[Node=24mm, preaction={fill=yellow}, drop shadow, Pattern] (b) {with shadow};
```

opacity is also applied to filling color. Then you must declare shadow option always before filling preaction.

```
\node[Node=24mm, drop shadow, preaction={fill=yellow}, Pattern] (b) {with shadow};
```

Instead of `preactions` you can also use `postactions`, but in this case you will need to `draw` again the node, because the pattern is drawn over it.

Next code shows examples with `preaction` and `potsaction` options.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,patterns,shadows,fit,backgrounds}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{% customization of pattern
         % based on <m.wibrow@gm...> - 2013-03-24 07:20: 
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=5pt
        }
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north east hatch}% name
    {\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain=going below,
    node distance=2mm,
    Node/.style = {minimum width=#1,
                   shape=rectangle, 
                   draw, fill=white,
                   on chain},
    Pattern/.style = {pattern=north east hatch,
                    pattern color=teal!30,
                    hatch distance=7pt, 
                    hatch thickness=2pt},
    font=\small\sffamily]
%----------------
    \node[Node=24mm, Pattern, 
            preaction={fill=white}] (a) {without shadow};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[fit=(a),fill=red] {};
    \end{scope}

    \node[Node=24mm, drop shadow,
            preaction={fill=yellow}, Pattern] (b) {with shadow};

    \node[Node=24mm, preaction={fill=yellow},
            drop shadow, Pattern] (b) {with shadow};

    \node[Node=24mm, postaction={Pattern},
            drop shadow] (b) {with shadow};

    \node[Node=24mm, postaction={draw=red, Pattern},
            drop shadow] (b) {with shadow};

    \node[Node=24mm, drop shadow] (c) {without pattern};
%---
 \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

**First version**

Next code is just an idea. Looks like is not possible to `fill` a hatch pattern with any color but you can try to draw `double lines`. It's not perfect and I don't know how to do it better because I don't understand enough how it works. This solution was obtained after playing with `\hatchdistance` and `\hatchthickness`.

```
  \documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
    \usetikzlibrary{chains,patterns,shadows,fit,backgrounds}
\tikzset{% customization of pattern
         % based on <m.wibrow@gm...> - 2013-03-24 07:20: 
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=5pt
        }
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north east hatch}% name
    {\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfsetinnerlinewidth{1pt}
        \pgfsetinnerstrokecolor{white}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain=going below,
    node distance=2mm,
   Node/.style = {minimum width=#1,
                  shape=rectangle, draw, fill=white,
                  on chain},
Pattern/.style = {pattern=north east hatch,
                  pattern color=teal!30,
                  hatch distance=4pt, hatch thickness=2.5pt},
                        ]\small\sffamily
%----------------
\node[Node=24mm,Pattern]    (a) {without shadow};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[fit=(a),fill=red] {};
\end{scope}

\node[Node=24mm,Pattern,
      drop shadow]          (b) {with shadow};
\node[Node=24mm,
      drop shadow]          (c) {without pattern};
%---
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is big enough to see some thin blue lines behind white ones. I don't know where they come from.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. it works and result is good enough for my temporary needs. me either not understand haw this pattern work. I also observe this tiny blue lines in my other examples.  At first I expect that to pattern can be defined an "background" color or it can be put somehow in foreground of node with fill. Maybe this can be feature request.

Comment: @Zarko: Please look at updated answer. It shows a better solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is great solution! I my confess, when I need to "browse" in tikz manual for something, i feel a little bit lost in forest of information in it, so many time i do not see particular tree ... and thank you for explanation. It is very helpful form my future plans for more drawing more complex.