# Filling rectangle in TikZ with more than one color

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

To draw a rectangle and fill it in gray in TikZ:

```
\draw [fill=gray,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
```

Now, I want to fill it in both gray and yellow. The best way would be if I can make diagonal stripes of gray and yellow alternately. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: In `tikz` these stripes are called patterns. The manual has a lot of examples for that. When the documented functions are not enough, have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns

Comment: @papabravo Thanks, is there a quick way to implement what I wanted without having to define a custom pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit tricky solution without defining custom pattern for rectangle `a=2xb`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{2}%width of rectangle
\def\b{\a/2}%height of rectangle
\def\lw{0.1}
\draw[] (0,0) rectangle (\a,\b);
\foreach \x in{0,0.2,0.4,...,\a}{
\draw [gray,line width=\lw mm](\x,0)--(0,\x/2);
\draw [gray,line width=\lw mm](\a,\x/2)--(\x,\b);}

\foreach \x in{0.1,0.3,...,\a}{
\draw [yellow,line width=\lw mm](\x,0)--(0,\x/2);
\draw [yellow,line width=\lw mm](\a,\x/2)--(\x,\b);}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**Update: using `patterns.meta`**

`patterns.meta` library was developped after this question and answers were proposed. So, it's worth to write a possible solution using the library.

The new pattern `Lines` can be used as an alternative to `north east hatch`. And if we want different colors (or patterns) over the same path, `preaction` or `postaction` has to be used to define de second or third pattern.

As you can see in following code, the new library simplifies patterns definitions:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[opacity=0.5, 
pattern={Lines[angle=-45, distance={5pt/sqrt(2)}]}, 
pattern color=yellow,
preaction={%
    pattern={Lines[angle=-45, distance={5pt/sqrt(2)}, xshift=2.5pt]}, 
    pattern color=gray}
] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can `fill` areas with some `pattern`, but you cannot combine `fill` with color and `pattern` on same path. If you want to use both, use `preaction` to fill with color and `pattern` to draw your pattern after filling.

Already predefined patterns use thin lines to draw, therefore if you want to use same width stripes, you need to define your own pattern.

Next you have two examples, both use `preaction` to fill with `gray` and `pattern` to draw orange stripes. First rectangle uses predefined `north west lines` pattern and second one a new `north east hatch`. (Taken from [using pattern inside tikz shapes with dropped shadows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154842/using-pattern-inside-tikz-shapes-with-dropped-shadows/155100#155100))

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{% customization of pattern
         % based on <m.wibrow@gm...> - 2013-03-24 07:20: 
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=5pt
        }
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north east hatch}% name
    {\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Pattern/.style={pattern=north east hatch, pattern color=orange, hatch distance=7pt, hatch thickness=2pt}]

\draw[preaction={fill=gray}, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=orange, draw=red] (0,0) rectangle (2,2.5);

\draw[preaction={fill=gray}, Pattern, draw=red] (2.5,0) rectangle (4.5,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to make north WEST hatch by making change to `\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\hatchdistance}}` and `\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{0pt}}`, but does not look well: line has white teeths.  Do you know what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer I linked to above, below is a solution. The package itself does not give you an easier way I'm afraid. Unless of course you draw the pattern by hand.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

% defining the new dimensions and parameters
\newlength{\hatchspread}
\newlength{\hatchthickness}
\newlength{\hatchshift}
\newcommand{\hatchcolor}{}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{hatchspread/.code={\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1}},
         hatchthickness/.code={\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1}},
         hatchshift/.code={\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1}},% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor/.code={\renewcommand{\hatchcolor}{#1}}}
% setting the default values
\tikzset{hatchspread=3pt,
         hatchthickness=0.4pt,
         hatchshift=0pt,% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor=black}
% declaring the pattern
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
   {custom north west lines}% name
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
   {% shape description
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \ifdim \hatchshift > 0pt
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\hatchshift}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \fi
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
%    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}% dashing cannot work correctly in all situation this way
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
   }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}% hatchshift must be >= 0
\draw[pattern=custom north west lines,hatchthickness=5.5pt,hatchspread=15pt,hatchcolor=gray] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw[pattern=custom north west lines,hatchthickness=5.5pt,hatchspread=15pt,hatchcolor=orange,hatchshift=7.5pt] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```