# Two-color fill pattern with continuous diagonal lines with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

I'm trying to create (with overleaf) a two-color fill pattern with continuous diagonal lines. I have copied most of the code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154842/using-pattern-inside-tikz-shapes-with-dropped-shadows) (many thanks to the stackexchange community). However, my result looks like this:
[image: Fancy Pattern, however not my expectation]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
     Pattern/.style = {pattern=north east hatch,
                    pattern color=yellow,
                    hatch distance=10pt, 
                    hatch thickness=4pt},
  ]

  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);

  \makeatletter
\tikzset{
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=5pt
        }
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north east hatch}% name
    {\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\makeatother
  
 
 \draw[preaction={fill=green}, Pattern] (o) 
    -- ++(1,0) 
    -- ++(0,-1) 
    -- ++(-1,0) 
    --cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There are some bumps on the lines. What's going wrong with my code? How can I remove this bumps.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Update 19:03h:
I used Acrobat Reader, SumatraPDF, and Firefox for viewing, however, similar artifacts occur in all cases.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301) and thanks for including a  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) . It ran fine for me without the bumps. I suspect this is an artifact of your particular pdf viewer.  Trying zooming in and out, or another pdf viewer such as Acrobat Reader.

Comment: I get different "bumps" at different zoom levels in both mac preview and mac adobe.

Comment: you changed the values of hatch distance and hatch thickness.

Comment: Exactly, I changed the thickness and distance because my aim was a pattern with thicker lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By use of `patterns.meta` library the result is far better than with `patterns` (but for pickpockets still not perfect):

[image]

Ar least, code is much, much simpler:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=green,
      postaction={pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={6pt},line width=3pt]},
                  pattern color=yellow},
      postaction={draw, semithick}]
     (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 strange that the typo `(1,)` still compiles

Comment: @hpekristiansen, indeed! Thank you to note it. Corrected now.

Comment: @Zarko: Many thanks for that solution. It looks much better than mine. The funny thing is that in Firefox the pattern looks horrible but in Adobe Acrobat it's depitcted like in your solution.