# How to make a striped, colored circle in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, circles

I want to make something like this[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: Could this work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/643126/47927 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[orange!50!yellow, postaction={pattern={Lines[angle=-45, distance=2mm, line width=1mm]}}] circle[radius=1cm];            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Black and orange striped circle]

**Edit:** The stripes are exact. Any bleed through of color is because of viewer artefacts. It is dependent on the viewer used and dependent on zoom level. It is impossible to totally avoid when there are three colors involved - black, orange and background white.

One possibility is to make orange stripes only a little wider than the black stripes, instead of a full orange circle, so the effect is only at a small distance.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pattern={Lines[angle=-45, distance=2mm, line width=1.1mm, xshift=1.4mm]},  pattern color=orange!50!yellow] circle[radius=1cm];            
\fill[pattern={Lines[angle=-45, distance=2mm, line width=1mm]}] circle[radius=1cm];            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks nice, but there are some yellow dashes spanning the width of the black stripes both in your image and in the result after I compile your code.

Comment: No there are not - see edit and try to zoom in or use an other viewer.

Comment: How can I change the the stripe colors from yellow/black to red/blue? I tried "red!50!blue" but the result looks pretty bad.

Comment: @Gary Use `\fill[blue, pattern color=red, …`. The `\fill` will default to `black` in this case. With `red!50!blue` you just specify a mixed color.

Answer (score 5):

You need not Tikz, if you are using OpTeX. You can do something like this:

```
\hbox{\clipincircle 5mm 5mm 10mm 10mm{%
\pdfsave\pdfrotate{-45}%
   \rlap{\kern-5mm
     \vbox{\fornum 1..10\do {\hrule width5cm height2pt {\Yellow \hrule height2pt}}}}%
\pdfrestore
}}

\bye
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? Does the solution not work? (I can not test it as I do not have OpTeX)

Comment: I show that we don't need to use TikZ for simple tasks like lines in a circle. TeX format didn't be specified by OP. You cannot suppose that this format is LaTeX.