# Elegant hash areas for mathematical graphics...

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sometimes on a graph you need to hash out areas in order to show vividly what the domains are. Is there an elegant way to create these hash areas using an instruction similar to the rectangle one? Would it be possible to hash out the interior of any shape? And it would be awesome if the hash would allow automatically for gaps were notation needed be over-imposed (like for x and 1 in my MWE)... I am aware of the pattern=north east lines, but that one is too rigid, I cannot control the distance between the lines. My MWE is kinda verbose, sorry...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{7.0cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45]% functia PUTERE 2^x
%\clip (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (4.0,4.0);
% grid
%\draw[step = 0.1cm, gray, ultra thin] (-5.0, -1.0) grid (4.0, 0.0);
%
% HASH lines for y < 0
%
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-5.0, -0.1) -- (-4.9, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-5.0, -0.5) -- (-4.5, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-5.0, -1.0) -- (-4.0, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-4.5, -1.0) -- (-3.5, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-4.0, -1.0) -- (-3.0, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-3.5, -1.0) -- (-2.5, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-3.0, -1.0) -- (-2.0, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-2.5, -1.0) -- (-1.5, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-2.0, -1.0) -- (-1.0, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.5, -1.0) -- (-0.5, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -1.0) -- (0.0, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-0.5, -1.0) -- (0.5, 0.0);
% gap for x notation
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (0.0, -1.0) -- (0.4, -0.6);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (0.7, -0.3) -- (1.0, 0.0);
%
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (0.5, -1.0) -- (1.5, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (1.0, -1.0) -- (2.0, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (1.5, -1.0) -- (2.5, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (2.0, -1.0) -- (3.0, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (2.5, -1.0) -- (3.5, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (3.0, -1.0) -- (4.0, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (3.5, -1.0) -- (4.0, -0.5);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (3.9, -1.0) -- (4.0, -0.9);
%
% 
\coordinate (OR) at (0.00, 0.00);
\coordinate (LX) at (-5.00, 0.00); % left x
\coordinate (RX) at (4.00, 0.00); % right x
\coordinate (BY) at (0.00, -1.00); % bottom y
\coordinate (TY) at (0.00, 8.00);
%
% axa 0x
%
\draw[->][line width=1.00pt] (LX) -- (RX);
\node[violet] at (3.8,-0.4) {\textbf{\textit{x}}};
%
% axa 0y
%
\draw[->][line width=1.00pt] (BY) -- (TY);
\node[right,violet] at (0.2, 8.0) {{\boldmath$a^{\raisebox{+4.0pt}{$\scriptstyle{x}$}}$}};
\node[right,violet] at (0.1, 7.3) {{\boldmath$(a \,=\, 2)$}};
%
% ORIGINE
% points on the graphic
\filldraw [red] (OR) circle(2pt);
\node[violet] at (-0.2,-0.3) {\textbf{\textit{0}}};
%
% COORDONATE -- numerotare axa Ox POZITIVA
%
\draw[violet,line width=1pt] (0.50, -0.10) -- (0.50, 0.10); % x = 0.5
\node[violet] at (0.50, -0.40) {\textbf{\textit{x}}}; 
\draw[violet,line width=0.75pt,dotted] (0.50, 0.00) -- (0.50, 1.4142);
\filldraw [violet] (0.50, 1.4142) circle(2pt);
\node[above,violet] at (0.50, 1.4142) {\textbf{\textit{a\textsuperscript{x}}}}; 
%
\draw[line width=1pt] (1.00, -0.10) -- (1.00, 0.10); % x1
\node at (1.00, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{1}$};
\draw[line width=1pt] (2.00, -0.10) -- (2.00, 0.10); % x2
\node at (2.00, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{2}$};
\draw[line width=1pt] (3.00, -0.10) -- (3.00, 0.10); % x3
\node at (3.00, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{3}$};
%
% COORDONATE -- numerotare axa Ox NEGATIVA
%
\draw[line width=1pt] (-1.00, -0.10) -- (-1.00, 0.10); % -x1
\node at (-1.10, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{-1}$};
\draw[line width=1pt] (-2.00, -0.10) -- (-2.00, 0.10); % -x2
\node at (-2.10, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{-2}$};
\draw[line width=1pt] (-3.00, -0.10) -- (-3.00, 0.10); % -x3
\node at (-3.10, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{-3}$};
\draw[line width=1pt] (-4.00, -0.10) -- (-4.00, 0.10); % -x4
\node at (-4.10, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{-4}$};
%
%
% COORDONATE -- numerotare axa Oy POZITIVA
%
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, 1.00) -- (0.10, 1.00); % y1 
\node at (-0.40, 1.00) {$\scriptstyle{1}$};
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, 2.00) -- (0.10, 2.00); % y2 
\node at (-0.40, 2.00) {$\scriptstyle{2}$};
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, 3.00) -- (0.10, 3.00); % y3
\node at (-0.40, 3.00) {$\scriptstyle{3}$};
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, 4.00) -- (0.10, 4.00); % y4 
\node at (-0.40, 4.00) {$\scriptstyle{4}$};
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, 5.00) -- (0.10, 5.00); % y5 
\node at (-0.40, 5.00) {$\scriptstyle{5}$};
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, 6.00) -- (0.10, 6.00); % y6 
\node at (-0.40, 6.00) {$\scriptstyle{6}$};
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, 7.00) -- (0.10, 7.00); % y7 
\node at (-0.40, 7.00) {$\scriptstyle{7}$};
%
% COORDONATE -- numerotare axa Oy NEGATIVA
%
% GRAFICUL functiei 2^x
%
\draw[violet, line width=1.75pt, domain=-5.00:3.00] plot[smooth](\x, {2^(\x)});
%
% filled circles
%
\filldraw [blue] (0.0,1.0) circle(2pt);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%
\hspace*{1.0cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resizebox{8.0cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45]%functia LOGARITM ln x
% grid
%\draw[step = 0.1cm, gray, ultra thin] (-1.0, 0.0) grid (0.0, 2.0);
%
% HASH lines for x < 0
%
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, 2.9) -- (-0.9, 3.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, 2.5) -- (-0.5, 3.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, 2.0) -- (0.0, 3.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, 1.5) -- (0.0, 2.5);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, 1.0) -- (0.0, 2.0);
% gap for 1
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, 0.5) -- (-0.5, 1.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-0.3, 1.2) -- (0.0, 1.5);
%
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, 0.0) -- (0.0, 1.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -0.5) -- (0.0, 0.5);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -1.0) -- (0.0, 0.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -1.5) -- (0.0, -0.5);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -2.0) -- (0.0, -1.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -2.5) -- (0.0, -1.5);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -3.0) -- (0.0, -2.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -3.5) -- (0.0, -2.5);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -4.0) -- (0.0, -3.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -4.5) -- (0.0, -3.5);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -5.0) -- (0.0, -4.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -4.5) -- (0.0, -3.5);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-1.0, -5.0) -- (0.0, -4.0);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-0.5, -5.0) -- (0.0, -4.5);
\draw[red, line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, -5.0) -- (0.0, -4.9);
%
% LOGARITM function
%
%\clip (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (4.0,4.0);
%
% grid, drawn with a step in a specified rectangle
%\draw[step = 0.1cm, gray, ultra thin] (-1.0, -5.0) grid (0.0,3.0);
%
%\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
%
%
%\begin{comment}
% 
\coordinate (OR) at (0.00, 0.00);
\coordinate (LX) at (-1.00, 0.00);
\coordinate (RX) at (8.00, 0.00);
\coordinate (BY) at (0.00, -5.00);
\coordinate (TY) at (0.00, 3.00);
%
% axa 0x
%
\draw[->][line width=1.00pt] (LX) -- (RX);
\node[blue] at (7.8,-0.4) {\textbf{\textit{x}}};
%
% axa 0y
%
\draw[->][line width=1.00pt] (BY) -- (TY);
\node[right,blue] at (0.2, 2.8) {\textbf{\textit{ln x}}};
%
% ORIGIN
% points on the graphic
\filldraw [red] (OR) circle(2pt);
\node[red] at (0.2,-0.3) {\textbf{\textit{0}}};
%
% COORDONATE -- numerotare axa Ox POZITIVA
%
\draw[line width=1pt] (1.00, -0.10) -- (1.00, 0.10); % x1
\node at (1.00, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{1}$};
\draw[line width=1pt] (2.00, -0.10) -- (2.00, 0.10); % x2
\node at (2.00, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{2}$};
\draw[line width=1pt] (3.00, -0.10) -- (3.00, 0.10); % x3
\node at (3.00, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{3}$};
\draw[line width=1pt] (4.00, -0.10) -- (4.00, 0.10); % x4
\node at (4.00, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{4}$};
\draw[line width=1pt] (5.00, -0.10) -- (5.00, 0.10); % x5
\node at (5.00, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{5}$};
\draw[line width=1pt] (6.00, -0.10) -- (6.00, 0.10); % x6
\node at (6.00, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{6}$};
\draw[line width=1pt] (7.00, -0.10) -- (7.00, 0.10); % x7
\node at (7.00, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{7}$};
%
% COORDONATE -- numerotare axa Ox NEGATIVA
%
% COORDONATE -- numerotare axa Oy POZITIVA
%
\draw[magenta, line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, 1.00) -- (0.10, 1.00); % y1 
\node[magenta] at (-0.40, 1.00) {$1$};
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, 2.00) -- (0.10, 2.00); % y2 
\node at (-0.40, 2.00) {$\scriptstyle{2}$};
%
% COORDONATE -- numerotare axa Oy NEGATIVA
%
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, -1.00) -- (0.10, -1.00); % y1 
\node at (-0.40, -1.00) {$\scriptstyle{-1}$};
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, -2.00) -- (0.10, -2.00); % y2 
\node at (-0.40, -2.00) {$\scriptstyle{-2}$};
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, -3.00) -- (0.10, -3.00); % y3
\node at (-0.40, -3.00) {$\scriptstyle{-3}$};
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, -4.00) -- (0.10, -4.00); % y4 
\node at (-0.40, -4.00) {$\scriptstyle{-4}$};
\draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, -5.00) -- (0.10, -5.00); % y5 
\node at (-0.40, -5.00) {$\scriptstyle{-5}$};
%
% COORDINATES for drawing
%
%
\coordinate (EE) at (2.7182, 0.00);
\coordinate (PI) at (3.1415, 0.00);
%
% GRAFICUL functiei LOGARITM
%
\draw[blue, line width=1.75pt, domain=0.01:7.00, samples=500] plot[smooth](\x, {ln(\x)});
%
% filled circles
%
\filldraw [red] (1.00, 0.00) circle(2pt);
%
% punctul e
%
\filldraw [magenta] (EE) circle(2pt);
\node[magenta] at (2.7182, -0.30) {\textbf{\textit{e}}};
\draw[magenta, dotted, line width=1.00pt] (2.7182, 0.00) -- (2.7182, 1.00); % e
\draw[magenta, dotted, line width=1.00pt] (0.00, 1.00) -- (2.7182, 1.00); % e
\filldraw [magenta] (2.7182, 1.00) circle(2pt);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could (should?) use a `foreach` to draw it, as well as to draw the axis tics. Check out the first tutorial in the first part of [the pgf manual](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), for instance section 2.20 p41.

Answer (score 11):

Next code shows how to use define a `pattern` with user defined `\hatchthickness` and `\hatchdistance`. This pattern was taken from [using pattern inside tikz shapes with dropped shadows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154842/using-pattern-inside-tikz-shapes-with-dropped-shadows/155100#155100)

This pattern is used to `fill` a rectangular node which is drawn in background layer:

```
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[fit={(-5,0) (4,-1)}, inner sep=0pt, Pattern] {};
\end{scope}
```

The pattern doesn't consider `holes` but you can `fill=white` all nodes which need to be readable over it:

```
\node[violet,fill=white] at (3.8,-0.4) {\textbf{\textit{x}}};
```

Your code has been reduced with the pattern definition, but also using some `\foreach` loops to draw `ticks`. And I think it could be reduced even more if you used `pgfplots` which is loaded but never used.

Next code shows only left figure. Right one can be easily obtained applying similar tools.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,backgrounds,fit}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{% customization of pattern
         % based on <m.wibrow@gm...> - 2013-03-24 07:20: 
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=5pt
        }
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north east hatch}% name
    {\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\makeatother

\tikzset{Pattern/.style={pattern=north east hatch, 
         pattern color=red, hatch distance=3mm, 
         hatch thickness=1pt}}

\begin{document}

%\resizebox{7.0cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45]% functia PUTERE 2^x
%\clip (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (4.0,4.0);
% grid
%\draw[step = 0.1cm, gray, ultra thin] (-5.0, -1.0) grid (4.0, 0.0);

%
% 
\coordinate (OR) at (0.00, 0.00);
\coordinate (LX) at (-5.00, 0.00); % left x
\coordinate (RX) at (4.00, 0.00); % right x
\coordinate (BY) at (0.00, -1.00); % bottom y
\coordinate (TY) at (0.00, 8.00);
%
% axa 0x
%
\draw[->][line width=1.00pt] (LX) -- (RX);
\node[violet,fill=white] at (3.8,-0.4) {\textbf{\textit{x}}};
%
% axa 0y
%
\draw[->][line width=1.00pt] (BY) -- (TY);
\node[right,violet] at (0.2, 8.0) {{\boldmath$a^{\raisebox{+4.0pt}{$\scriptstyle{x}$}}$}};
\node[right,violet] at (0.1, 7.3) {{\boldmath$(a \,=\, 2)$}};
%
% ORIGINE
% points on the graphic
\filldraw [red] (OR) circle(2pt);
\node[violet,fill=white] at (-0.2,-0.3) {\textbf{\textit{0}}};
%
% COORDONATE -- numerotare axa Ox POZITIVA
%
\draw[violet,line width=1pt] (0.50, -0.10) -- (0.50, 0.10); % x = 0.5
\node[violet,fill=white] at (0.50, -0.40) {\textbf{\textit{x}}}; 
\draw[violet,line width=0.75pt,dotted] (0.50, 0.00) -- (0.50, 1.4142);
\filldraw [violet] (0.50, 1.4142) circle(2pt);
\node[above,violet] at (0.50, 1.4142) {\textbf{\textit{a\textsuperscript{x}}}}; 
%

\foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,3}{
 \draw[line width=1pt] (1.00*\i, -0.10) -- ++(90:0.20); % x1
 \node[fill=white] at (1.00*\i, -0.40) {$\scriptstyle{\i}$};}

%
% COORDONATE -- numerotare axa Oy POZITIVA
%
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{
    \draw[line width=1.00pt] (-0.1, \i) -- ++(0:0.20); % y1 
    \node at (-0.40, \i) {$\scriptstyle{\i}$};
    }
%
% COORDONATE -- numerotare axa Oy NEGATIVA
%
% GRAFICUL functiei 2^x
%
\draw[violet, line width=1.75pt, domain=-5.00:3.00] plot[smooth](\x, {2^(\x)});
%
% filled circles
%
\filldraw [blue] (0.0,1.0) circle(2pt);
%
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[fit={(-5,0) (4,-1)}, inner sep=0pt, Pattern] {};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**Update**

Thank you to Gonzalo Medina, we have a `pgfplots` version for this figure:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,backgrounds,fit}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{% customization of pattern
         % based on <m.wibrow@gm...> - 2013-03-24 07:20:
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=5pt
        }
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north east hatch}% name
    {\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\makeatother

\tikzset{Pattern/.style={pattern=north east hatch,
         pattern color=#1, hatch distance=3mm,
         hatch thickness=1pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  ymax=8,
  ymin=-1,
  xmax=3.5,
  clip=false,
  xtick={-4,-3,...,3},
  ytick={1,2,...,8},
  x tick label style={fill=white}
  ]
\addplot[violet, line width=1.75pt, domain=-5.00:3.00] {2^(x)};

\node[violet,fill=white]
  at (axis cs:3.8,-0.4) {\textbf{\textit{x}}};
\node[right,violet]
  at (axis cs:0.2, 8.0)
  {{\boldmath$a^{x}$}};
\node[right,violet]
  at (axis cs:0.1, 7.3) {{\boldmath$(a \,=\, 2)$}};
\filldraw[red] (axis cs:0,0) circle(2pt);
\draw[violet,line width=0.75pt,dotted]
  (axis cs:0.50, 0.00) -- (axis cs:0.50, 1.4142);
\filldraw[violet] (axis cs:0.50, 1.4142) circle(2pt)
  node[above,violet]
    at (axis cs:0.50, 1.4142)
    {\textbf{\textit{a\textsuperscript{x}}}};
\filldraw[blue] (axis cs:0.0,1.0) circle(2pt);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[fit={(axis cs:-5,0) (axis cs:3.5,-1.3)}, inner sep=0pt, Pattern=cyan] {};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: Naive questions about pgfplots not being used: does plot[smooth] come from somewhere else? What is then so specific (and desirable) to pgfplots?

Comment: @Diegis: Replace `\usepackage{plgplots}` by `\usepackage{tikz}` and will get same results. `plot[smooth]` is a `tikz` command. Did you look at [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) documentation? At least it provides `axis` environment which avoids you typing all commands for axis and marks. May be you don't like its default appearance, but almost everything can be changed. If you need to type a lot of graphics like these, I think it's worth to take a look at it.

Comment: @Ignasi I wrote a `pgfplots` approach, but instead of writing another answer, I think that, if you agree, it could be added to your answer. What do you think?

Comment: @Ignasi in case you want to add the code to your nice answer, which I've upvoted ;), here it is: http://pastebin.com/4wkZhz2Q

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thank you for your code, I've included it.

Comment: @Diegis If you want to look at it, Gonzalo Medina has written a `pgfplots` solution for your figure. Following his suggestion, I've included it in my answer. No you can better decide about using `pgfplots` or pure `TiKZ` code for this kind of figures.

Answer (score 3):

I took the liberty to draw one of the examples with the `mfpic` package,
which comes with a macro precisely built for those kind of problems:

```
\thatch[<hatchsp>,<angle>][<color>]<closed path>
```

It fills any closed path with lines at `<angle>`degrees, separated from each other by a distance of `hatchsp`. Another macro, `\hatchwd{}` macro specifies the width of those lines. There is also two other hatching macros as variants of `\thatch` with predefined angles, `\rhatch` (going from lower left to upper right) and `\lhatch` (going from lower right to upper left).

In this example all the hatching work is done by the following instructions:

```
\hatchwd{1pt}
\rhatch[3mm][Cyan]\rect{(\xmin, \ymin), (\xmax, 0)}
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multido, xcolor}
\usepackage[metapost, clip, overlaylabels]{mfpic}
    \setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
    \opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}[1]{-7}{3.9}{-1.5}{8.9}
    % Function
    \penwd{1pt}
    \fdef{f}{x}{2**x}
   \draw[magenta]\function{\xmin, \xmax, 0.05}{f(x)}    
   % Hatching
   \hatchwd{1pt}
   \rhatch[3mm][Cyan]\rect{(\xmin, \ymin), (\xmax, 0)}
   % Axes and marks
   \penwd{.5pt}
   \doaxes{xy}
   \xmarks{ceiling(\xmin) upto -1}\xmarks{1 upto floor(\xmax)}
   \ymarks{ceiling(\ymin) upto -1}\ymarks{2 upto floor(\ymax)}
   \pointcolor{red}\point[4pt]{(0, 0)}
   \pointcolor{blue}\point[4pt]{(0, 1)}
   % Labels
   \setrender{\gclear}
   \tlpointsep{3pt}
    \tlabelrect[][tr](0, 0){$O$} 
    \tlabelrect[][tc](\xmax, 0){$x$} 
    \tlabel[cr](0, \ymax){$y$}
    \tlpointsep{6pt}
    \tlpathsep{1pt}
    \multido{\i=\xmin+1}{-\xmin}{\tlabelrect[][tc](\i, 0){$\i$}}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{\xmax}{\tlabelrect[][tc](\i, 0){$\i$}}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{\ymax}{\tlabel[cr](0, \i){$\i$}}
    \tlabelrect[][cr](0, -1){$-1$}
    \drawcolor{magenta}
    \dashed\lines{(0.5, 0), (0.5, 1.414)}
    \tlabel[cr](3, 8){\textcolor{magenta}{$a^x (a=2)$}}
    \tlabel[bc](0.5, 1.414){\textcolor{magenta}{$a^x$}}
    \tlabelrect[][tc](0.5, 0){\textcolor{magenta}{$x$}}
\end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

To be compiled with LaTeX first (no matter the engine), then the resulting `.mp` file with MetaPost, and then the `.tex` file again with LaTeX.

[image]