# Dashed border but custom shape

Tags: tcolorbox, border

I know that `tcolorbox` can have dashed border. However the stripes are rectangular. But is it possible to change the rectangles to parallelograms (45 angled) with inner and outer border as well, such as

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with a `tcboxedraster` which contains only one `tcolorbox`. The envolving box contains the pattern and the inner box covers part of it imitating the slanted dash.

The pattern definition was taken from [using pattern inside tikz shapes with dropped shadows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154842/1952)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{% customization of pattern
         % based on <m.wibrow@gm...> - 2013-03-24 07:20: 
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=5pt
        }
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north east hatch}% name
    {\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    Pattern/.style={
        pattern=north east hatch,
        pattern color=black,
        hatch distance=15pt, 
        hatch thickness=5pt
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcboxedraster}[%
    raster columns=1,
    colframe=black,
    colback=white,
    ]{
    enhanced,
    colframe=black, 
    colback=white,
    underlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[Pattern] (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
        }
    }
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcboxedraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! how do you know all this stuff?

Comment: Reading packages documentation and trying to answer questions here.