# Combine fill and pattern in a pgfplot boxplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, boxplot

Is it possible to combine a pattern with a background color in Pgfplot boxplot?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
ytick={1},
yticklabels={Index 0},
]
\addplot+[
boxplot prepared={ median=1, upper quartile=1.,  lower quartile=0.5, upper whisker=1.5, lower whisker=0. },
fill=green,
draw=red,
pattern=north east lines,
] coordinates {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It seems that pattern and fill cannot be combined.  Any Idea?

I also tried using `postaction` as mentioned in [How to combine fill and pattern in a pgfplot bar plot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24964/how-to-combine-fill-and-pattern-in-a-pgfplot-bar-plot)

```
\addplot+[boxplot prepared={  median=1,  upper quartile=1.,  lower quartile=0.5,   upper whisker=1.5,  lower whisker=0.},
 fill=green,
 draw=red,  
 postaction={pattern=north east lines}
 ] coordinates {};
```

The boxplot result is the following

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25032/121799.

Comment: @marmot ... Possibly my mistake, but trying to do it and it doesn't show the pattern but just the green fill. Can you please add it as an answer with the exact code?

Comment: @marmot: Ok... got it... need the way with nomorepostaction of the accepted answer

Comment: @koleygr Yes, that's true.