# Change style of labels of Tikz nodes of a given style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How can all labels of a given type of node be restyled in Tikz?

Imagine that there are nodes of different styles, and that only the nodes of style X should have red labels. Is this possible without having to change all labels one by one of nodes of style X?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To change it for *all* nodes:

```
\tikzset{every node/.style={<style_specs>}}
```

If you have a custom style, you can set this only for that specific node style:

```
\tikzset{My Style/.style={red, draw=blue, fill=yellow!20, minimum size=0.5cm}}
```

If you want to change an existing node style, you can use `.append style` to add to the nodes style specs:

```
\tikzset{rectangle/.append style={draw=brown, ultra thick, fill=red!30}}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{My Style/.style={red, draw=blue, fill=yellow!20, minimum size=0.5cm}}
\tikzset{rectangle/.append style={draw=brown, ultra thick, fill=red!30}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [My Style] at (0,0) {$x$};
    \node [My Style] at (1,0) {$y$};

    \node [rectangle] at (2,0) {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

This actual intent here is more complex that what I thought since a label is actually a node.  One solution would be to define a style for each particluar shape. So, for instance, for a `rectangle` you could define `My Rectangle` as:

```
\tikzset{My Rectangle/.style={
    rectangle, draw=brown, fill=yellow, thick,
    prefix after command= {\pgfextra{\tikzset{every label/.style={blue}}}}
    }
}
```

which alters the label style (Again, thanks to percusse):

[image]

You could also just change the `rectangle` style as follows:

```
\tikzset{rectangle/.append style={
    prefix after command= {\pgfextra{\tikzset{every label/.style={blue}}}}
    }
}
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{My Rectangle/.style={
    rectangle, draw=brown, fill=yellow, thick,
    prefix after command= {\pgfextra{\tikzset{every label/.style={blue}}}}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [rectangle,    label=black text] at (1,0) {$z$};
    \node [My Rectangle, label={blue text} ] at (3,0) {$z$};
    \node [rectangle, label={blue text} ] at (5,0) {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am looking for something like \tikzset{X/.style={label={[red]:...}}}` for example, to change the color of the labels of node X to red.

Comment: @mljrg see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49113/11241

Comment: Can I set a text to this new style?

Comment: @hola: Not sure I understand what you are asking as the `\tikzset` defines a new style. If you want to have it applied ALL the time, then you can use `\tikzset{every node/.style={My Rectangle}}`. If that doesn't solve your question, perhaps you need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 24):

***Prolog:***
*After Peter Grill [undeleted his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78690/16595) my answer becomes kind of* `null`*.

But maybe someone else can profit from it in some way …*

## What  does not work

Surprisingly (to me anyway) the following will turn the node's text itself green.

```
\tikzset{X/.style={label/.style={green}}}
\node[X,label=hello] {X};
```

The existing `every label/.style` definition apparently works only in a scope-like usage.

```
\begin{scope}[every label/.style={green}]
    \node[X,label=hello] {X};
    % and a lot of other X nodes
\end{scope}
```

Adding the `every label/.style` to the definition of `X` fails (with no change to the output):

```
\tikzset{X/.style={every label/.style={green}}}
\node[label=hello] {X};
```

## What does work

The `/.style` can have one argument:

```
\tikzset{X/.style={
    % your styles here, e.g.
    draw,
    circle,
    % and …
    label={[green]#1}
    }
}
\node[X=hello] {X};
\node[X={[draw]hello}] {Y}; % this fails, you can't add an extra optional argument
```

## My proposal

I'd use the `.style args` key handler, where one can set the argument pattern to `[#1]#2`. Note, that the `[]` are not mandatory!

The key handler `.style 2 args` has also two arguments where *the second one* is optional, but it requires you to write `X={hello}` or `X={hello}{draw}`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{X/.style args={[#1]#2}{
    % your styles here, e.g.
    draw,
    circle,
    % and …
    label={[green,#1]#2}
    }
}
\node[X={[]hello}] {X};
\node[X={[draw]hello}] at (1,0) {Y};
\node[X={[red]hello}] at (2,0) {Z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

### Furthermore

I believe there is a solution hidden in the answers of [Optional arguments in pgfkeys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39834/optional-arguments-in-pgfkeys). But they all appear to require to write `[draw]{hello}`.