# Comprehensive list of TikZ style options?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels, tikz-styles

I'm aware that one can use `\tikzstyle{every label}=[...]` to apply styles to every label within a `tikzpicture`; or `\tikzset{mystyle/.style={...}}` to apply style specs to a specific type of node `mystyle` (from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78690/10906)); however, I'm having trouble finding style specs that meet my needs, mostly because I don't know what types of options are valid Ti*k*Z and what aren't.

For example, I wanted the labels `x`, `y`, and `z` in the take-grant diagram below to be in bold roman type, but not the labels on the edges.  It turned out that adding the `\tikzstyle{every label}=[font=\bfseries]` was what I needed, but it took a lot of mostly fruitless searching before I found that.  Is there a **concise resource** which lists all of the style specs one can use?

More generally, although the [Ti*k*Z manual](http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) gives lots of thorough examples of using options for nodes, paths, and styles, it does not appear to be comprehensive.  Am I missing something?  Are there **better resources for enumerating options in general?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,topaths}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',semithick,auto]
    \tikzstyle{subj} = [circle, minimum width=8pt, fill, inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{obj}  = [circle, minimum width=8pt, draw, inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{dc}   = [circle, minimum width=8pt, draw, inner sep=0pt, path picture={\draw (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west) (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);}]

    \tikzstyle{every label}=[font=\bfseries]

    % Before diagram .........................
    \node[obj,  label=below:x] (xa) at (0,0) {};
    \node[subj, label=below:z] (za) at (1,0) {};
    \node[dc,   label=below:y] (ya) at (2,0) {};

    \path[->]   (za)    edge                node[swap]  {$t$}       (xa)
                        edge                node        {$\alpha$}  (ya);

    \node at (3,0) {$\vdash^{*}$};

    % After diagram .........................
    \node[obj,  label=below:x] (xb) at (4,0) {};
    \node[subj, label=below:z] (zb) at (5,0) {};
    \node[dc,   label=below:y] (yb) at (6,0) {};

    \path[->]   (zb)    edge                node[swap]  {$t$}       (xb)
                        edge                node        {$\alpha$}  (yb)
                (xb)    edge[bend left=60]  node        {$\alpha$}  (yb);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is the output you get from your code? Maybe you have placed your TikZ picture inside a math environment or the text is in italics before the TikZ picture.

Comment: Doh!  I had it inside of a `lemma` on my end of things (which doesn't yet have any text, so I didn't notice it was italicizing everything).  Edited the question and output accordingly.  Though the specific problem is solved, the underlying question still remains.

Comment: Related: [Summary of Tikz commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84753), especially [Andrew Stacey’s non-community-wiki answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84961/16595). Also related: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372) (`\tikzstyle` only sets `/.style`, there are many more handlers.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The summary of Ti<i>k</i>Z commands does indeed look useful, but in a way, is the opposite of what I'm looking for.  I'm interested in a comprehensive list of **options**.  For example, when [Andrew Stacey's CW answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84757/10906) says `draw[=<colour specification>]`, what counts as `<colour specification>`?

Comment: Yes, there are not a lot of _macros_. Options (of styles or …?) are an awful lot out there. I was hoping that that question actually would produce a comprehensive lists of keys, their values and their effect. The PGF manual does already explain every key and every option in much detail. To answer your example: That has not so much to do with PGF/TikZ, but with `(x)color` because these specifications are just forwarded to the underlying color engine. Although there are many examples in the TikZ manual, the `xcolor` manual probably offers you more help.

Comment: And to hopefully minimize the confusion: `\tikzstyle{<name of style>}=[<stuff>]` does nothing else than `\tiktset{<name of style>/.style={<stuff>}}`. So you could actually apply `every label/.style={font=\bfseries}` to a node with labels, to a path with nodes with labels, to a scope with nodes with labels or …. In the case of the `every node/.style` there is even a short-cut: the `nodes` key. Issuing `nodes=<stuff>` does nothing else but `every node/.style={<stuff>}`. Conclusion: Oftentimes keys are short-cuts to other keys and nest deeply .

Comment: There are 765 keys documented by the pgfmanual!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Here is a list of 710 keys (automatically extracted from the pgfmanual):

```
>
above
above delimiter
above left
above left of
above of
above right
above right of
absolute
accepting text
accepting where
alias
align
allow upside down
ampersand replacement
anchor
and gate
and gate IEC symbol
append after command
arrow box arrows
arrow box east arrow
arrow box head extend
arrow box head indent
arrow box north arrow
arrow box shaft width
arrow box south arrow
arrow box tip angle
arrow box west arrow
arrows
aspect
at
auto
ball color
bar interval shift
bar interval width
bar shift
bar width
base left
baseline
base right
below
below delimiter
below left
below left of
below of
below right
below right of
bend
bend angle
bend left
bend pos
bend right
bottom color
buffer gate IEC symbol
callout absolute pointer
callout pointer arc
callout pointer end size
callout pointer segments
callout pointer shorten
callout pointer start size
callout pointer width
callout relative pointer
cells
chain default direction
chamfered rectangle angle
chamfered rectangle corners
chamfered rectangle sep
chamfered rectangle xsep
chamfered rectangle ysep
child anchor
circle connection bar switch color
circle through
circuit declare annotation
circuit declare symbol
circuit declare unit
circuit ee
circuit ee IEC
circuit handle symbol
circuit logic
circuit logic CDH
circuit logic IEC
circuit logic US
circuits
circuit symbol size
circuit symbol unit
circular drop shadow
circular glow
circular sector angle
clip
clockwise from
cloud ignores aspect
cloud puff arc
cloud puffs
cm
color
colored tokens
column sep
concept color
connect spies
const plot
const plot mark left
const plot mark right
continue branch
continue chain
controls
copy shadow
counterclockwise from
cs/angle
cs/first line
cs/first node
cs/horizontal line through
cs/name
cs/node
cs/point
cs/radius
cs/second line
cs/second node
cs/solution
cs/vertical line through
cs/x
cs/x radius
cs/y
cs/y radius
cs/z
current point is local
curve to
cylinder body fill
cylinder end fill
cylinder uses custom fill
dart tail angle
dart tip angle
dash pattern
dash phase
data/format
data/headline
data/samples
data/separator
data/source
data visualization/about
data visualization/about strategy
data visualization/after creation
data visualization/after survey
data visualization/after visualization
data visualization/arg1
data visualization/arg1 from key
data visualization/arg1 handle from key
data visualization/at end survey
data visualization/at end visualization
data visualization/at start survey
data visualization/at start visualization
data visualization/axis options/exponential steps
data visualization/axis options/linear steps
data visualization/axis options/tick placement strategy
data visualization/before creation
data visualization/before survey
data visualization/before visualization
data visualization/class
data visualization/compute step
data visualization/euro about strategy
data visualization/few
data visualization/half about strategy
data visualization/int about strategy
data visualization/many
data visualization/new object
data visualization/none
data visualization/phase
data visualization/quarter about strategy
data visualization/school book axes
data visualization/school book axes standard labels
data visualization/scientific axes
data visualization/scientific axes end labels
data visualization/scientific axes standard labels
data visualization/scientific axes upright labels
data visualization/scientific clean axes
data visualization/scientific inner axes
data visualization/some
data visualization/step
data visualization/store
data visualization/uv axes
data visualization/uv Cartesian
data visualization/uvw axes
data visualization/uvw Cartesian cabinet
data visualization/when
data visualization/xy axes
data visualization/xy Cartesian
data visualization/xyz axes
data visualization/xyz Cartesian cabinet
dates
day code
day text
day xshift
day yshift
declare function
decorate
decoration
decoration/amplitude
decoration/anchor
decoration/angle
decoration/aspect
decoration automaton/auto corner on length
decoration automaton/auto end on length
decoration automaton/if input segment is closepath
decoration automaton/next state
decoration automaton/persistent postcomputation
decoration automaton/persistent precomputation
decoration automaton/repeat state
decoration automaton/switch if input segment less than
decoration automaton/switch if less than
decoration automaton/width
decoration/closepath code
decoration/curveto code
decoration/end radius
decoration/foot angle (initially 10)
decoration/foot length (initially 10pt)
decoration/foot of (initially human)
decoration/foot sep (initially 4pt)
decoration/lineto code
decoration/mark
decoration/mark connection node
decoration/mark info/distance from start
decoration/mark info/sequence number
decoration/meta-amplitude
decoration/meta-segment length
decoration/mirror
decoration/moveto code
decoration/name
decoration/path has corners
decoration/pre
decoration/pre length
decoration/raise
decoration/reset marks
decoration/reverse path
decoration/segment length
decoration/shape
decoration/shape end height
decoration/shape end width
decoration/shape evenly spread
decoration/shape height
decoration/shape scaled
decoration/shape sep
decoration/shape size
decoration/shape sloped
decoration/shape start height
decoration/shape start width
decoration/shape width
decorations/post
decorations/post length
decoration/start radius
decoration/stride length (initially 30pt)
decoration/text
decoration/text align
decoration/text align/align
decoration/text align/fit to path
decoration/text align/fit to path stretching spaces
decoration/text align/left indent
decoration/text align/right indent
decoration/text color
decoration/text format delimiters
decoration/transform
delta angle
direction ee arrow
distance
domain
double
double arrow head extend
double arrow head indent
double arrow tip angle
double copy shadow
double distance
double distance between line centers
draw
draw opacity
drop shadow
edge from parent path
end angle
even odd rule
every year
execute after day scope
execute at begin cell
execute at begin day scope
execute at begin picture
execute at begin scope
execute at begin to
execute at empty cell
execute at end cell
execute at end day scope
execute at end picture
execute at end scope
execute at end to
execute before day scope
external/export
external/export next
external/figure list
external/figure name
external/force remake
external/mode
external/only named
external/optimize
external/optimize command away
external/optimize/install
external/optimize/restore
external/prefix
external/remake next
external/shell escape
external/system call
external/verbose
external/verbose IO
external/verbose optimize
face 1
face 12
face 2
face 3
fading angle
fading transform
fill
fill opacity
fit
fit fading
fixed point arithmetic
fixed point/scale file plot x
fixed point/scale file plot y
fixed point/scale file plot z
fixed point/scale results
folding line length
font
foreach/count
foreach/evaluate
foreach/remember
foreach/var
fpu
fpu/handlers/empty number
fpu/handlers/invalid number
fpu/handlers/wrong lowlevel format
fpu/output format
fpu/rel thresh
fpu/scale results
general shadow
generic circle IEC/before background
generic diode IEC/before background
grow
grow'
grow cyclic
growth function
growth parent anchor
grow via three points
height
id
if
images/external info
images/include external (initially \pgfimage{#1})
in
in control
in distance
info
info'
info sloped
info' sloped
initial text
initial where
in looseness
in max distance
in min distance
inner color
inner frame sep
inner frame xsep
inner frame ysep
inner sep
inner xsep
inner ysep
inputs
insert path
intersection/by
intersection/name
intersection/of
intersection/sort by
intersection/total
intial distance
isosceles triangle apex angle
isosceles triangle stretches
join
jump mark left
jump mark right
key filter handlers/append filtered to
key filter handlers/ignore
key filter handlers/log
key filters/active families
key filters/active families and known
key filters/active families or descendants of
key filters/active families or no family
key filters/active families or no family DEBUG
key filters/and
key filters/defined
key filters/equals
key filters/false
key filters/is descendant of
key filters/not
key filters/or
key filters/true
kite lower vertex angle
kite upper vertex angle
kite vertex angles
label
label distance
label position
late options
left
left color
left delimiter
left of
lens
level distance
light emitting
lindenmayer system/anchor
lindenmayer system/axiom
lindenmayer system/left angle
lindenmayer system/name
lindenmayer system/order
lindenmayer system/randomize angle percent
lindenmayer system/randomize step percent
lindenmayer system/right angle
lindenmayer system/rule set
lindenmayer system/step
line cap
line join
line to
line width
local bounding box
logic gate anchors use bounding box
logic gate IEC symbol align
logic gate IEC symbol color
logic gate inputs
logic gate input sep
logic gate inverted radius
loop
looseness
lower left
magnification
magnifying glass handle angle aspect
magnifying glass handle angle fill
mark
mark color
mark indices
mark options
mark phase
mark repeat
mark size
matrix
matrix anchor
matrix of math nodes
matrix of nodes
max distance
meta-decoration automaton/next state
meta-decoration automaton/switch if less than
meta-decoration automaton/width
middle color
mid left
mid right
min distance
minimum height
minimum size
minimum width
missing
miter limit
month code
month text
month xshift
month yshift
move to
name
name intersections
nand gate IEC symbol
node distance
node halign header
nodes
nodes in empty cells
nonzero rule
nor gate IEC symbol
not gate IEC symbol
number format/assume math mode
number format/@dec sep mark
number format/fixed
number format/fixed zerofill
number format/frac
number format/frac denom
number format/frac shift
number format/frac TeX
number format/frac whole
number format/int detect
number format/int trunc
number format/min exponent for 1000 sep
number format/precision
number format/sci
number format/sci 10e
number format/sci 10^e
number format/sci e
number format/sci E
number format/@sci exponent mark
number format/sci generic
number format/sci generic/exponent
number format/sci generic/mantissa sep
number format/sci precision
number format/sci subscript
number format/sci superscript
number format/sci zerofill
number format/set decimal separator
number format/set thousands separator
number format/showpos
number format/skip 0.
number format/use comma
number format/use period
ohm
on background layer
on chain
on grid
only marks
opacity
or gate IEC symbol
out
out control
out distance
outer color
outer frame sep
outer frame xsep
outer frame ysep
outer sep
outer xsep
outer ysep
out looseness
out max distance
out min distance
overlay
parabola height
parametric
parent anchor
path fading
path picture
pattern
pattern color
pin
pin distance
pin edge
pin position
point down
point left
point right
point up
polar comb
pos
postaction
preactions
prefix
prefix after command
radius
random starburst
raw gnuplot
rectangle split allocate boxes
rectangle split draw splits
rectangle split empty part depth
rectangle split empty part height
rectangle split empty part width
rectangle split horizontal
rectangle split ignore empty parts
rectangle split part align
rectangle split part fill
rectangle split parts
rectangle split use custom fill
regular polygon sides
relative
remember picture
reset cm
resistor
right
right color
right delimiter
right of
rotate
rotate around
rotate fit
rounded corners
rounded rectangle arc length
rounded rectangle east arc
rounded rectangle west arc
row sep
samples
samples at
scale
scale around
scope fading
shade
shading
shading angle
shadow scale
shadow xshift
shadow yshift
shape
shape aspect
shape border rotate
shape border uses incircle
sharp corners
sharp plot
shift
shift only
shorten <
shorten >
sibling angle
sibling distance
signal from
signal pointer angle
signal to
single arrow head extend
single arrow head indent
single arrow tip angle
size
sloped
smooth
smooth cycle
spy connection path
spy scope
spy using outlines
spy using overlays
starburst point height
starburst points
star point height
star point ratio
star points
start angle
start branch
start chain
step
stepx
stepy
structured tokens
swap
tape bend bottom
tape bend height
tape bend top
tension
tex4ht node/class
tex4ht node/css
tex4ht node/escape
tex4ht node/id
text
text/at
text/base
text/bottom
text depth
text height
text/left
text mark
text mark as node
text mark style
text opacity
text/right
text/rotate
text width
text/x
text/y
token distance
tokens
to path
top color
transform canvas
transform shape
transparency group
trapezium left angle
trapezium right angle
trapezium stretches
trapezium stretches body
trim left
trim lowlevel
trim right
turtle
turtle/back
turtle/bk
turtle/distance
turtle/fd
turtle/forward
turtle/home
turtle/left
turtle/lt
turtle/right
turtle/rt
upper left
upper right
use as bounding box
variable
width
x
xbar
xbar interval
xcomb
xnor gate IEC symbol
xor gate IEC symbol
x radius
xscale
xshift
xslant
xstep
y
ybar
ybar interval
ycomb
year code
year text
y radius
yscale
yshift
yslant
ystep
z
```

**Edit:**

Here is a command to extract automatically all the *documented* keys from the TeX files of pgfmanual (the result is not perfect):

```
find . -iname '*.tex' -print0 \
  | xargs -0 perl -lane 'if (m<\\begin\{(?:style)?key}\{/([^=}(]*)=>){print "$1"}' \
     | sort
```

Comment: Of course a comment to each would be ideal ... It is only 710!!! . Obviously I'm kidding ... :)

Comment: This could be turned into a wiki, so that the community can add a comment to each, or at least to some.

Comment: I guess if each of those keys had an explanation with it, we'd just end up with the manual again...

Comment: @Jake, it could be a short explanation, only as a reminder and not a complete reference. Also, these keys could be separated in two lists, one for frequented used and other for rarely used, in order to facilitate looku ps.

Comment: I love automated approaches :-) Instead of a short manual explanation, we maybe could automatically add the respective chapter heading and pgfmanual page number (maybe from the aux file) as a reference to each item.

Comment: **This is great!** I agree, it would also be helpful to have some idea of what _values_ these keys can take, since a large part of my particular trouble was determining that `font=` was expecting something like `\bfseries` and not, say, `\textbf`.  Since it seems many specifications are specific to various packages or engines (e.g., valid color specifications depend on the color engine used), perhaps even just "where to find more" would be good enough for some.

Comment: @TimParenti There is an index at the end of the manual. Keys are also marked.

Comment: @Paul could you share the script you used to extract the list? It could be useful to keep it up-to-date with new versions of pgf...

Comment: @Bordaigorl Done...