# How to mirror / flip node in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Some components in Circuitikz use nodes intead of path decorations, so transforming them with invert or mirror does not work. For example, the spdt switch in the image always has its single wire side on the left, even if the whole image is flipped using xscale=-1 as a tikzpicture environment property.

[image: spdt switch]

Example code:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (5, 0) to (0, 0) node[spdt] {};
\begin{circuitikz}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add some code to show what you're dealing with?

Comment: Please can you make your code compilable? Especially if the answer you've got doesn't help, something people can compile makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nodes can be rotated using the `node[rotate=90] {}` property (replace 90 with the angle you want, can be negative) and flipped in a certain direction by using either `node[xscale=-1]` or `node[yscale=-1]` or both. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95144/99411) provides a list of all possible node / style attributes in Tikz.

Comment: The answer is not self-contained. It's like a comment, or like booze talk hearing somebody say something