# tikz: Pre- and postfix for every node's text

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

In order to configure a node's line spacing for multi-line text I am forced to preface the text with `\baselineskip=2.5ex` and append an additional `\par` after it inside every single node. Is there a way to avoid doing this repeatedly?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture, overlay,
    every node/.style={fill=green, font=\large}
      ]
  \node (N0)
    at (0,0)
    {Start}; % <- That's what I want for multi-line text: Only the text
  \node[right=of N0, text width=3cm, align=center] (N1)
    {\baselineskip=2.5ex Looooooooooong multi-line text.\par}; % <- That's what's required
  \node[right=of N1, text width=3cm, align=center] (N2)
    {\baselineskip=2.5ex Another looooooooooong multi-line text.\par};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Are there node style parameters to define such pre- and postfix commands? [There exist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95120/comprehensive-list-of-tikz-style-options) `postaction` and `preactions` parameters which don't help me. The following code does not produce correct linespacing (the `\par` seems to be ignored).

```
%...
    every node/.style={fill=green, font=\large, postaction={\par}}
%...
  \node[right=of N1, text width=3cm, align=center] (N2)
    {\baselineskip=2.5ex Another looooooooooong multi-line text.};
%...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Although the code snippets you show are quite detailed, it's not easy for potential helpers to actually debug it.  Please extend your example to a small, easily compilable file, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that can be copy-pasted for experimentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Did so, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any need for the `\par`, but you can use `/tikz/execute at begin node` and `/tikz/execute at end node`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={fill=green, font=\large},
    execute at begin node={\baselineskip=5ex\relax},
    % execute at end node={\endgraf}% not needed, as far as I can see
    ]
  \node (N0) at (0,0) {Start};
  \node[right=of N0, text width=3.2cm, align=center] (N1)
    {Looooooooooong multi-line text.};
  \node[right=of N1, text width=3.2cm, align=center] (N2)
    {Another looooooooooong multi-line text.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed the unneeded `remember picture, overlay`, increased the 3cm to 3.2cm to avoid an overfull `\hbox` in the second node and increased your `\baselineskip=2.5ex` to `\baselineskip=5ex` in order to make its effect more visible. The `\relax` ensures that TeX doesn't try to expand tokens after the `5ex` when reading the value assigned to `\baselineskip`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `font`. See whether this works for you. I use `\baselineskip=5ex` to emphasize the difference.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture, overlay,
    every node/.style={fill=green, font=\large},
    baselineskip/.style={font={\large\baselineskip=#1}}
  ]
  \node (N0)
    at (0,0)
    {Start}; % <- That's what I want for multi-line text: Only the text
  \node[right=of N0, text width=3cm, align=center,baselineskip=5ex] (N1)
    {Looooooooooong multi-line text.}; % <- That's what's required
  \node[right=of N1, text width=3cm, align=center,baselineskip=5ex] (N2)
    {Another looooooooooong multi-line text.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot. Although it solves my actual problem, it does not answer the question. I'll wait a little bit before I accept the answer. Maybe someone else will chime in.

Comment: @Jersey Glad to help. If my answer answers the question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: +1 You could also use the key `node font` for `baselineskip`, this allows you to avoid the duplication of `\large`. ` baselineskip/.style={node font={\baselineskip=#1}`.