# TikZ pre- and append text/commands to all rectangle nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to pre- and append code (text and commands) to all nodes with the `rectangle` option?

I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521188/tikz-pre-and-postfix-for-every-nodes-text) which explains how to execute a command before every node, but this does not allow me to insert visible text, at least not when I tried it.

Edit:

```latex
\tikzset{
  ell/.style={
    % The shape:
    ellipse,
    %minimum width=6mm,
    minimum height=6mm,
    % The rest
    inner sep=0,
    draw=black,
    fill=white,
    font=\ttfamily},
  skip loop/.style={to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}}
}

{
  \tikzset{ell/.append style={text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=latex,thick,
    /pgf/every decoration/.style={/tikz/sharp corners},
    line join=round,line cap=round,
    fuzzy/.style={decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=0.5mm,amplitude=0.15pt}},
  ]

    \ttfamily
    \begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below,
            node distance=1mm,
            every node/.append style={on chain, scale=0.7,
                minimum width=5cm, align=center},
            every ell node/.append style={
                execute at begin node=(,
                execute at end node=)},
        scale=0.7,
        ]
        \node [ell] (stmt01) {2.  \verb|z = 20|};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome! Yes, it is.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every rectangle node/.append style={
    execute at begin node=bla\space,
    execute at end node=\space pft}]
    \path node[rectangle] {hello} (0,-1) node[rectangle] {world};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since rectangle is the default,

```
 \path node {hello} (0,-1) node {world};
```

yields the same result.

**UPDATE**: As for your updated question, `ell` is not a shape but a style.  So instead of `every ell node/.append style=` you need something like `ell/.append style=`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  ell/.style={
    % The shape:
    ellipse,
    %minimum width=6mm,
    minimum height=6mm,
    % The rest
    inner sep=0,
    draw=black,
    fill=white,
    font=\ttfamily},
  skip loop/.style={to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}}
}

  \tikzset{ell/.append style={text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=latex,thick,
    /pgf/every decoration/.style={/tikz/sharp corners},
    line join=round,line cap=round,
    fuzzy/.style={decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=0.5mm,amplitude=0.15pt}},
  ]


    \begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below,
            node distance=1mm,
            every node/.append style={on chain, scale=0.7,
                minimum width=5cm, align=center},
            ell/.append style={
                execute at begin node=(,
                execute at end node=)},
        scale=0.7,node font=\ttfamily
        ]
        \node [ell] (stmt01) {2.  \verb|z = 20|};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you could append the stuff to each `ellipse` node with

```
\begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below,
        node distance=1mm,
        every node/.append style={on chain, scale=0.7,
            minimum width=5cm, align=center},
        every ellipse node/.append style={
            execute at begin node=(,
            execute at end node=)},
    scale=0.7,node font=\ttfamily
    ]
    \node [ell] (stmt01) {2.  \verb|z = 20|};
\end{scope}
```

[image]

Comment: In that case I'm doing something wrong, could you please take a look at the updated answer?

Comment: @ConstiP `ell` is not a shape, but a style in your post. So instead of `every ell node/.append style=` you need something like `ell/.append style=`.

Comment: @schrödingers-cat Thank you. Good (?) news, now I see the `)` at the end, `(` is still missing...

Comment: @ConstiP I added the full code to the answer, and get both `(` and `)`.

Comment: @schrödingers-cat Yes I copied the relevant parts. I just checked and it seems the bounding box gets added, it's just that the text itself isn't visible. There is another scope coming afterwards but this doesn't seem to be the source of this. I'll need to look around, thanks for the great answer.

Comment: @schroedingers-cat In case you're wondering what was the problem, it was the fill. ;) Strange that it worked for you but it seems my version draws the before, then the fill, the content and finally the after...

Comment: @ConstiP That's interesting, I have never seen something like this with a normal fill (but with `path picture` I have seen such effects).