# Why ' every label/.style={draw}' also `fill`s?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please look at next code and its result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw=red,fill=green},]
\node[label=above:a] (A) {AAA};

\node[label={[draw]above:b}, right=of A] (B) {BBB};

\begin{scope}[every label/.style={draw}]
    \node[label=above:c, right=of B] (C) {CCC};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I understand that `labels` are `nodes` which are created after its main node. (Look at [Every non-label node in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49096/every-non-label-node-in-tikz)), so I understand that options `draw` or `fill` inherit main node colors as is shown in middle node. But I don't understand why `every label/.style={draw}` also fills the label, as is shown in right most node above. Could you explain it?

Comment: You might want to `append style` to `\begin{scope}[every label/.style={draw}]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because by default, `every label` is defined as `draw=none,fill=none`. By setting `every label/.style=draw`, you're overwriting these options, and the `fill=green` from the `every node` style is used. To get the expected behaviour, use `every label/.append style=draw`.