# labels of nodes with drop shadow

Tags: labels, tikz-styles, shadows

in cases, that all nodes in some `tikz` pictures have shadow. this can be done for example by:

```
every node/.style = {draw, fill=white, drop shadow},
```

problem arise, if i like to some of this nodes add labels. this labels also have shadows, which i not like to have. i try remove them with

```
no shadows/.style = {general shadow/.style=},
```

but this doesn't work (as i expected):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, fill=white, drop shadow},
no shadows/.style = {general shadow/.style=}, % should remove drop shadow, but not
every label/.append style = {label distance=1em, font=\scriptsize, no shadows}
                        ]
\node[label=how to remove label shadow?]  {node with shadow};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**
to make question and *mwe* more clear:

- `no shadows/.style = {general shadow/.style=},` is taken from [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) answer on [question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129318/remove-drop-shadow-from-one-node/129322#129322) described in code **A**
- his solution in code **B** i didn't test since it require (as i understood code) that

  `\makeatletter
  \tikzset{no shadows/.code=\let\tikz@preactions\pgfutil@empty}
  \makeatother`

  should be in preamble, what for some reasons not like to have
- the solution should be applied to all labels, i.e. it can be used as styles options in `every label/.append style = {<other style's definitions>, no shadows}`
  -now i wonder why solution of  [Qrrbrbirlbel] works in code example **A** where `no shadows` is option of `child` and not of node. in case, that i move it to node, also this code doesn't work correctly.

so far elegant solution provided by [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t), which make label shadow invisible, fulfill all my expectations. in time of this writing the solution of [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) is still in progress/evolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could to modify the `every shadow` style, inside the `every label` style. E.g. add `every shadow/.style={opacity=0}` to `every label` to make the shadow invisible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, fill=white, drop shadow},
every label/.append style = {
     label distance=1em,
     font=\scriptsize,
     every shadow/.style={opacity=0} % <- add this
  }
                        ]
\node [label=foobar]  {node with shadow};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: good idea to make shadow invisible :-). i will wait for some time if more answers are received.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I didn't know you don't like the `\makeatletter` stuff. In this case, I think that Torbjørn T.'s solution is the best. Here is an alternative, which has the advantage that the shadow can be switched off locally (no every shadow), but the big disadvantage that it will put a white box on top of other things that may exist. I have checked that this version can also be appended to `every label`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, fill=white, drop shadow},
no shadows/.style = {drop shadow={fill=white,opacity=1,shadow scale=1.01}}, % should remove drop shadow, but not
%no shadows/.code = {\pgfextra{\tikzset{general shadow/.style=}}}, % should remove drop shadow, but not
every label/.append style = {label distance=1em, font=\scriptsize}
]

%\tikzset{general shadow/.style=}                        ]
\node[label=how to remove label shadow?] (A)  {node with shadow};
\node[right=1cm  of A, label={[no shadows]shadow removed from label?}] (B) {node with shadow};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to argue that it might be advantageous to switch off shadows locally if needed, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129322/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129322/121799
\tikzset{no shadows/.code=\let\tikz@preactions\pgfutil@empty}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, fill=white, drop shadow},
every label/.append style = {
     label distance=1em,
     font=\scriptsize,
  }
                        ]
\node [label={[no shadows]foobar}]  {node with shadow};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here a special for Zarko, which yields the same output:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129322/121799
\tikzset{no shadows/.code=\let\tikz@preactions\pgfutil@empty}
\tikzset{every label/.append code=\let\tikz@preactions\pgfutil@empty}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, fill=white, drop shadow},
every label/.append style = {
     label distance=1em,
     font=\scriptsize,
  }
                        ]
\node [label={foobar}]  {node with shadow};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Hoping to resolve the issues discussed in the comments (after carefully(?) reading [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131179/121799) ;-):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129322/121799
\tikzset{no shadows/.code=\let\tikz@preactions\pgfutil@empty}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, fill=white, drop shadow},
every label/.append style = {
     label distance=1em,
     font=\scriptsize,
     fill=blue,
     no shadows
  }
                        ]
\node [label=foobar]  {node with shadow};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i looked this solution, but other (used in my test) was declared that also work :-(. do you test, if it work inside `every label/.append stale ...`?

Comment: @Zarko I added a solution. Neither `every label/.append stale` nor `every label/.append style` works, but `append code` does.

Comment: i managed to include it in `qvery label/.append ...`, however, now i remember, why i didn't select this solution on the first lace: for some reason i like to have `no shape` definition placed between `tikzpicture` options at other styles definition. is there a way to do this? so far my experiments fails :-(

Comment: @Zarko What do the `...` stand for in `qvery label/.append ...`? Could you perhaps add the complete experiment that fails?

Comment: ups, mistyping: `every label/.append` and `....` stand for `style = <style definitions>}. sorry disorder.

Comment: @Zarko I still do not quite understand what you want. Could you please temporarily add a complete example to your question? (I guess that the main issue is that `no shadow` is a code which swallows all directives stored in `\tikz@preactions` and has to make sure to reinstate them when needed.)