# Shading apply to label unexpected in matrix environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tikz-matrix, shadows

I am trying to add shadow to node. For normal node, the shade will not impact the label. However, for nodes inside a matrix, the labels are shadowed too.

MWE below

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, matrix, shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
        \tikzset{myrect/.style={draw, rectangle, font=\ttfamily, fill=white, drop shadow}}
        \tikzset{mylabel/.style={color=blue, font=\tiny \ttfamily}}
        \node[myrect, label={[mylabel]above:normal label}] (ele) {Single Element};

        \matrix (layer) [matrix of nodes, nodes={myrect, anchor=center}, column sep = 1cm, below = of ele] {
            |[label={[mylabel]:matrix label 1}]|matrix element 1 &
            |[label={[mylabel]:matrix label 2}]|matrix element 2 &
            |[label={[mylabel]:matrix label 3}]|matrix element 3 \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is as the following:[image]

How this happen and is there way to avoid it?

Comment: The `nodes=` key for the matrix is like a shortcut for `every node/.style=` and since labels are also nodes, they also get the `drop shadow`. I suspect that some keys, like `draw` are reset within a label, but others like `drop shadow` are not.

Comment: You could use the `no shadows` key from solution B from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129322/74459) and add it to your `mylabel` style. That would delete all preactions added to the labels, including the `drop shadow`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to adjust the your `style-set` definitions (as done by `@marmot`):

```
 \documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows, shapes, positioning, matrix}
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129322/121799
\tikzset{no shadows/.code=\let\tikz@preactions\pgfutil@empty}
\makeatother
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422782/labels-of-nodes-with-drop-shadow
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style = {font= \ttfamily, draw, fill=white, drop shadow},
    every label/.append style = {
        font=\tiny \ttfamily,
        color = blue,
    }
    ]
    \node [label={[no shadows]foobar}]  (ele) {node with shadow};
    \matrix (layer) [no shadows, matrix of nodes, draw = none, column sep = 1cm, below = of ele] {
        |[label={[no shadows]:matrix label 1}]|matrix element 1 &
        |[label={[no shadows]:matrix label 2}]|matrix element 2 &
        |[label={[no shadows]:matrix label 3}]|matrix element 3 \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This should give you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, both you and @Max point me to solution of disable `preactions`. I am still wondering if there can be options in matrix to avoid polluting the `label`

Comment: @EricSun Also, as far as not to `pollute` the matrix environment, I dont know. May be I can look it up.

Comment: Don't mark accepted because I am afraid people may stop entering this post when they find there has already been an answer. Anyway I have checked it now :)