# Can we show all the nodes' name in slightly gray color next to them?

Tags: tikz-pgf

When there are many nodes each have different names like `n1, n2, n3, c1, c2 ,c3 ...` after a while I started to get lost which node has which name.

Hence, we can help grid help lines using `\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,5);`.

Can we apply similiar approach for defined node names? like if a node's name is `n1`, can `n1` show up next to node in slightly gray color and apply this for all the nodes in the `tikzpicture`?

Comment: Check the answer by @cfr at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327269/how-could-i-show-tikz-node-names-in-the-output-e-g-in-a-label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This combines [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49106/16595) to [Every non-label node in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49096/16595).

You can also use my answer but Andrew's is safe for when PGF/TikZ updates.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  clear label/.style={prefix after command={[every non label/.style={}]}},
  every node/.style={every non label,clear label},
  every non label/.style={label={[font=\tiny,gray]:\tikzlastnode}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\foreach \x in {A, ..., F}{
  \node[circle, draw] at (5*rand, 5*rand) {\x};
}

\node (abc) at (0,0) {x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]