# TikZ: collecting defined coordinates in a list

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, automation, coordinates, def

I want to collect previously defined coordinates in a list and print them later in a `\foreach`-loop for debugging purposes.

The following MWE shows the list `\points` which ideally should be defined and collected by some TeX/TikZ mechanism:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (A)  at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B)  at (1,1);

    \def\points{A,B}% <--- how to automate?

    \foreach \point in \points
      \fill (\point) circle (0.1) node[above] {(\point)};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a package or a macro available for such a task?

I am grateful for any advice!

Comment: Related: [tikz pgf - Can we show all the nodes' name in slightly gray color next to them? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651540/can-we-show-all-the-nodes-name-in-slightly-gray-color-next-to-them)