# How do I make the arrow -->-- using xymatrix?

Tags: xy-pic

I do not know any TikZ so I cannot use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line) post, which otherwise is precisely what I am looking for. So how do I make such a square? The best I could come up with was

```
\ar@{-}[r]^{\delta}|-{>}
```

but it doesn't look good and does not work on vertical lines/arrows.

Now, having done this square my guess would be that the corners would be empty, that is, the edges would not meet each other. How do I fix that problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want an arrowhead in the middle of the arrow?
Use the ‘break’ via `|-*=0@{>}`.
This drops the directional tip, taking up no space.
It should work whatever the direction of the arrow.

Hope this helps,

Ross

BTW, the list  Xy-pic@tug.org  is the best point of contact
for Xy-pic related questions.

Comment: Welcome to tex.SX!  I hope you don't mind if we try to prove your last sentence wrong ...